# Can we adopt a stop whining about bad SO questions policy?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

As a new user I cannot tell you how excited I was to find SO. SO is an amazing resource for which you can get questions that would have taken ages on other sites or cost lots of money to get technical assistance.

Yet, I find myself less and less excited about SO the more I hear high reputation members moan about how awful the questions that are currently being asked are, the politics of reputation seeking, and the beneficence of SO gurus who attempt to maintain the quality of the site even while it goes to the dogs.

I would like to say that the way I see it there is going to be large realms of questions for which there will be a finite number of possible questions. Is it really the end of the world if a question happens to be similar or overlap with another question? If you don't like it, refer to the other question! If you find it easier to answer the question directly, answer the question! Do we really need to care if that user ends up getting a reputation boost because he answered an easy question?

Back in the day (for which I was not aware of SO) I am sure there were thousands of easy questions that were answered and people got rewarded for their obvious answers! You don't see anybody suggesting that we go back and strip veterans of their high reputation because they happen to answer questions that were extremely easy when the questions had not been asked yet!

Yet, by requiring questions to be 'unique' it creates a barrier in which to answer questions and gain reputation users must be much more knowledgeable than I would imagine some of the classic questions would have required. This in effect is creating a barrier so that new users who might be just as willing to to be helpful as old users are barred from gaining reputation points. And for what?

So that people asking questions can be told their question is duplicate and told to find their help somewhere else?

I think there are good reasons to answer questions even if they are duplicated and I know that the official SO policy agrees with me. So let's just stop whining about it!

I think SO is an amazing place. I am sure many people agree. Are we going to let the whole attitude of the site become negative because veterans see other users racking up reputation? I say, if people want to waste their time answering silly questions and if users want to waste their time writing duplicate questions rather than finding on topic responses, let them.

I am just happy SO exists. Thank you everybody for your amazing work!

Comment: So, you are whining about people whining about bad SO questions? If so, can we [stop that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) as well?

Comment: *"You don't see anybody suggesting that we go back and strip veterans of their high reputation because they happen to answer questions that were extremely easy when the questions had not been asked yet!"* By all means do visit MSE for various proposals suggesting precisely that.

Comment: @Jefffrey I was not unaware of the irony :) Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: The "whining about bad questions" is typically in response to whining about "why are all my questions being closed?"

Comment: Duplicate questions ***are not harmless.*** People searching for the answers to their problems ***have to sift through all those duplicates.*** Which duplicate has the best answer? Oh, if only all the answers could exist in one place, on one question, with the best answer voted all the way to the top! Oh wait...(end sarcasm). Also, questions on [main] might have links that point to canonical answers. Search results in Google will not.

Comment: Okay, okay I have looked at a few of the recent posts and seen a full page with the exact same questions being asked over and over and over again. I apologize for asking such a question as this and humbly seek forgiveness.

Comment: To quote myself: " The number of superlative experts isn't scaling as fast as the total number of users. While there may be more than enough users to answer the duplicates, a lot of the answers they give are WRONG.

The guru-level experts don't have time to review all the duplicate answers. "  [more](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254746/103167)

Comment: I don't mind closing or merging _true duplicates_... one problem here is that sometimes someone misunderstands and thinks a question is a duplicate when it's actually not.  Or sometimes over time the answer changes!  Is that still a duplicate?  If an SDK has 5 releases in between the same exact question being answered, it's a safe bet that "same question" will have a new answer after X number of years...  I've seen legitimate questions shut down because of this very phenomenon.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This started out as a comment, but... I have opinions

I think you're misinterpreting the slew of recent questions. No one is whining about people gaining reputation. People are worried about the site being watered down and are finding less *interesting* questions. If people lose interest because they're being asked for the 1,000th time how to format a date in PHP then they're eventually going to stop answering completely, leaving the more experienced programmers unavailable when the harder questions come up.

There are certainly thousands of "low" reputation users who are highly experienced programmers. What you probably don't see is that those that want to answer a lot of questions for other users *don't* stay "low" reputation users for long; they quickly become high reputation users and start down the road of question fatigue.

Hardly anyone is complaining about reputation and those that are have been shot down.

Comment: Then don't answer the question if it is tedious.  I completely agree with you.  I just don't see the point of complaining about it.

Comment: But that's what all the questions have been about @fsmart! Read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251897/off-topic-questions-have-to-be-cleared-out-of-the-way-but-not-via-closure, which is billed as a way of getting the less interesting things out of the way. What you have to understand is that Stack Overflow receives _a lot_ of questions a day and sometimes even finding the interesting stuff can be difficult.

Answer (score 15):

Gaining reputation is not the point of the site. The point of the site is to be a repository of useful questions and answers.

The point of marking duplicate questions isn't to deprive people of reputation. It's to provide answers faster and avoid having to endlessly repeat ourselves. It also consolidates knowledge in one (or a small handful) place rather than scattering almost identical answers to identical problems all over the place.

> And for what?
>
> So that people asking questions can be told their question is duplicate and told to find their help somewhere else?

Yes, exactly. If their question is *already answered*, why not point it out and give them their answer immediately? Why not save both their time and ours?

(If you have a great answer to a question that's a duplicate, go and post that great answer on the "root" question.)

Comment: "Are we going to let the whole attitude of the site become negative because veterans see other users racking up reputation? I say, if people want to waste their time answering silly questions and if users want to waste their time writing duplicate questions rather than finding on topic responses, let them. "

Comment: Thing is your premise "he site become negative because veterans see other users racking up reputation" is completely flawed, I have no idea how you came up with that. People gaining rep doesn't annoy anyone. People failing to do basic amounts of research does, after a while. Seeing the same question again and again and again is depressing and doesn't encourage continued participation.

Comment: People gaining rep is actually a really good thing, the more people there are with some moderation powers the better!

Comment: +100 for the first sentence, if I could.  I'm sick and tired of people treating Stack Overflow like an enormous multi-player video game, instead of trying to build something that's useful to people.  Your rep points are unicorn farts, people.

Comment: Ben if that were true we might as well turn this into Wikipedia and let everyone be a moderator. :p

Comment: @DavidWallace: Are you also sick and tired of people treating video games like video games? Or anything else that has no real-world tangible benefit? Odd.

Answer (score 7):

Always remember that all of reputation is a means to an end. The goal is a repository of high quality questions and answers. The key thing is; if you think you can do better than the existing answers on the duplicate target we 100% want you to answer. But we want you to answer where the largest number of people will see your answer and that’s on the duplicate target (and you can gain reputation for your answer there if people upvote it).

There is a very real concern, not that new users will gain reputation (which is fine) but that question quality will fall and the experts will leave; if most of the questions have been answered a thousand times before or are unclear it is more difficult to to find something to answer.

> I would like to say that the way I see it there is going to be large
>   realms of questions for which there will be a finite number of
>   possible question

I'm not sure that’s true; new technologies come out every day and there are a vast number of permutations for each technology. But even if it was true and one day we will have answered all possible programming questions; then that’s not a bad thing, its mission accomplished

> Back in the day (for which I was not aware of SO) I am sure there were
>   thousands of easy questions that were answered and people got rewarded
>   for their obvious answers! You don't see anybody suggesting that we go
>   back and strip veterans of their high reputation because they happen
>   to answer questions that were extremely easy when the questions had
>   not been asked yet!

Actually that [was suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153152/should-we-reset-the-all-reputation-point-of-all-users-to-0), it was..... not popular. I shall not duplicate the arguments put forward in that question but feel free to add your own thoughts there

Comment: Okay, you are right. About that topic being brought up previously. However, on your other point, I genuinely believe people like helping other people. I believe that most people who have high reputations are that type people. Are they really going to abandon their opportunity to help others because they are bored with the questions?

Comment: @fsmart The vast majority of people here are here to help other people (the rest are somewhat foolish) but even helpful people can become exhausted and jaded. More so you stop feeling you're helping people when you're repeating something which is answered a 100 times before and was easily available to the OP. I don't count that as helping, thats spoon feeding