# How to decide which questions I should not answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions

My question ties into the whole SNR (signal to noise ratio as used in discussions like [More effective closing / downvoting of junk questions to help with the signal-noise ratio?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no?cb=1) and [Why the backlash against poor questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254358/why-the-backlash-against-poor-questions)) discussion of lately but from a different side and I did not find a similar question.

In the last weeks, I have felt more and more discouraged to participate on SO. But opposed to what I read in many other questions and discussions, in my case it is not due a decreasing quality in questions but due to the way the community responds to that. I do not have a lot of rep and only started answering questions not too long ago. 
But the more I read meta, the more I feel like I actually should not do that. Apparently it seems to be consensus that answering *bad* questions actively hurts the community as a whole.

And more than once have questions been closed on me while I was still trying to figure out the basic problems of the OP in the comments, so I would assume those are considered bad questions.

Both of these points together most likely make me the dreaded low-rep rep-whore that I read so much about. And I have to admit that yes, gaining rep is in fact a motivation for me to answer questions. But if that is not the intention, then what is the rep for?

I admit that the quality of questions is not very high. But then again, after more than 7 million of questions, is that not to be expected? I came too late to answer a question about the vexing parse. So if I ever want to ascend into the ranks of the 2k+ users, do I not have to answer the questions that are posted in my tags?

On the other side, I do understand that signal-to-noise ratio may be a problem and while I do not understand how closing or putting on hold really helps that (the question is still on the new questions page for a while) I really do not want to be part of the problem. And I do not want to be seen as detrimental to the community as a whole. Seeing how I can not stop asking bad questions, I apparently need to make sure to not answer them anymore. And that is my question:

How do I make sure to not be detrimental to the community by answering questions? What guidelines should I adopt before even beginning to answer a question? Should I only consider question with 2+ upvotes and no answers so far? Is it okay to ask in comments if I feel the problem is with the asker's English abilities and not his programming skill, even if the question already has a downvote?

In short: How to not be considered a rep-whore? Well, apart from just stopping to answer any questions, of course. Unless that is considered to be the only way to help the site.

Comment: `"questions been closed on me while i was still trying to figure out the basic problems of the OP"` - there is absolutely nothing wrong with this. While getting clarification from the OP, you can make suggestions to add more details which might very well get the post reopened. A question being closed is by no means it's final form :)

Comment: Having patience with the poster of a question isn't a bad thing.  Don't let the curmudgeons make you feel guilty for that.

Comment: First rule of English:  `I` is always capitalized.

Comment: @Lix Sure, but if the high-rep users who come across the question figure it should just be closed, does that not mean they consider it a poor question? And does that not mean I should rather not answer it? After all, not letting people answer the question because it is bad is basically the only thing closing does. So if i not only try to answer a bad question but also actively work to get it re-opened despite the high-rep people who should know what to do would prefer it to be deleted, does that not make me even more of a rep-whore?

Comment: @devadder - if you work together with the OP to improve the current question and change it in such a way that makes it a good question then you're doing the right thing. Once it's reopened and in a good form there is no problem to provide an answer.

Comment: I think you're overestimating the negative impact that answering low-quality questions has on the website.  And the fact that you care strongly about how you're going to manage to up your rep *does* make you a "rep addict" (I prefer that term) but **so what**?  You're helping random strangers out on the internet, who cares why you're doing it.

Comment: @roippi My problem is not so much with my fear that i would actually hurt SO badly. My problem is that every time i read on meta about the apparent decline in question-quality, a lot of very high-rep users point out that rep-whores with low rep are part of the problem by encouraging bad questions. So my question is: If that is considered to be a problem, then in what way should i avoid to actually be part of it?

Comment: @DeVadder Don't let the finger pointing deter you. If you want to answer a question, just do it. I'm okay with saying this *now* because [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/169611) is going into effect soon.

Comment: @DeVadder the **actual** problem is that people have to wade through a lot of low-quality crap; you are dealing with one (misguided) proposed solution to reduce said crap levels. IMHO this "don't encourage them, and they'll go away" mentality is completely futile, in reality we need [tools](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253324/give-high-rep-users-extra-weight-on-close-votes/253332#comment16454_253332) and [more tools](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions?lq=1) to address the actual problems.

Comment: I'm finding that closed, locked, off-topic, and other negative tags/status/settings have been placed on the questions I'm looking for answers to. Some are often years old, even though they have obvious value (to me, and the OP, at minimum) they've been cast aside by the greater SO community. This is negative and discouraging, for those answering the questioned (correctly, too), for those asking the question, and for those later reading the Q&A. Maybe Q&As with enough up-votes after a dismissal should be automatically re-examined?

Comment: @RobertHarvey -e^(i pi) exception, among others, exists.

Comment: Short answer - from experience. Answer 100 questions, analyze which ones brought you the most reputation (pleasure, self-gratification, or whichever your value is). Adapt your picking strategy.

Comment: @roippi And we need less [tools](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tool).

Comment: @Code What we really need are more [tools](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no) to deal with all of the [tools](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tool).

Comment: No doubt, it is harder then it was in 2008/2009 to get to say 2K or any other target you have.  You have 2 options: rep-whoring or answering some not so basic questions.  I am sympathetic as someone with 3K+ rep who would rather be at 30K+, but the one variable missing from many of these arguments is time.  This site cannot be the same site it was in 2008/2009.  It can have the same purpose, but it is another state now and we will never return to that original state.  It will continue to evolve.  I am a runner.  I am getting slower with each year.  There is just no way around that.

Comment: Aside from anything else, there's a tension between helping questioners, vs helping all the people who find answers on the site without posting, vs helping the people who look at the recent questions list and maybe answer. For example I just answered a question that was (about to be) marked a duplicate of a much broader question, because while in theory the questioner could work through all the irrelevant parts of the "dupe" answers to solve their problem, that would take a long time and for that matter they could do the same with a C++ textbook (taking even longer).

Comment: ... the question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744187/include-cpp-and-h-files-not-working/23744340#23744340) is not useful to future visitors, and I don't expect any rep from the answer, but personally I find it more rewarding to help people I can see. So I sometimes answer questions that are "bad" from the POV of the site as a reference resource, provided that they're clear and admit a clear answer.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. It definitely takes a lot longer to answer proper questions to gain rep, as they are invisible to the hoards of the clueless to upvote. I know this from personal experience. But when rep whoring it's easy to gain lots of upvotes on really terrible questions.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

### Clarifications

First off, don't worry about being a "rep-whore" if your goal here is to help people. That term is somewhat over-used, and often used jocularly - after all, the entire *point* of this site is posting answers to questions, and if you're getting rep for that you're *probably* doing something right.

Second, it's entirely up to you whether or not you answer a given question. If it isn't closed, it's fair game - the biggest complaint you'll see browsing meta is that folks [struggle to find questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254358/why-the-backlash-against-poor-questions/254411#254411) they *want* to answer, which I suspect you've struggled with as well - *this* is the problem folks are frustrated by, too many questions that are difficult to understand and unlikely to ever be useful to anyone else, not enough questions that challenge the answerer to contribute something useful to The Internet. If you find a question that you can both understand *and* write a good answer, go for it!

### Turning sand into pearls: answering for the ages

As someone *able* and *willing* to write answers, *motivated* to help others, you hold great power. You may not realize it, but you have the ability to turn something as common as mud (questions) into a rare gem (a well-answered question). Or, as Jeff put it, [to turn sand into pearls](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/):

> Is this a brilliant question? Is it even an original question? No, it’s just a mundane grain of sand question that could have been asked by anyone at any time. What makes it remarkable is the incredible answer ...

If you look at the folks on Stack Overflow who command the most respect from their peers, they're the folks who, time and time again, take a mundane question and write an exceptional answer. Some of them are professional writers, with years of experience under their belts - but others learned this skill here or on other forums, doing exactly what you're doing: trying to help others. What they all share is a willingness to not just solve the asker's problem, but to also **explain the solution in a way that's accessible to future readers!**

That's right: don't *just* help the person with the question. Write an answer that'll help anyone else encountering the same problem in the future. Explain the cause of the problem. Explain why the solution fixes it. Use language that is accessible to a broad audience. Write as though you were blogging about a problem that has afflicted many, not just shoveling a solution at some drive-by asker on a forum. The true beauty of Stack Overflow is its ability to preserve answers for the ages - so make sure you're making the most of this ability.

#### Polishing those pearls: edit the *question* too

There's something you touch on that I've seen far too often: someone takes the time to write a good answer, *and then the question gets closed* - perhaps even deleted. All that potential is wasted - the asker got his answer, but no one else will ever benefit from it.

That saddens me... *Because it is so easily avoided*.

If you took the time to understand a problem and wrote a good, clear answer to it, **take an extra minute and fix the question too!** Let's face it: most askers are terrible writers. Their titles are useless, their descriptions are unclear, they include *waaay* too much irrelevant code...

**If you spend time answering a poorly-written question and don't then *edit the question*, you're just throwing away your work.** You might as well have written your answer on a piece of paper, shown it to one person, and then *burned it.* Is that *really* how you want to spend your time?

I spent my first month on Stack Overflow answering with *one* goal: [get full editing rights](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) so that I could edit the questions I was answering. You can now *suggest* edits to questions even without the full editing privilege, but I would still urge you to earn it as fast as possible: it will allow you to make much more comprehensive edits, much more quickly. If you see the potential for a pearl in an ugly grain of sand, then it behooves you to shine it up as quickly as possible - re-write it from top to bottom if necessary - else, don't be disappointed if it sinks below the waves never to be seen again. [You can even earn badges for this now...](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/)

### Whorish behaviors to avoid

All that being said, there are actually a handful of very negative behaviors that some answerers engage in that *do* warrant the use of a pejorative description. So when you're answering, be sure to avoid:

- **Plagiarism** - taking others' work without giving them credit. There's no excuse for this. See: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)
- **Voting fraud** - creating [sockpuppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685) to upvote your posts, or asking your friends / co-workers to upvote them without regard for their usefulness. This is unfair to folks who prefer to focus on writing helpful answers instead of playing silly rep games. See: [More Voting Anomalies](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/)
- **Begging for votes / accept marks** - trying to brow-beat other users into giving you reputation or recognition. See: [How to educate new users about accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145987/how-to-educate-new-users-about-accepting-answers)

### In closing

I have two last bits of advice: [don't neglect the Unanswered pages](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags), and don't let what other people say get you down. Presumably, you're here for a reason: don't *forget* that reason. Hang on to it, defend it, and in all that you do here work to make this site the kind of site *you* want to be a part of. Stack Overflow has always thrived on this sort of enlightened self-interest - the day we all become a bunch of cowards too afraid of criticism to do what is right is the day this all comes falling down.

#### Related:

- [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)
- [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)
- [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: I have a question about "editing the question too". How does it comply with the rule that edits to questions should not change the intent. In this answer even a full re-write is suggested. But wouldn't this be likely to change the intent at least ever so slightly and then be against the do only cosmetic changes in question rule? So if you write an answer you can also re-write the question?

Comment: Intent != expression, @Trilarion. If you're answering the question, then *hopefully* you know good and well what the asker's intent was - even if he did a lousy job of expressing it. So do what you have to to express it properly - if you make a mistake, the asker can always roll back the edit.

Comment: @Trilarion Here's (IMO) a decent example of fixing a question by mostly rewriting it: [then](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23660848/2), [now](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23660848/3). The question as asked was clear to me (because I've seen it before), but unlikely to be found by anyone else with the same problem in the future therefore -> use knowledge/hindsight to bring focus on the problem, and remove cruft.

Comment: @AD7six This is really a good example because the content is not changed although the presentation has much improved. I will keep coming back to it to learn from it.

Comment: Especially in the case where you write a thorough and _accepted_ answer, @Trilarion, you should be nearly merciless in making the question a clear introduction to, and search target for, the problem that you've identified and solved in your answer. The question belongs, in some measure, to Stack Overflow itself, and its target is the future.

Answer (score 19):

There are 3 kinds of questions to be worried about.

**Duplicates:**

If you start researching the question and find a SO post right away, than the question is a duplicate.  You should mark it as such.  Duplication is fairly common, but it's not that huge of a problem.

**Off Topic questions:**

If a question is not about programming, or if it's an opinion based question, or if it's in some way unable to be concretely solved, than it's off-topic.  [There's an enumerated list of off-topic reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Off topic questions are a problem, but they pale in comparison to this next one.

**Unreasonably difficult to answer questions**

These I think are the biggest problem questions that SO has.  Sometimes they leave out important information.  Sometimes they simply ask too much(like for a whole project).  Sometimes it's difficult to figure out what the Asker wants in the first place.

You don't have to worry too much about answering these questions by definition.  You'll probably find them to not be worth answering yourself in the first place.  You can vote to close, downvote, ask questions of the OP, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you look around the site for awhile and get a feel for which questions are well-received by the community and which ones are not?  I think you will find that the questions that are well-received:

1. Are completely specified; that is, there is enough information in the question for it to be answerable.
2. Demonstrate the OP's level of knowledge; they will understand the answer you give them.
3. Are not trivial questions that can be easily answered by a Google Search.
4. Are not "lazy" questions, i.e. "Halp fix my borken codez."

Answer questions in the knowledge domains that you are comfortable with.  If you are a Java programmer, in general you should be answering Java questions, not Python questions (unless the question has general applicability to all programmers).

Look at the questions [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has answered, and the way he has answered them.  He's practically made an art form out of this.  Not all questions he answers are great questions, but he's knowledgeable enough to figure out what the OP is asking anyway.  He answers quickly with a short, but correct answer, and then writes out a detailed explanation of his answer in the following 5 minutes.

Answer (score 8):

You'll know when you *can't* answer a question. It will be for one of two reasons:

- It's just a *really* hard question and you don't know the answer
- You can't come up with an answer because the person asking didn't provide enough information.

With the latter, sometimes great questions have simple 'oh, duh!' omissions - asking good questions can be *hard* when you're swimming in the sea that is your problem at hand. That's when you comment and ask for whatever information might be lacking, or simply pointing out the omission.

Other times, the question author didn't provide a key piece of information, but you can be *pretty* certain you know what's going on from other information provided. Go ahead and write an answer in these cases if you can and feel inclined. You should beware those that will just suck you dry after changing their question multiple times, remember - you're not *obligated* to hand-hold.

Just try your best to *teach* when you answer. Even if the question isn't all that great, your *answer* can quite possibly become the inspiration for someone to improve it - even you! When you think that an answer to a question asked on the site would provide a *lasting* source of help for programmers, then don't hesitate to write one - and don't listen to people telling you what you should or should not answer.

Do, however, listen to people telling you *how* you should answer. People get annoyed when rather poor questions get *very* terse, often snarky answers that gain an inordinate amount of up-votes. If you take the time to actually write a *lasting* contribution, to explain the why in addition to the what, you've got nothing to worry about.

There is something to be said for duplicates - if you think you've seen the question before, take a moment to look around and see if you can find it, and *if it has a good answer*, use it as a target for "Close as duplicate". If we've got trails of duplicates leading to something, let's make sure there's *something* at the end of it.

This doesn't need to be any more complicated than that. If you have knowledge, want to share it, are sure it applies and you're willing to give us something valuable - *do it*. We'll get our hands wrapped around the perceived quality decline, quite a few brains are working on it, and we've got developers waiting to implement it.

Share what you know and have a good time doing it, that's why we built this place. If that changes *as a matter of policy* then we're really in trouble. It's not nearly to that point.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from excellent answers by others, one more note:

Sometimes, YOU are right and the community is wrong. On other sites (granted, it didn't happen on SO), I had at least a couple of cases where:

- User posts a question
- Community (or usually mods) close it because they didn't get it or didn't know enough to realize it's eminently answerable
- I read it and know it's answerable
- I petition for the question to be reopened on Meta (including my proposed answer)
- The question is reopened
- I post an answer
- The question stays open and starts gathering upvotes, because people who couldn't figure out it's a good question due to nuances of the subject matter can now see it clearly due to the answer being present.

This shouldn't be read as a license to think that every question closure you disagree with is incorrect... but if you are totally sure that you CAN provide a good answer and that the question is just misunderstood, META is your friend.

Comment: You forgot one important step: Editing the question so it is understandable, without divining back from the answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator - sometimes, that's needed. Sometimes, not.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays?

You should answer pretty much none of them. :(