# Should I fix my incorrect answer so as to make it pretty similar to existing ones?

Tags: discussion, answers

Consider that my incorrect answer on a given post managed few upvotes.  A passer-by observed the flaw in the answer and pointed it out in a comment.

What should I do?

- Leave the incorrect answer as is.
- *Append* the correct answer to my obviously incorrect but upvoted answer silently.
- *Append* the correct answer to my obviously incorrect but upvoted answer silently.  Flag the comment pointing out the anomaly in the answer as obsolete so that nobody observes it.
- *Append* the correct answer to my obviously incorrect but upvoted answer and try to pose as a good citizen by saying: "This would not work for such and such reasons.  As such, it's best to do as in [XYZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/)."
- Anything else?

What is the best approach?

---

EDIT: An argument that is heard in favor of appending the correct answer (from an existing one) to one's own incorrect one is: "Improving an answer by adding conditions for hypothetical situations is quite the idea of SO."

I even asked it in chat once and the takeaway was that since the content on SE is licensed under [creative commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), it's ok to transform one's answer into something that summarizes one or more of other answers to the same question.  If that is the case, then shouldn't there be just one answer for one question -- having a community wiki should suffice.  The concept of reputation and such should go away.

Comment: Where's option "thank the commenter, upvote the correct answer(s), possibly improve one of them and delete my now-known-to-be-incorrect answer?" (related: [How do I get my answer unaccepted when I know it isn't correct?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255839/761202)).

Comment: @AD7six That's precisely why I left an option: "Anything else?"

Comment: If your answer is incorrect, and someone else (or many other people) has posted a correct one, what's the point on patching up yours? I would just leave my answer as it is, for the sake of reminding people that there's actually a wrong way of trying to solve that issue - so they won't try themselves. The comment there pointing out the mistake should be enough for passers by, but it won't cause any harm if you copy it as it is and add to the bottom of your answer (stating the reason obviously).

Comment: In my opinion, admit you made a mistake, then fix it.  It won't go unnoticed anymore... :)

Comment: @devnull : If your answer is incorrect to the point it won't actually solve the OP's problem and there are other answers which will, then delete your answer regardless of upvotes. If your answer is syntactically incorrect due to a typo or similar then just edit and correct it.

Comment: @Squonk I understand what to do in such a cases.  The question was intentionally phrased in a manner indicating that I'm seeking an opinion on what _I_ should do.  It was more to determine what do folks think of _adapting_ one's own incorrect answer so as to make an existing correct and less upvoted one __redundant__.

Comment: Why would you *append* the correct answer, rather than *linking to* the correct answer??

Answer (score 23):

> Anything else

## Yes.

Fixing incorrect answers is always preferable to anything (and you don't need to leave traces of the incorrect answer - if anyone is curious, they can see the revision history), but if fixing your answer makes it identical to an existing answer, then the "anything else" option could be to delete.

But a lot depends on the exact circumstances.

If the mistake is a common mistake someone could make (and if you are willing to tolerate downvotes), then leaving the incorrect answer with the comments intact as a sign post of what not to do is an option.  Your answer could be valuable as a teaching experience.

But if it isn't a common mistake, or you don't want to tolerate downvotes or have a tarnish on your online reputation<sup>1</sup>, then deleting is probably the best options.

And lastly, if your answer is the accepted answer, then you should update your answer regardless of anything else because you do not want the pinned answer to be wrong.

<sup>1 - Reputation in the dictionary sense and not as it pertains to your Stack Overflow "reputation"</sup>

Comment: If you think your answer is actually quite a common mistake, then edit your answer to point out the common mistake, and then include the correct solution.

Comment: If the answer hasn't been accepted yet, and if _fixing_ it makes it identical to one of the other answers does "fixing" it amount to "cheating"?  (I'd also edited the question after you responded, so you may want to look at it again.)

Comment: @devnull I don't see SO as a game, so cheating is never a term I would use, as it implies an attempt to "win".  But the simple fact is we do not need 2 answers that say the exact same thing, so if your answer is wrong, and you don't want to keep it as a sign of what not to do, then delete it.

Comment: OK.  So what I thought is not quite different from what you suggest.  As an observer, if I see a wrong answer being modified to be pretty similar (exactly same?) as another answer, should I choose to ignore?  It's something that isn't quite a rare phenomenon and somehow doesn't seem to be quite appropriate to me.

Comment: @devnull if there are 2 virtually identical answers, you can flag the one that is a duplicate.  A mod might not delete it, but if the user has a habit of changing answers to match the correct answer after the fact, then the mod might address the issue with that user.

Comment: "If the mistake is a common mistake someone could make (and if you are willing to tolerate downvotes), then leaving the incorrect answer with the comments intact as a sign post of what not to do is an option. Your answer could be valuable as a teaching experience" I love doing that. I recommend that the user adds a Bold note at the top of his answer saying that: **This answer is incorrect. It's only here because of the valuable comments.**

Comment: @Flimm - OP has said this is a situation where *someone else has already answered* with the correct solution. In that case, the ideal edit is to **link to** the answer you now consider to be correct. Don't duplicate info already on another answer.

Answer (score 9):

This comes down to

> Does my answer have any value that the existing correct one does not?

If the only way to make your answer correct is to make it identical to an existing answer, then you're probably best just to delete it.  If you have something new to say, that's not in the existing answer, then leave it there.

But do not allow an incorrect answer to stay on the site.  It would be really nice if Stack Overflow contained only correct answers; and that should be something that we all work towards together.

Comment: And if my answer is incorrect to begin with, is there much point in leaving the incorrect answer and modifying it such that it's similar (identical?) to another answer?

Comment: @devnull - Huh?  Dawood just said "If the only way to make your answer correct is to make it identical to an existing answer, then you're probably best just to delete it."  You appear to be asking the exact same question again, to which the answer will still be "No".