# Should I delete my own downvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

When answering questions on SO (And SE in general) I always think about the problem of the OP, how to explain the solution in a way that he/she understands and solves the problem, and then the current context and content of the question to serve as a good knowledge base for future users.

This works well with good answers: Write a good quality answer, with a good format, references, explanations, etc; and the answer will be well received by others and it will be upvoted since it was usefull. But, **what about bad answers?**

Sometimes I wrote an answer which isn't well-received, or the solution I had proposed was a very bad idea (which I've realized only after a downvoter comments...—***so yes, do please always write comments after downvoting***). What I should do with that?

I could delete the answer since its not a good answer at all, and only serves to gain downvotes. But I consider that a bad answer could contribute to the Q/A too, not showing what you should do as good and upvoted answers do, but showing **a very bad idea and what you should never do in that situation.**

Considering that, **what should we do with downvoted answers which have been revised and commented by downvoters?**

**Should we delete them? Or should we leave them there as more knowledge for the Q/A?**

Comment: Side note: Is this question better for the generic meta page since is not SO specific?

Comment: It's fine here.

Comment: You should wait for it to get to -3 before deleting it to earn the peer pressure badge :)

Comment: Deleting a downvoted answer will restore the points?

Comment: @Magnetic_dud, yes.

Comment: If you get 1 or 2 downvotes you should re-think your question and make edits, if you cannot make the question any better then wait for a 3rd downvote then maybe think about removing it. However do not remove it if you think it will help somebody in the future.

Comment: it makes me feel judged and outcasted when i get downvotes. a familiar feeling from high school for this geek.

Comment: What if I answer this question with a bad answer to get -3? I hadn't yet got "peer pressure" badge :D

Comment: @Manu343726, Maybe you should edit the correct answer with the additional information—information about the wrong solution; after that you can delete your original post since the useful info is already located somewhere else. If there isn't already a correct answer, edit your wrong answer to be the correct answer, but leave in the useful-yet-wrong information with explanation like why its wrong etc.

Comment: -1 for "please always write comments after downvoting".  That is not a requirement.  If you get downvotes, you probably already know why.  If you don't, you probably should not even be answering the question.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg It may not be a requirement but man, if nobody ever explains why your first answer or question sucks and you never figure it out, it can become a huge barrier to future participation in Stack Overflow. That shouldn't be what we aim for.

Comment: @RobertTalada If I can offer a helpful suggestion, I will usually do that in a comment instead of downvoting.  If I can't, I may downvote.  I rarely both comment and downvote.  One thing you might notice, is that on this question, I did downvote, and did explain why in a comment.  But this is meta, so downvoting "rules" differ.

Comment: If downvotes without comments would be the norm, SO would quickly devolve into a forum for a small like-minded "inner circle" that deters newcomers. Not sure if that is a good goal to have for any kind of longetivity.

Comment: @Pacerier - re *"Maybe you should edit the correct answer with the additional information"* - I've learned the hard way on SO to be *very* cautious about making any edit beyond the most trivial. The consensus seems to be to just add a comment, and move on.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen - Be forewarned: most downvotes don't come with comments. And yes, a significant number of people have felt deterred (both by downvotes *and* by negative comments, however - so not sure if "always comment" helps that much). Not just newcomers. Google "why stackoverflow sucks", "negativity at stackoverflow", or "why I left stackoverflow". Its a hard problem, because pushing junk down *is* an essential part of SO. Yet its human nature to "take it personally". Unfortunately its also human nature to sometimes come across too harsh. I have failed many times to strike the right balance.

Answer (score 226):

Here's what I do:

1. Upon receiving a downvote, I review my answer and ask myself, "is there something I can improve here"? If there is, and I have time, I improve it.
2. If I no longer feel my answer provides anything useful to future readers of the question, I delete it.
3. If I still think my answer is useful and accurate, I laugh heartily at the poor deluded sucker who just wasted a downvote, and move on.

Comment: Sometimes after answering I realise I misread something or the OP clarifies what they're actually asking for with an edit, in which time down votes have been cast for my answer. When following option 1 above, I sometimes delete my answer until I've corrected it and then undelete it when I'm done, to avoid it being voted to the depths of doom. Is that the way to do it? Just wondering if there are any issues with deleting and then un-deleting?

Comment: Not really; as long as you're not trying to mislead anyone, go for it.

Comment: "if I still think my answer is useful and accurate, I laugh heartily at the poor deluded sucker who just wasted a downvote, and move on." :D

Comment: -1. The answer is missing the point and hence irrelevant. It does not address the fundamental flaw of the system which leads to shocking reactions like this: `if I still think my answer is useful and accurate, I laugh heartily at the poor deluded sucker who just wasted a downvote, and move on.`.

Comment: Have you ever received a down-vote? o_O

Comment: I've probably attracted more downvotes than most of the folks complaining about them, @Infinite. Have you *seen* the stuff I write? ;-)

Comment: Just to make things easier this very answer allready received two down-votes. *shakes head*

Comment: I guess that there are quite a few who can read your mind.  There are many who _improve_ their downvoted or wrong answers by making those identical to the already existing answers.

Comment: In fact the tendency to _improve_ answers is so common that it prompted me to ask this once: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256312/should-i-fix-my-incorrect-answer-so-as-to-make-it-pretty-similar-to-existing-one

Comment: @Shog9, I've read that often deleting our own answers may trigger some automatic checks. Would Tanner's proposal above hit these automatic checks?

Answer (score 22):

I think a downvoted *and* commented answer is better **not** be deleted, mainly because it can be a potential "common mistake" when handling similar questions, and having it downvoted and visible can help others to not go this way. If the answer is not commented about why it's downvoted, you should revise it and delete in case of your own failure, for example, in understanding the question.

PS: If that answer is at -3 or lower, *and* you don't yet have a "Peer Pressure" badge, you may delete it just for the sake of receiving that badge.

Comment: I agree to better not delete. If it is not salvageable, e.g. because it is based on false basic assumptions, it should be clearly marked as "wrong, don't do that, only here as a warning" (and shouldn't receive many more downvotes). But is should really be commented well. As others said: If it's salvageable, save it though. I have seen answers almost turn on their head (which makes some comments obsolete), but then they had become good. It's learning as a community process.

Comment: If it is a potential common mistake, it would be best included in an answer that actually provides the correct answer AND details all the problems with the common mistake method.

Comment: this is a good point, actually - if downvoted answers are useful, why is there an incentive (via the rep recovery) to delete them?

Comment: @hdgarrood - Because *nearly all* answers downvoted below zero aren't useful. Worth removing (if the answerer returns, and after reading the comments, agrees). Out of thousands of such answers I only recall a handful that had any value. I've left a couple such answers myself. Its not possible to achieve a "perfect" system; all design decisions are tradeoffs. In the rare case it matters, you could delete your answer (that no one upvoted), and add a new answer explaining the mistake you made, so others can avoid it, and which answer(s) you recommend instead.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve It might not be "Perfect". But it can be better. I doubt this is already the best possible tradeoffs.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve In the rare case when I am certain that my downvoted answer is a valuable bad answer, I want to recover my rep and help the community. Your recommendation is great, I can be helpful and get rep back.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, what is a "Peer Pressure" badge and why would I want one of these? LOL
I came here because I noticed my answer was poor, so I deleted, and only then googled what should I do and found this answer. I decided to delete before it reached -3 LOL.

Answer (score 17):

If the answer is wrong then you should consider deletion. However, bear in mind that for new, low rep users this could result in an automatic answer block if too many negatively scoring answers are deleted. For established users it shouldn't be a problem.

If the answer is salvageable (it's only at a score of -1 or -2) they you should consider editing it to fix any errors. The outcome is not certain - especially if there are other answers - but you could end up with a positively scoring answer.

Which of the two approaches you take will have to be decided on a case by case basis.

Comment: When a answer I posted reaches `-2`, I sometimes ask something like: _"Downvoters, could you please comment on the vote? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it..."_ Are comments like that actually "Okay" on SO?

Comment: Yeah @Cerbrus. But still from -2 the question can go up to positive, I have such an example.

Comment: @Cerbrus - not really, as the down-voters won't get notified of the comment and probably won't be coming back.

Comment: @ChrisF: Sometimes if I see that on others even if I don't downvote myself I may comment to say what I think could be improved in an answer (eg "Your language is very unclear" or whatever) which I wouldn't have spent my time doing if I wasn't going to downvote it myself. It doesn't do any harm, I'd have thought.

Comment: The actual down voters probably won't be back; but if you get down to -2, the down voters probably aren't the only people who think there's something wrong with it.  I've seen more than a few (and left a few of my own) "I didn't downvote but the problem I see is ..." type comments.

Comment: Before you ask "downvoter please explain", I believe you should do several things.  (1) Read the other answers, to gain an insight into what the correct solution might be.  (2) Test your answer to make sure it actually compiles and works.  (3) Re-read the question and make sure you've actually answered it.  The fact is, there are numerous answers out there with a "downvoter please explain" comment, where either the code (1) obviously doesn't compile, or (2) obviously produces incorrect output, or (3) obviously doesn't answer what the OP actually asked.  If I have downvoted such an answer, ...

Comment: ... and it's clear that the respondent didn't bother to take the time to compile and test their code, then I don't see why I should spend more of my time telling the respondent what they could have easily found out for themselves.  @Cerbrus.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Fair points, and those are things I did check for, before asking it. However, I can see how the questions aren't that suitable, so I'll avoid it, from now on ;-)

Answer (score 14):

I actually get immense value out of the downvoted answers. They show me exactly the WRONG way to do something. I can't tell you how many times I have gone to a SO question with a solution in mind, then, upon seeing my idea downvoted into the dust, I know that it is not the best practice solution.

Downvoted answers help provide context to the question and illustrate common bad practices that otherwise might seem like a good approach.

Comment: +1 for "downvoted posts does not equal unuseful posts".

Answer (score 6):

I think it would be useful to partition "bad answers" in at least two groups:

1. Answers that does not answer the question
2. Answers that answers the question, but where the solution has negative implications.

Considering this, we could probably agree that the type 1 always should be deleted to reduce noise.

However, I would argue that the type 2 generally can provide some value, as it might expose negative implications of actual working solutions that people might be using by just out of habit, or because it's the first solution that came to mind. A solution presented in a "bad answer" could actually be commonly used.

**Edit**

Based on the extensive argumentation in the comments, let me clarify what I mean.

Answers that provides a good solution to a problem is obviously of value, and will be voted up to display the community agreement of it. This is how SO functions.

Answers that does not provide a functional solution to the question is obviously bad, they will get downvoted and should be removed to reduce noise.

Answers that *do* provide a functional solution but achieves this is a bad way will get downvoted. By keeping bad solutions **that clearly are downvoted** visible, any consumer of the solution domain (future googelers) will have more information to use to build his own model of the solution domain as a negative example.

Of course a good answer is better then a bad. But a good upvoted answer *and* a bad downvoted answer will together provide the consumer with more relevant information to build his own model of the larger solution domain, then what only one good answer would provide.

In the same way that we use upvotes to mark a answer is good, we have to assume that users in the same way understand that a downvoted solution is bad.

Comment: If there really is value in explaining what not to do then the answer should be written to explain why you shouldn't be doing something, while also explaining how you should do it.  Just having an answer that is asserting an incorrect solution with a bunch of downvotes is far less useful, and more problematic.

Comment: @Servy But the answerer is obviously not aware of that it is a bad solution. By keeping it on display with it's downvotes, we are not preventing anyone from writing a better answer.

Comment: The whole *premise* here is that the author has recognized that it's a bad solution.  By keeping the solution around you are still asserting it as a solution to the problem, even though it's a bad solution.  You should re-write the post so that it's correct and helpful, if you don't want to delete it, rather than leaving around an incorrect and unhelpful post.

Comment: @Servy No, the premise is that a user is providing a bad solution, and the *community* recognizes it as bad. The user might not be able to rewrite it in a good way, if he did, he would probably not provide a bad solution to start with. If it is downvoted with comments, I think we could see that as an obvious flag for that it is not a good solution, and we don't have to worry about other readers confusing it with a good solution.

Comment: If the author hasn't recognized that the answer is a bad answer in response to the community's feedback then they won't delete it, and that's that.  They'd only delete it if they recognized that it's not an appropriate solution, so that's the only case in which this discussion is even relevant.

Comment: @Servy He might choose to delete a heavily downvoted answer even if he does not understand the rationale behind why it is bad, and thus would be unable to reason about what was wrong whit his answer and what to do instead. Even if he do understand exactly what is wrong with it, someone else might already have provided a good solution. To clarify, my point is that it can be of value to let bad, but functioning, solutions surface to the area, and clearly mark them as such, regardless of the properties of the poster. I'm not even sure about what we are arguing about here.

Comment: If he doesn't understand why the solution is bad of problematic then apparently reading the post and seeing that it's downvoted doesn't teach the reader the problems with using that approach, so it's not accomplishing what you claim it accomplishes.  You're claiming that these answers are helpful.  I'm claiming that they're not, and should be either edited into helpful answers or deleted.

Comment: @Servy Ah, but I don't care about the original answerer. I care about the thousands of googelers that reads the question and its answers years to come.

Comment: If even they can't understand the problems with the answer, having written it, what makes you think all of those future readers who are much less likely to understand the topic or that particular approach in particular, are going to be more capable of learning from it?  I'm also talking about future readers, and I'm saying that we don't want to have a bunch of downvoted answers advocating bad solutions.  If there is real value in explaining why a particular approach shouldn't be used, then have an answer that explains why that approach is wrong, not why its right.

Comment: 1. The cognitive abilities of the answerer is not relevant. 2. They will see a functioning solution that is downvoted, hopefully with some comment of why, and hopefully a better solution in another answer. Then they will see multiple ways to solve the problem, they have the opportunity to reason about why one of them is bad and the other is good which will improve their general awareness of the problem/solution domain.

Comment: I reject your assertion that when the author of a post can't figure out why a solution is incorrect, despite being told that it's incorrect, that future readers are likely to do so, and that them being able to divine why the answer is wrong in such a case is preferable to having an answer that *explains* why the approach is wrong instead of leaving it as an exercise to the reader (one that the majority of readers are unlikely to be *capable* of doing, let alone having sufficient motivation to actually do).

Comment: @Servy That the author would not be able to reason about his answer was the result of some distant branch of our arguing. As I said, whether the answerer understands the problem of his solution or not is irrelevant. What is relevant is that a functional but bad solution that is downvoted provides an opportunity to better understand the problem/solution domain. If someone does not bother, he can just ignore it. He will probably not use a downvoted answer if he can choose a better one.

Comment: No, the author's feelings *aren't* irrelevant.  If the author feels that the post is helpful then it's not being deleted regardless of what you think so the question is moot.  You're asserting that having an answer advocating a bad solution that is apparently wrong in a complex enough way that even the author can't figure out why it's wrong is something that readers are likely to find helpful, because they'll correctly figure out on their own why it's wrong, and this is better than *explaining* why it's wrong in an actual answer.

Comment: Well, we are discussing a general approach here, so we could say that we are actually discussing how the author actually should feel about it. You are putting words in my mouth, I'm arguing that a functioning but bad solution that is clearly downvoted might provide value in that it clearly displays the bad part of the solution domain, which might be of interest of someone trying to understand the whole problem solution. Just forget about it being complex or the author not understanding the domain himself, I tell you, that is not relevant in what I'm arguing for.

Comment: @Servy "and this is better than explaining why it's wrong in an actual answer" Oh, that is not at all what I'm saying. If he can/want explain what was wrong with his answer, that that would be even better. But if not...

Comment: And I'm telling you that it *is* relevant.  It is relevant to my explanation of why your assumptions of how it will work are wrong.  You're assuming that the readers of such a post are going to figure out why the solution is bad despite not having any explanation of why it's bad.  You're claiming everyone is going to figure it out on your own.  That assertion is simply incorrect.  You claiming that the author of the post is apparently likely to not understand why it's wrong only serves to indicate that your assertion that everyone else will isn't going to be true.

Comment: No, they do not have to figure it out on their own. This is what downvotes and comments are for. That's a core feature of SO. Anyway, updated my answer and will leave it at that.

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, I don't have too many answers with a negative score, but I have deleted some. In most of these cases, it was because I didn't understand the question, or gave a wrong answer. Also, it has happened that I thought I could give a short, maybe incomplete answer to point someone in the right direction. Quite often that will result in downvotes too, because some people expect answer to contain a full solution.
Whatever the case, you can delete such an answer if you feel like it. If not, it will grey out and become more or less invisible anyway.

I think it doesn't serve much purpose to give a bad answer, and then leave it as a showcase for what not to do. If you feel a certain bad habit needs to be disadvised, then mention it in a comment.

StackOverflow as an archive is mainly useful for good answers. If your answer shows a solution that can be a good alternative to the accepted answer, leave it. If you find that your answer is bad, just delete it.

Or fix it of course, but quite often you will find that someone else has posted the correct answer in the mean time, in which case, fixing is useless, because it would just result in a duplicates of the right answer.

When deleting answers, don't restrict yourself to downvoted answers though, it is perfectly legal to delete upvoted answers as well. I've done that too (apparently, you get a 'disciplined' badge for it), although sometimes it is hard. One example where I didn't is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113262/how-to-determine-if-pdo-is-enabled-in-php/6113296#6113296). My solution there works fine, the question got 24 upvotes and was accepted. Nevertheless, I think the answer by SalmanPK is better, and his method may be the 'official' way to go, opposed to my trick. Tough choice. :)

Comment: I like "If you feel a certain bad habit needs to be disadvised, then mention it in a comment."

Answer (score 3):

Let's distinguish between several cases:

1. The answer is reasonable, just unpopular (because, say, it doesn't use "singletons" when everyone else says that's the "obvious" solution).
2. The answer is essentially correct standing alone, but had been invalidated by a subsequent OP edit or comment, or perhaps by an OS version change or some such that some other poster pointed out.
3. The answer is more or less valid but flawed -- perhaps a stupid mistake in execution.
4. The answer indicates that you completely misunderstood the question.
5. The answer strongly suggests that you can find your ax with two hands.

In general, for the latter three I'd edit in an apology of sorts, leaving any of the answer that might remain helpful.

For the second I'd edit in a comment that indicated the answer was no longer valid.

For the first, to heck with them -- I've got 25K points and don't care if I lose a few or not.  They can stick it up their mouse button.

I've only very rarely deleted answers, when I realized pretty much right off that I'd effed something up or not read the question correctly or some such.

Comment: I would leave the first one, edit an update into the second one, edit the third one to fix it (because that's what editing is for), delete the fourth one, and I don't know what you mean by #5.

Comment: Re *"I've only very rarely deleted answers"* - Good for you. Unfortunately, there are a significant number of people who have written answers far less carefully, or don't understand a topic well enough, and once the flaws are pointed out, would be best off simply deleting the answer. [If they have nothing useful to contribute to the discussion, beyond what other answers already say.]

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to say that a poor answer can still be part of a shared learning experience. If you suggest a solution, but it has a comment warning you of the pitfalls of that approach, then this stands as a warning to someone else trying to do the same thing.

You learn, and you can give that lesson to anyone reading the thread. Nobody (or at least, nobody worth knowing) will look at that downvote and consider your other answers any less valuable.

Answer (score 1):

I have never deleted an answer of mine (that I can recall, at least), and I probably never will.  If I recognize my own mistake, if it's fixable then I'll fix it, otherwise I will acknowledge it, either in the comments or in an edit to the answer itself (depending on what makes the most sense for the most visibility), but will otherwise leave it in the hopes that my error, recognized as an error, can still be informative to others.

Answer (score -1):

> What should I do with that?

I don't know what should be done. Others on Meta will likely give you pretty good direction. There's already some unique views and good answers.

However, here's what I do: I leave it to be down voted. I look at it like "stand up and take it like a man". I don't take the easy way out, even if its more painful.

I also look at it as "take the good with the bad". Its not really fair to keep the good ones and discard the bad ones. If you want up votes, you have to take down votes on occasion.

Comment: You shouldn't be deleting the posts to get reputation back, you should be deleting them because the post is harmful and removing it makes the world a better place.  The fact that it gives you some rep is merely an additional incentive for you to do the right thing.

Comment: @ Servy - If I was doing something incorrectly, then others might be doing it incorrectly too. Leaving it up so others learn how *not* to do it is a benefit to the community.

Comment: 1) Yet that's not what your answer is advocating.  If that's why you feel that the answer should stick around then that's what you should say. 2) If the goal is to explain how not to solve a problem then the answer should be written (or re-written) to explain that a solution isn't appropriate and why, rather than advocating it as a valid solution when it's not.

Comment: @Servy I think jww may have a point here: we need *bad* examples too. Changing your answer in order to show that you have improved as a programmer and as a person may be admirable... But sometimes seeing a really downvoted answer with an information that you used to believe was *right* teaches you more than reading a perfect, right answer.

Comment: Of course, I also believe that almost nobody will act like that. I am guilty of deleting downvoted answers, and probably will do again. :-/

Comment: @rsenna Seeing a downvoted answer *when you don't understand what's wrong with it* is not particularly valuable.  If there is significant value in understanding what a particular approach is and why it shouldn't be done *then have an answer explaining what a particular approach is and why it shouldn't be done* rather than having an answer advocating the use of a problematic answer.

Comment: @Servy Again, I disagree. I believe there is value in bad examples. We learn by mistakes, at least as much as we learn by doing things right. And we have many ways of finding out why that answer was downvoted: comments to that answer, googling about it and so forth. Also, a downvoted answer will make you curious (sometimes even angry), if it says something that you believe is right. You'll activelly try to find out if it is, indeed, wrong.

Comment: @rsenna For the person who posted it, sure, that's generally true.  The downvotes may provided motivation for them to learn why their answer is bad.  If they do actually learn why the answer is bad *they should be fixing their answer to reflect that* instead of leaving it as a bad answer.  As much as the person who posted the answer may be sufficiently skilled and motivated to figure out why it's a bad answer and learn from it, other readers are going to be dramatically less likely to.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should not delete an down-voted post since it indeed does help in the learning process as it is an example of a bad idea. Which has the potential to teach others that might have had the same idea that it is not a particularly good one. Here the, community should take on themselves to comment where the flaws are so the people who were wandering: "What is wrong here?" can learn something from it.

Comment: Isn't this answer basically the same as [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263082/456814)?