# Is this answer suitable?

Tags: discussion

When answering the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718696/java-extremely-basic-jfilechooser-issue), I made the following answer (already deleted. I am not sure whether I made some mistakes here):

[image]

And it seen that it doesn't solve the question of OP (though it works fine on my computer). In this [Should I delete my own downvoted answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263046/should-i-delete-my-own-downvoted-answer), I know that if it is accurate I should keep it even it is voted down.

So my question is my answer wrong or off-topic?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the OP either doesn't understand how file choosers work, or he's asking for something that violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: So my answer is wrong?

Comment: Apparently.  The other person posting an answer was also downvoted, and the answer deleted.  Ultimately, I think the question is misguided; if he wants the kind of custom behavior he is describing, he needs to write his own dialog form.  That's the only correct answer.

Comment: Tip: Avoid answering confused questions. Try to clear doubts using comments, or improve the question first to make it clearer by suggesting edits. Your answer is correct from technical perspective, but it's paired with a bad question. Java is a high volume tag, you will find many good questions. Just customize your fav tags and ignored tags.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Thank you for your tips. I am learning to answer some questions and make some contributions to SO.