# Deleting my own bad answer after it is accepted

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm having some issues with a particular [bad answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19552112/2635601) of mine that I posted about a little more than a year and a half ago.  The answer does do what the OP wanted, but didn't do it in a way that reflects good practice.

The answer has attracted some downvotes and there are better ways of doing what OP wanted in other answers and comments.  I figured since the answer isn't helpful and is actively harming the community (with bad information) and myself (loss of rep) it was time to vacate that answer.  The problem here is that now I realize that I can't delete my own answer because it is accepted.

I quick search here on meta turned up [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263046/should-i-delete-my-own-downvoted-answer) on the topic.  After reading through it I am now a bit conflicted on whether it is the best thing to have the answer deleted. Again, while my answer was functionally correct, there were better ways to go about doing it.

If a future reader comes across my post and sees that simple string replacements are best left to simple string functions instead of regular expressions, well then my error has given them helpful knowledge.  That results in a net gain IMO - which a little lost rep is a small price to pay for others to learn from it.  Then again, the post is grayed out so it may also be doing nothing for the community or myself.

Before posting this I edited the post to reflect what the better answer would have been.  However it still leaves the question: Should I ask for a moderator to intervene and delete the post (if they will that is), or leave it as is in the hopes it helps a future user? My opinion at this point would be to simply get rid of it, but it technically belongs to the community, good or bad.

Comment: I doubt a mod would delete it. They might agree to disassociate you from it though so upvotes and downvotes would no longer go to you and your name would not appear against it.

Comment: Note that using "EDIT:" in your posts is both unnecessary and undesirable. Stack Exchange is not a forum, and every post already has a detailed revision history viewable by anyone..  Michael specified exactly how to do this properly: *use a horizontal rule to separate the old answer from the new.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for that clarification. I was getting ready to make an edit to that but it seems you've beaten me to it.

Comment: According to [this search query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-3+is%3Aa+isaccepted%3Ayes) there are 1,369 accepted downvoted answers like yours, so you're not alone :-)

Comment: I've posed this as a feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272849/please-allow-me-to-delete-my-own-accepted-answer If you agree, please upvote it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Edit your post, but *don't remove the original answer*. I've run into [this same problem myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833314/are-secret-urls-truly-secure/4833324#4833324). As long as your newer version of the answer still answers the original question, you are only improving your answer.

I would clarify what the original answer was, separate the old and new answers with a horizontal rule, and write in your new answer. Clearly identify why you are making a change so people who end up on your answer can learn from the change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That is exactly what I did - edited with the correct info, but left the original post.

Comment: You can edit your answer but it doesn't remove the downvotes.