# How should I react to downvotes?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Some time ago, I saw a user with high reputation getting very upset for a downvote in his answer, despite the answer having a positive score in total. Was he just worrying about his reputation, or was he worrying about the correctness of his answer?

I was told to ignore downvotes when the affected post still has a positive score, such as [What does i = (i, ++i, 1) + 1; do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614396/what-does-i-i-i-1-1-do) and [Why does this program print “forked!” 4 times?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716300/2411320). However, what if the downvoter states that you are wrong, or that you should change something in the post, so that it is better/more correct?

In other words, **how do I know when a downvote states something important, and when I should ignore it?**

In general, I would post a comment asking whether there is something I should improve in my post, but that seems like noise, especially when you answer the questions of eager askers.

Comment: In short, you don't know. Votes are meant to signal someone thinks there is an issue, not necessarily to the poster but to everyone. The tooltip offers some possible reasons.

Comment: I am not sure what a tooltip is @AlexanderO'Mara :/

Comment: It's the little hover text when you mouse over the voting buttons. :)

Comment: I think that down votes on questions are sometimes more of an issue. I am a little afraid to ask questions because even when I try my best, I get down votes, often with little explanation. This only happens on Stack Overflow, so I'm pretty sure that I'm not entirely to blame.

Comment: Well @Laurel by questions expands on downvotes to answers as well, which is something that bugs me most, because when someone reads an answer (with a positive score) expects it to be correct! What you are mentioning here is something else, I think and by that I mean that when reading a question, you expect to read false things. I see your point though, but that should be a different new question I think! Thanks Αλέξανδρε! :)

Comment: A downvote *may* signal that something is wrong. Some people get up in arms about this and demand reasoning, others don't. I prefer those that don't, if i felt a comment would help improve the answer/question I would leave one. They're two separate actions.

Comment: So @KevinB you think that a downvote should make me rethink the quality of my post and if the downvoter lies no comment and I don't see anything to improve, then I just move on?

Comment: Yes. If no suggestion for improvement is left, there may be nothing you can do to fix the problem that caused the downvote. (or there may be no problem at all)

Comment: I see, but sometimes you can't see the problem, someone else has to inform you! @KevinB you may post an answer with that, if you like.

Comment: You should *always* assume that a downvote on your post is because of a problem with it, and do your best to find and fix the problem.  You should only ever ignore it if you can't find the problem, can't fix the problem, or if you're confident you understand why others don't feel the answer is helpful and simply disagree.

Comment: @kevin you should still look for what you think the problem is, even if there is no comment.

Comment: Of course, i didn't mean to indicate that you shouldn't.

Comment: and... as much as i hate those comments, you're likely to come out ahead posting them more often than not. Worst that can happen is noone responds to it.

Comment: @KevinB It's really annoying when you see "why u downvote!!!" comments that are YEARS old. I always flag them for removal as long as they're not recent.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263046/should-i-delete-my-own-downvoted-answer

Comment: How to react to downvotes? I usually start with a state of shock and disbelief

Comment: FWIW, my most frustrating downvote was (probably) due to a mis-click, since it happened literally a second or two after the page refresh when I submitted an answer. I _assume_ someone was attempting to downvote the answer that had previously been at that spot on the page (IIRC, that answer wasn't wrong, but it only partly answered the question, which is what had motivated me to write mine). It _couldn't_ have been a revenge DV, since the voter wouldn't have had time to read that I was the answer's author. Annoyingly, the down-voter didn't notice their mistake.

Comment: @Laurel That is just [so] in general, people are afraid to give credit when it's due for some reason or it's just not seen as the done thing, number of answers I've left that just get ignored, be it in a low traffic area is frustrating but I imagine over time will improve.

Comment: I don't react to them.They don't get me in a tizzy. Maybe for people with a type A personality or has substantial narcissistic traits.I use to politely ask if the downvoter would help me improve the question/answer. I do accept people will downvote, and if they don't answer I don't think anything of it and move on.I have seen people go nuts over a single downvote and I just dismiss it as "That is their personality". I generally leave a comment when I downvote with a reason, but there is no requirement on the site to do so. the unfortunate thing is if you comment it can infuriate them even more

Comment: Worrying about downvotes in the [c] tag is like worrying about flies on a manure pile.

Comment: The question was generic @BobJarvis, not just for [tag:c]. :)

Comment: @gsamaras - in cases where my deathless prose, which will eventually be appreciated for the genius it displays but is in the meantime cruelly misunderstood, has been summarily downvoted by the dark minions of the Evil One I find comfort by going down down down to the cool dank recesses of my parents basement, there to spends hours and hours and hours hee-hee sharpening sharpening sharpening my machete collection until the edges GLEAM in the gloaming, oh yes they do precious they do until the day comes when they shall be released to do my bidding hee-hee-hee-hee-hee-hee-hiccup... :-)

Comment: Hiccup @BobJarvis, hiccup! :)

Comment: I think **the big problem** is not even how annoying it can be for the creator of the answer, BUT how, as a reader searching for an answer, (sometimes random) downvotes burying **correct answers** at page bottom, can make the answer **seem wrong to the reader** (# which of many answers to try) !

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Without ever having formalized it, when I saw your question I realized I had a bit of a mental checklist I use (without obsessing too much):

Re-read your answer and ask yourself:

- Does it really *answer* the question?<sup>1</sup>
- Is it correct? (Check it!)
- Are you perhaps perpetuating something you heard once that is, in fact, incorrect or outdated?
- Are you using ten-dollar words where one-dollar words would do, sacrificing clarity?
- Are you expressing *opinion* as though it were *fact*?
- Does it ramble before (or without) getting to the point?

Re-read the *question*:

- Have you misunderstood it?
- Does the answer really help, or is it just useful academic information without really being connected with the question asked?

Read other answers, if there are any, comments, etc.:

- Do they demonstrate that your answer is incorrect?
- Do they reveal where, although correct, your answer may be unclear?

*(I have been guilty of all of the above, and occasionally, when I've been lucky, someone has had the courtesy to tell me so.)*

Having done all that, you'll probably find one of roughly four things; here's my suggestion for each:

1. Your answer is wrong. Happens to us all sometimes! If there are correct answers to the question at this point, or you don't know the correct answer, delete it. If there aren't correct answers and you (now) know the correct answer, fix it.
2. Your answer is unclear: Clarify it.
3. Your answer is correct but contrary to common myth: Clarify it to address the myth head-on, with references and/or proof.
4. Your answer simply duplicates an answer posted earlier that you didn't see, without adding any additional useful information: Delete it.

Sometimes, downvotes are absolute rubbish. Other times, they genuinely are a signal that you need to double-check yourself. Sometimes they're just a difference of opinion you have to live with. In my experience, overall, the "real reason to double-check" downvotes are more common than the other two (modulo revenge downvoting).

---

<sup>1</sup> There's [some question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325860/still-no-answer-suggesting-incomplete-answers-or-editing-improving-the-ques) about whether *incomplete* answers fit this criterion; read the [linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325860/still-no-answer-suggesting-incomplete-answers-or-editing-improving-the-ques) and its links, and use your own judgement.

Comment: I agree here and this isn't really contradicting what you're saying, but I would like to note that continually re-reading downvoted questions with a view to finding fault can produce confirmation bias. Some downvotes may be made purely on the basis that the person posting has done something elsewhere that the user didn't like, such as disagreeing with them in the comments, or criticising their post. Though I've disagreed with someone in the Stack Overflow comments before and when I learned more about coding, realised I was actually the one who was wrong (about order of precedence, I recall...)

Comment: Also read the other answers and comments. They might expose something you have missed that is wrong with your answer.

Comment: In my experience, a downvote almost always has a comment explaining it. The rare few cases where there are none, either it was a rubbish downvote (proved by upvotes coming after) or there was something blatantly wrong with the answer. So I'd say no reaction needed unless more come.

Comment: @spectras: That's not my experience, and unfortunately many people read Shog9's answer to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not) to mean they shouldn't comment when downvoting. I'm pretty sure that's not what he says; I read it as you should comment when downvoting just like you should comment when not downvoting: if the thing you're downvoting can be improved, post a constructive comment saying how it can be improved, without reference to your vote. But you'll hear people say it means "don't comment on downvotes."

Comment: @Bergi: Absolutely.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder> interesting, indeed I see how it could be read to fast and lead to this interpretation. I see your point of taking two separate, concomitant actions when you downvote *and* comment.

Comment: Was tempted to downvote just to see if you'd run through your own list of steps, but to be honest, this answer is superb. Thanks!

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman: Ha! :-)

Comment: Upvote for using the phrase "absolute rubbish." ;-)

Comment: What is a "ten-dollar word"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton A ten-dollar word is usually sesquipedalian.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ten-dollar%20word

Comment: @shoover Ah, that makes it clear. I thought the original was being a bit circumlocutious.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I am Circumlocutious! Your monosyllabic morphemes will be added to our polysyllabicism. Resistance is inefficacious.

Comment: Great answer. I like it a lot. If every user on SO would know this there would probably much less bad feelings happen.

Comment: "Does it really *answer* the question?" You have to be a little careful here. *Sometimes*, an answer isn't trying to provide a definitive, complete answer but is contributing useful and relevant information or a viewpoint that isn't included in other answers, and those answers can be valuable. This is appropriate less on SO than on some other SEs, but it's not impossible.

Comment: @jpmc26: I don't participate much on other SEs, but on SO, the answer box is for *answers*. Anything else should be an edit to another answer, or a comment.

Comment: [The Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) disagree with you: "Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on." So there is plenty of precedent for "answers" that don't "fully" answer the question. Plus significant revisions to other people's answers are also discouraged. Just be practical. If the post is valuable, it's okay.

Comment: @jpmc26: I read that as *edit the question to add detail*, not post incomplete answers. Could definitely use some better phrasing. Re not massively-revising other answers: Yes, this is discouraged. If that were necessary, I would post a summary of the other answer with all relevant detail, citing and linking the original answer, and then post the further information I felt was necessary. Thus, the answer remains an answer to the question, even if the other answer is deleted for some reason.

Comment: It's the "How do I write a good answer?" It *obviously* refers to answers. You shouldn't edits those details into someone else's question, anyway. They might rely on assumptions that aren't true of the OP.

Comment: @jpmc26: I don't find it obvious, but as I said above (deleted now because I've deleted what it links to), I can *really* see how one would read it that way. I've [moved the question about it to MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325860/still-no-answer-suggesting-incomplete-answers-or-editing-improving-the-ques) because I'm looking for an SO-specific answer. Re the editing thing: Disagree. It's either the same question, or it's a different question. If it's the same question, you ensure that your edits are in keeping with the assumptions.

Comment: @jpmc26: I couldn't see any reason not to flag that up above, though, so I've done that. Thanks for raising it.

Comment: I hate when #3 happens... *nudges @T.J.Crowder*

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: LOL!

Answer (score 36):

Since there's no way to know who downvotes a post or why, you really can't know when it's a "I'm in a bad mood" downvote versus a "This answer is dangerous and will turn your computer into a nuke" downvote. The sole exception is if someone tells you what they find wrong with your post in a comment.

But, to answer the question in your title as well, you can react in a productive manner without knowing for sure:

1. If there are comments on your post, re-read them to see if there's any criticism there that could help you. Even if it wasn't the voter who commented, the voter may have agreed with a comment. This could be easier to note if any of the comments are upvoted.
2. Re-read your post. Does the English come out weird? Maybe someone found your post hard to understand and this is why they downvoted. If you don't see anything wrong with it, it may pay to have a friend read the post to see if they spot anything odd or if they have any issues understanding it. (This is also a good tip for *before* you post, but I've had posts come across perfectly fine to me that someone finds grammatical issues with later.)
3. If your post is an answer, examine your proposed solution. Is it generally considered a "bad practice" solution? Can you think of better solutions? This step could benefit from doing extra research, but for one downvote that may not be necessary.
4. Re-read the question. Is it poorly written, unclear, or otherwise off-topic? Some people, not necessarily a lot or everyone, will downvote answers to bad questions, regardless of quality.<sup>*</sup> If this is the case, not much you can do to improve your answer. You *can* help improve the question or, if necessary, help remove it.

   If your answer has been accepted and the question is unclear, either closed as such or people are talking about different and unrelated problems in the answers or comments, then help the OP edit and clarify their post. If the post is low quality or otherwise off-topic and you cannot help to edit it into shape, you can delete your answer to make it easier to clean up the question.
5. Shrug and move on. When you've exhausted avenues of potential improvement for your answer, you can do nothing more than move on. If your post continues to draw downvotes, or attracts comments about its correctness or quality, then revisit the post.

You're correct that posting a comment asking what's wrong is noise- It's unlikely that the downvoter will see that comment, and everyone else will be speculating. (Unless, of course, they are also downvoting.) If you can find nothing wrong with your post and are not receiving comments about it, then you'll just have to wait and see what happens.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Thanks to Laurel in the comments for reminding me of this.</sub>

Comment: The other thing I would add is to read the question. Is it complete garbage? Unclear, a typo, or otherwise off-topic? Some people down vote people who answer questions like that.

Comment: Thank you, @Laurel I've added that to my answer. I'd forgotten about that case.

Comment: If you're getting downvotes for answering an unclear question there isn't, "nothing you can do." You can (and should) delete your answer and help the OP clarify the question until it's answerable.

Comment: +1 for great answer and for addressing the possibility of "i'm in a bad mood" downvote.

Comment: Some downvotes i have seen seem pretty harsh. Users have been downvoted just for posting an alternative solution to a problem. But.. if people dont like it you can always delete your post and get your points back. Its called peer pressure.

Comment: If someone says they're downvoting _strictly_ because the post is an alternative solution, @Ola, then that's something to be mildly concerned about. Now, if they say the downvote is for a _bad practice_ or _incorrect_ alternative solution, that's a warranted downvote. If no one says why the downvoted the alternative... We're back up to paragraph one of this answer.

Comment: I disagree that posting a comment is noise, if the downvote is on a new answer to a new question. It can be removed later! In my experience, most of the time the downvoter responds, or sometimes other people. When the problem is fixed, the downvote gets removed in, I'd say, about 80% of the cases. Of course the comment must not be aggressive or arrogant in any way for this to work. For me, it's a great way to learn.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to assume a *single* unexplained downvote is simply a legitimate point of disagreement and leave it at that (unless I can spot a flaw in the post; that's worth fixing whether or not it was the reason for the downvote). If I get *several* downvotes I'll often leave a comment asking for the reasoning. Even if the original downvoters never come back, if there's more than one it's likely a future reader will also have a criticism I haven't thought of (may or may not be the same one).

Answer (score 12):

If you can't find a reason by looking through the comments or through the posting guidelines, then breathe deeply and move on.

Comment: Good point, but that was told in the comments too. :)

Comment: @gsamaras you're not going to downvote me, are you? ;-)

Comment: Haha, I did upvote you @empty, where you the one who downvoted my question I linked to? :P

Comment: I never downvote unless someone's being abusive.  I prefer comments or in extreme cases flagging for moderator attention.  There's no upvotes on my answer tho.

Comment: @empty so if you come across an answer, try it and find that it doesn't work you leave no signal to the rest of us and waste all our time trying it too? That doesn't really seem very nice when you look at it from the point of view of the masses rather than the point of view of the single asker or answerer. The needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few so I've heard.

Comment: Upvotes allow good answers to float to the top. If a comment shows me to be wrong, then I correct. There is no reason for me to worry about a down vote with no explanatory comment

Comment: I comment, I don't usually downvote. There's a reason why downvotes incur a penalty in reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience, your reaction to downvotes should depend on the type and amount of votes you already received for that answer.

For example, if you already have 5 upvotes and then get 1 downvote without a comment, just ignore it.

You should always react to a comment however, not necessarily reply to fight/defend your point, but maybe adjust wording in your answer, so that it becomes less ambiguous. If someone took time to write a comment, please respect their time and give it a thought on how you can improve.

If you get 2-3 subsequent downvotes, there must be something wrong with your answer. Re-read, check the question, check other answers for clues.

Often people just like to downvote because they feel like it - there is nothing you can do about it. If you've been on Stack Overflow for a while and are getting 1-2 downvotes per week - I think this is totally normal. Somebody will always disagree with at least one of your opinions.

Comment: *"For example, if you already have 5 upvotes and then get 1 downvote without a comment, just ignore it."* That's not my experience. I routinely see robo-voters upvoting answers (er, um, sometimes mine) where that one downvoter was actually correct. I recall a recent instance where I had (I kid you not) nine upvotes and one downvote on an answer that was 100% wrong. Okay, it's rare compared with more even voting, but I would say, don't ignore, just check. *(How very meta: Not my downvote!)*

Comment: You should not just be ignoring downvotes like this.  If you do your due diligence to find a problem and see nothing to fix, then there's not any more you can do.  You should still look, and when you *do* find nothing you should take it as your failure to find a problem, not the voter's problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I appreciate your feedback on this, my experience has been different. Probably because I don't participate in heated discussions so much, where robo votes matter. In cases like this (my opinion) a downvoter should care to put a comment, in order to get noticed. Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31944875/897326), there is 1 random downvote on that. Can't remember my other answers that suffered but there were quite a few.

Comment: @Neolisk: Yeah, rubbish downvotes absolutely do happen. :-) My view is just to not ignore it, but don't obsess either. When it happens to me (several upvotes and a downvote), I still double-check just in case, but yeah, I'm probably not as thorough as when it's simply downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Simply ignore it and go on forward. Stack Overflow is only a Q&A machine, nothing more. Don't see it as a replacement for social interaction.

Comment: Failing to accept feedback and learn from your mistakes (and ignoring them instead) is very harmful to you and will greatly impede your growth.

Comment: @Servy when you get only a downvote without further feedback, then what can you learn from it? Therefore, just ignore it.

Comment: You can learn all sorts of things from it.  Just look at some of the answers here.  If you fail to find anything, that's one thing, but when you don't even try and just assume you're infallible you're hurting yourself.

Answer (score -6):

First let's assume the reader is mainly interested in correct answers.

Whenever an answer seems to be clear and correct, and there are no relevant contrary facts, references, or (sound) reasons noted in the comments or answers, downvotes can be ignored.

It is possible that the downvoter:

- knows of a relevant objection, lacks the time to explain it, and dutifully downvotes an answer.
- is in error.
- is voting from some baser interest.  Example:  suppose a bounty with tied answers, and they wish to break the tie for themselves, an ally, or against a non-ally.
- is a keyword-based bot, or sometimes behaves like one.

There's no way to distinguish the first case from the others, even if there's a lot of downvotes.

As far as users finding answers goes, sometimes being in last place, or near last place, is itself a useful distinction.  Popularity is not infallible, and some popular answers are incorrect.  The suitably skeptical reader may then scroll to the end, and perhaps find a more correct minority answer.

---

Now let's assume the reader is more interested in advertising, social networking for its own sake, ulterior psychological motives, or adversarial competition.  To them a vote is a vote, no matter the reason. 
*Such* readers have many reasons to fight.  Uncommented downvotes can:

- reduce their own public esteem.
- reduce their allies public esteem.
- reduce the eyeball count for something they wish to promote.
- reduce their take-home pay, if they're paid to flog social media.
- contradict their prime directive (bots & AIs)
- mar a "*perfect record*".
- worsen paranoia.

Readers in first group (interested mainly in correct answers) all probably sometimes *wish* there were no readers in the second group, but the second group posts useful answers and comments too, and sometimes votes well.

Readers in the second group (a vote is a vote) may be skeptical about whether there really *are* any readers in the first group.

Comment: you have a great occasion to apply the accepted answer's tricks right now ;)

Comment: Ah well, 3 down, 6 minutes after posting.  Apparently the idea that _popularity is infallible_ might itself be somewhat _popular_.   "Nec audiendi qui solent dicere, [Vox populi, vox Dei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vox_populi#Proverbial_use), quum tumultuositas vulgi semper insaniae proxima sit."

Comment: Just a wild guess here, but I would say these downvotes are a direct result of failing to answer the question provided and taking a forum like approach to a Q & A. I sincerely doubt popularity has much if anything to do with it.

Comment: @ElderGeek, the OP wondered whether a hi-rep downvoted answerer was angrier over 1) the loss to his reputation or 2) the loss to public understanding (assuming the answer was correct) wrought by such a downvote.  With popular error answers, neither loss occurs: with popular errors, the downvotes are more correct by default, and reputation advanced by error should be not be envied.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion my comment was a comment on your answer, not an answer to the OP (hence comment here). I hope that clarifies any confusion. Best Regards.