# Initial Edits and Fastest Gun in the West

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

I've noticed a form of abuse recently.

Take a look at [this revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24931654/revisions) I've noticed this user as well as several others often do the following:

- Leave an empty answer that does not contribute to the question.
- Delete it, so it can't be down voted.
- Write the answer down.
- Undelete it.

This means that the answer is now marked as the first answer on the question (which attracts upvotes for being first) although it was not an answer, and it can not be penalized since it is deleted.

In my opinion, this form of abuse should not be acceptable in Stack Overflow. Before making a concrete feature request - What can we be done to mitigate or prevent it?

[image: a dirty business]

Comment: Why would you clear out his nickname if you link to his revision history?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I can't clear the name from his revision history, I would if I could. This is "minimizing the witch hunt" as I'd really like to focus on fixing the problem rather than focusing on a specific instance. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: I thought that the answers appear in random order, instead of the order of their insertion, till the answers get upvotes, even if we selected `votes` tab.

Comment: It's hard to upvote the answer while it's deleted. Do people really sort by age and assign votes based on timestamp, after the fact?

Comment: For me, if I asked a question, and there were two answers that had similar, and correct content, and they aren't really better than eachother, i'd go off of the timestamp, which is, then, where this becomes the issue. I think. Maybe.

Comment: @Bruno this is not the first time I've seen this - but like I said I'd _really_ like to avoid a "witch hunt" and I'd like to see how we can address the issue rather than punish a user who otherwise makes a lot of valuable contributions to the site.

Comment: @NickDugger: Well you certainly shouldn't be doing that. If they aren't really better than each other, and they're both correct, then you should upvote _both_. What the heck are you doing withholding upvotes based on relative post age?! Sounds like you're trying to use your votes to "game" the final answer order: that's not your job.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, but it is not only about votes. There are also the badges, for example: enlightened.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not speaking uppvotes, rather an actual acceptance of an answer. I was saying that if it was *my* question. I would upvote both, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You know that fastest guns really do get more upvotes, right ?

Comment: @rubenvb You'll find that the people that try to abuse site mechanics for the sake of reputation (exception those that go to the point of committing voting fraud) tend to have a lot of rep.  When you go out of you way to do everything you can to try to get rep, you tend to get more of it than people that don't care as much about trying to get rep.  This shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: I browsed through 6 or so pages of this user's edits and did not see this happening before. I've extensively edited answers myself; that is not "abusing the system". I don't see why deleting, thinking it over, and editing new insights into an answer is abusing the system.

Comment: In my experience, FGITW tend to abuse the grace period. This doesn't seem to be the case here. (Maybe that's what he was hoping for, and then got distracted before the end of the grace period.)

Comment: @Jongware the original answer was simply nothing. it was the minimal amount of text to act as a placeholder.

Comment: @rlemon: it might have been edited inside the grace period. "Oh wait, that was not a good answer."

Comment: -1: Well-written question but I disagree that we should do anything here.

Comment: @Jongware sure that is plausible,  but if the user is liberal with the deletes why would they edit with that content if not to just serve as a placeholder.

Comment: @dystroy: _"You know that fastest guns really do get more upvotes, right ?_" Not while they're in a _deleted_ state, no, they don't. There is a difference between (a) clicking on a new question, seeing the early answers and upvoting those, and (b) clicking on an old question and actively voting based on timestamp. FGTW is (a) and deleting prohibits it from being a factor here. Only (b) is an issue and I don't think you can solve that, nor does this delete-edit-undelete pattern make it any worse.

Comment: @Jongware, the problem is that this might be abusing the system when using the grace period (perhaps he was unable to complete the trick before the end of that period this time): you put a place holder, look at other similar answers appearing within those minutes, change yours substantially, and there you go, you've got the "earliest" and best answer.

Comment: @rlemon: from the history of this user I can say this is not a behavioural pattern. So far it seems to me a one-off occurrence.

Comment: @AndreSilva: [So it seems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta); that's new to me and I believe it's a recent change. Thanks.

Comment: @Ben: +1, then, but still see my answer.

Comment: @Bruno: can you see any *deleted* answers -- or possibly comments -- from which this user would have "stolen" his own answers?

Comment: @Jongware There is a deleted answer with bits of code in its history, obviously a bit similar since it was trying to answer the question, but it doesn't look suspicious to me. It would be quite unfair to throw accusations on that basis.

Comment: Good that you brought this up.  But I'm surprised that you didn't mention the other more common form wherein an extremely high rep user would change her answer within the 5-minute grace period to _include_ approaches suggested in other answers thereby making those appear redundant.

Comment: Moreover, there is another set who tend to make their posts _more complete_ by adding stuff like: "So you could also do as suggested by user XYZ ...".  I'd say that you get to see a variety of folks here.

Comment: I once posted this too: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256312/should-i-fix-my-incorrect-answer-so-as-to-make-it-pretty-similar-to-existing-one -- Interestingly enough what I could gather was that folks consider it okay to _fix your answer_ (even if you're copy/pasting from the other ones).  Sweet.

Comment: @thefourtheye: *"I thought that the answers appear in random order"* Not when you first come to the page. When you first come to the page their in "active", "oldest", or "votes" order (with "votes" being the default -- just checked). (And that's interesting, I thought it was "oldest." I wonder if that's a change or what.)

Comment: *"Moreover, there is another set who tend to make their posts more complete by adding stuff like: "So you could also do as suggested by user XYZ ...""* There are times that can be appropriate. I agree they are not numerous. In my view, if you do that, you're obliged to A) actually link to the answer (don't just refer to it, an actual link), and B) upvote it. If it's good enough to reference, it's absolutely good enough to vote up.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "withholding upvotes"?, why should you mandate how that user wants to upvote?. If he thinks that only one of two correct but similar answers merits an upvote then he should be upvoting one. "That's not your job", what, we have jobs here now?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history

Comment: @Lamak: I'm not "mandating" anything; he/she is free to use his/her vote as he/she chooses, just as I'm free to point out when that freedom is being wilfully abused by casting votes contrary to the way the system is intended to be used. Apparently you're incapable of comprehending why this "upvote just one of them to get your favourite to the top" is not supposed to be the role of any individual contributor, because it can't possibly work as a system. So I shan't bother explaining it to you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "What the heck are you doing withholding upvotes based on relative post age?!", yeah, just pointing out, whatever you say. So, upvoting the answer I prefer isn't the role of any contributor, right?

Comment: @Lamak: That is correct. You are not supposed to upvote the one answer you prefer. You are supposed to upvote any answer you find useful. The top answer is automatically determined by how many people found that answer useful compared to other answers. See, it's about _everyone's_ opinion, not just yours: when people try to "game" the system by asserting their own preference for a single answer to "win", it all falls over.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, exactly, it's about everyone's opinion...and my opinion is one of them

Comment: @Lamak: And your opinion is that both answers are equally good, so upvote both answers. This isn't hard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Again, you don't get to dictate how someone else choose to upvote. My opinion is that of both answers, only one gets un upvote (it's not really even **my** opinion, but a perfectly valid one nevertheless)

Comment: @Lamak: Again, I'm not "dictating" anything. I'm saying your voting pattern is silly and harmful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: People are not ideal. The system is not ideal either. Some try to game the system. Some others are frustrated by that and may very well want to go by their own voting rules in attempts to prevent the abuse. Why? Because gaming the system leads to gaining unwarranted rep, and it seems there is this large category of people who tend to trust the poster's rep more than necessary. That leads to highly-voted rubbish. And that, in turn, defeats the (main?) purpose of the system.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: To me, it's not about "justice" in terms of "I should've had more rep because I'm obviously better than e.g. this user who, nevertheless, has got more rep than me", rather it's about "This user shouldn't get so much rep given the amount of rubbish they've been posting lately and getting away with it, or they'll continue posting rubbish and get away with it the more easily the more rep they have".

Comment: @all I've posted my clarification on what happened below

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Since this example you picked doesn't actually seem to be an example of the abuse you describe, you could try to find an *actual abuse example*, where there's a pattern of a user doing this repeatedly, and update this question. If an answer is wrong, it's quite normal to delete it. Then if it can be edited to be correct, it will likely get undeleted after edits. This is normal, has happened to me a few times too. I do agree with your point, that something could be done to remove possibility of intentional abuse (such as updating displayed timestamps).

Comment: @AndriyM: To me it's not about the user's rep gains. It's about the post score. If post A is equally as good as post B, but you only upvote post A, then you're _lying_ about the perceived quality of post B, to everyone who comes along later and views the post. That breaks the voting system, effectively.

Comment: Can all the downvoters now undo their jumping of the proverbial gun with respect to the answer in question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Even though I agree that good effort and good knowledge should be rewarded, in my opinion this is not an exam where exactly identical answers are perfectly fine as long as they are correct. Keeping duplicate answers *can* be detrimental. If five people answered a question exactly the same way, correctly and almost completely, and a sixth person came later and added a valid and very important point, the latest answer might not get your attention soon enough if you had to scroll down to it past five absolutely identical answers because those had all been voted *honestly*.

Comment: @AndriyM: If you see duplicate answers that are obviously just copies then you should be flagging them. As for having to scroll down, well if you're a software developer reading a free Q&A and can't be bloody _bothered_ to read the whole page, then frankly you deserve to miss out on all the juicy details. Why should we labour to put everything juicy right at the top just for the exceedingly lazy?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No, I'm not talking about literal duplicates (= plagiarism), it's about "almost great" minds thinking alike. Several people, each in their own way, could address the same, more obvious, aspect or aspects of the problem correctly. Someone else might *later* address the missed part, but by that time the previous correct (and identical in essence) answers might have received so many honest votes as to leave little chance for the latest answer to be noticed and recognised adequately.

Comment: @AndriyM: Again, if you're performing research, it's your duty to read all of the material. It's nobody else's fault — and certainly not _ours_ — if a researcher can't be arsed to read more than the top two posts. It is not for us to throw away logic, common sense and a system with some integrity just so that we can force everything that some individual decides is "the best information" to the top of the pile for lazy people. That is the surest way to completely break the peer-review system and result in despotic sharing of information.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I get your point about research, common sense and lazy people, but sometimes you just can't afford a thorough research, and time constraints might press you to assume that the top two answers that repeat each other is all there is to what you need to implement/fix/whatever, *because* they echo each other *and* they are voted more or less equally. Again, I'm all for rewarding good contribution, but my position is *also* that duplicate answers can be detrimental to the quality of a site that poses itself as a repository of knowledge/experience.

Comment: @AndriyM: So flag them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, I might from now on, thanks, although when it comes to judging what does or doesn't add value from the *technical* point of view, I believe it's for the (relevant sub)community to decide, not for moderators. And so sometimes I might still just vote discreetly as before.

Comment: @AndriyM: If it's for the community to decide why are you taking it on yourself?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Maybe I misunderstand the word "community" or the phrase "community decides". I thought my decisions together with all the others' decisions aggregate to the community decision on something or other.

Comment: @AndriyM: I don't think flagging answers because they contain the same information as others would be appropriate at all. Just upvote the answer you think deserves it, and downvote the ones that don't add anything/are incomplete.

Comment: @AndriyM: Yes, and what I've been seen saying all along is that your decision to take matters into your own hands and vote for just one of two perfectly good answers is taking the aggregate role of the community and stealing it for yourself! The aggregation can't work effectively if everybody is gaming it to promote a single answer - what if everybody is trying to promote a different answer? There's no point in voting at all then because it's all entirely arbitrary.

Comment: [hyperbole](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Hyperbole): 
> your decision to take matters into your own hands and vote for just one of two perfectly good answers is taking the aggregate role of the community and stealing it for yourself!

Comment: @swasheck: Oh, I so much love comments in Greek.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Stealing the aggregate role of community for myself? Are you saying that my voting pattern is the single one that upsets the perfect balance that everyone else's voting is contributing to? I don't know what to say, this makes no sense to me, sorry. Other than that, I get your points and I *think* you get mine too, it's just that we disagree on priorities. You also appear to have a simpler and clearer voting principles than I do. I have no problem with that and I will stand by my preferences nevertheless.

Comment: I can't help it if none of you understand basic logic *shrug*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The criterion for an upvote is "This answer is useful", not "This answer would be useful if it were the only one here". If two answers say the same (useful) thing, I think one can cogently argue that the earlier is useful (because it adds something useful) while the later is not (because it does not). Personally, I wouldn't bother with this distinction if the posts are just a few seconds apart, but I doubt that even you would upvote a duplicate answer that came *very* late and offered no new improvements. It's just that different users put the cutoff at different times.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Sorry for being late to the discussion. I think it started late in the evening (my time, [IST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time)).

The [initial solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hs8qk/1/) ([and this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hs8qk/2/)) that I wrote was completely wrong, which I understood after I posted it as an answer, and then I didn't have any option but to delete it. When I delete an answer which is completely wrong as a normal practice (probably to hide how wrong it was), I replace it with some content, like `..` as was shown in the history. The original answer was not shown in the revision, because it was edited within the 5 min period.

As you can see from the attached fiddle references (there are multiple fiddle versions where I started to workout the solution), it was not a fastest gun approach. I think it was a genuine mistake from my side in understanding the question in my first read... In normal circumstances I won't post an answer without testing it against a fiddle if possible...

After which I updated the answer and posted the new answer.

Comment: I think too many ppl here complain about others trying weird ways to "steal rep" - Thanks Arun for explaining, I hope this is a humbling moment for all the suspecting complainers who have already posted on this thread.

Comment: But still I don't understand why you started with an empty post. It still seems like a race for the earliest time stamp. The delete and undelete probably wasn't part of it.

Comment: @Trilarion there were no empty post...

Comment: Then I do not understand the revision history. I shows me a 1 and ".." followed by a delete. Isn't this an empty post?

Comment: @Trilarion `..` was actually the original post... I posted an answer(wrong one), then deleted it within 5 mins and updated the answer with `..`

Comment: Whatever the reason (and I trust Arun), the solution proposed by Bartek would only be positive in my opinion (use as display|sorting date the one of the last undelete).

Comment: @Trilarion: Remember that edits within the first five minutes are not shown in the revision history. (We call them "ninja edits".) Both Arun (above) and Benjamin ([here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266693/157247)) have explained why the first edit could look blank when in fact the answer did not start out blank.

Comment: "When I delete an answer which is completely wrong as a normal practice (probably to hide how wrong it was), I replace it with some content, like .. as was shown in the history." While you're free to continue doing so, I don't see how there's any benefit to this (and, in this particular case, would have meant you weren't used as the example for this question). You were wrong, so what? Only 10k+ users can see deleted posts anyway, and I suspect every one of us is familiar with the concept of totally misinterpreting a question now and then.

Comment: I'm with Anthony. It grinds my gears when people "hide" their mistakes in deleted posts. In fact, if they do so after the grace period, I tend to roll the edit back (yes, even on a deleted post!) because it smells like vandalism and I don't like it on any post that I can, nonetheless, see. Besides, if there are any comments on that post then it's nice to see what they're talking about.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit From what I can see from a [very recent discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265658/self-vandalizing-deleted-answers) it seems to be an OK behavior... regardless if it is done after the grace period(5 mins) it is useless

Comment: @ArunPJohny: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266760/560648 Though yes I'm in a minority here

Comment: @sth: I doubt it, since he got his answer accepted and the most upvotes. You're just talking rubbish.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, maybe I went a little bit overboard with that...

Comment: It seems to me that it would've made slightly more sense to post an entirely new answer rather than editing the one you'd deleted to contain completely new content. This would've both avoided confusion for anyone who reads the edit  history later and removed any possibility for you to unfairly benefit from the timestamp making it look like you'd answered first. That said, it's pretty clear that this was entirely honest behaviour and the arguable harms of it are very petty, so... *shrugs*.

Comment: This discussion is completely out of my league since I don't even have a 2k rep, but it seems preposterous that a poster with a 147k rep would resort to a tactic like posting an empty answer, then deleting it, then undeleting it with the answer in place. All that so he can add 10, 20, or even 100 points to his rep?

Comment: How is that an answer to OP's question?

Comment: @yitwail: I've seen a few 20k+ users still being greedy for reputation, regardless of how much reputation they actually have. Seems like some people are addicted to it. You have to remember that a few points by itself is not much, but when added up can be a lot. Having said that, there are certainly many users here who are here to actually benefit the community, not just for a big fat number.

Comment: at-symbol-rr, I wasn't answering OP, I was merely commenting that had I been in OP's position, I would have given the poster the benefit of the doubt.

@Qantas 94 Heavy, I guess I'm fortunate not to have the addiction you describe. :)

Comment: @Trilarion see related feature request at MSE: **[Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017/165773)**

Comment: @yitwail if you had read my clarification you would have found that it was never an empty answer. It was a wrong answer which I cleared while I was correcting it. If you still have doubt about that fact if can check the edit history of the attached fiddle. That fiddle shows how the answer progressed

Comment: @Arun P Johny, I did read your clarification so I know it wasn't empty in the first place. I was only stating that unlike the OP, I would never have questioned your motives in the first place, and I'm not questioning them now, either.

Answer (score 99):

The simplest way to easily mitigate that would be to reset the answer timestamp when it's undeleted.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea, alternatively adding "undeleted on" would also suffice in this case.

Comment: in the spirit of "SO tracks everything" I'd be more for an 'undeleted on' label

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, doesn't undelete already show as "modified on"?

Comment: I would still like to see the answer's timestamp as the undeleted time. people can check edit history if they want the details. The text reads "answered X ago", which is accurate for undeleted answers regardless.

Comment: This proposal looks good. But an inquiry over this practice which is clearly an abuse should be done *too* in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe only allow undeletions after a certain time has elapsed. Something like accepting answers also has a forced time delay.

Comment: @rubenvb In that case you're preventing people from using the feature correctly to undelete a good post just to combat a practice that isn't terribly commonly seen.  There are ways of preventing this abuse without negatively impacting people acting appropriately.

Comment: @Servy how is a forced delay preventing people from doing something? It gives people time to consider what they're doing, which is a good thing.

Comment: @rubenvb It prevents people from undeleting an answer that they've fixed after it had problems, or at the very least, makes it super annoying for them in that they need to go do something else, try to remember that they need to return to that answer, then return to the answer later and undelete it.  The odds of someone forgetting or not  bothering are reasonably high there.

Comment: @Bruno: No but the edits will already have caused a "modified on" link to appear. And, Benjamin, since your hypothetical upvoters are already ignoring that, I don't see how adding "undeleted on" would make any difference.

Comment: delete/undelete is also handy when the *real* question is "evolving" as a result of comments.  You answer the X problem, then as it turns out to be Y, you might delete and learn more, then edit and undelete.

Comment: @Plutonix: Such a question should be entirely nuked. Stack Overflow is not a forum or discussion board. It does not have "evolution". Post a question, then post answers. Anything in between is abuse/idiocy.

Comment: @Servy: I have seen it when I was a 10K+ user. Thought it was odd, but it helps to get sorted by time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, if you modify an answer within 5 minutes of posting it, I don't think it leaves any mark at all (unlike comments).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  by that logic any question which requires more information to be elicited via comments should be nuked etc.  (and I did not mean it to be an XY problem, simply one where a little more info changes your original diagnosis).

Comment: @Bruno: Oh, yeah, if you manage to edit in an answer within the grace period, sure.

Comment: @Plutonix: No, any question which is _transformed into a new question_ after comments have revealed its lies and after answers have already been posted, should be nuked (or left in its original form).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *transformed into a new question* are your words, not mine.  Comments routinely ask the OP to edit the question to show more info.  The *reason* for more info is to ...well, get more info.  That there might be answers extant is irrelevant.

Comment: Do you mean **answer** timestamp?

Comment: @Plutonix: I know they were my words. As I was the one who wrote them... I'm confused. My point is that expanding an answer after a question has had "more info" provided (after requests in comments) is one thing, but an answer totally changing because a _question_ totally transformed is quite another. Therefore, your _"by that logic any question which requires more information to be elicited via comments should be nuked etc"_ is a strawman.

Comment: @ChrisF I found it funny how noone noticed that before :)

Comment: Problem with this idea is that it only partly mitigates the race for the earliest time stamp. What to do if someone just posts an empty answer and then gradually fills it with content but doesn't delete and undelete?

Comment: @Trilarion A partial solution to this other problem is to downvote answers (with a comment) when you see that happen. That's what I do. If the final answer happens to be really good, I undownvote but in the meantime the fast gun effect is mitigated. Not ideal but practically OK in my opinion.

Comment: @Trilarion ofttimes they are just short, not empty. The ability to gradually improve my answers is essential to how the site works. You can't realistically fight that except downvoting if you think the first revision doesn't stand on it's own. I still woild give at least that 5 minutes, though; I've managed to post half-finished answer a few times by accident.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, I believe you. But still there is the Fastest Gun in the West problem. Some people just post unfinished answers on purpose not accidentally. They want to have the earliest timestamp and they want to fish for initial upvotes even with unfinished answers. Not all are like you. You can fight it by adjusting the time stamp by combining (averaging) the time of several edits within a short time. Also by not allowing to upvote an answer within the first five minutes, although this may be too harsh.

Comment: ... and remove the silly grace period...

Answer (score 27):

I've just thought up a pattern where this form of revision history is not abusive:

- You answer the question thinking you've provided a useful solution.
- The OP edits the question in the first 5 minutes to change it, or in second thought you realize the solution doesn't work.
- You edit the answer to `. .` and delete it. [There was a recent meta thread where some users explained that they edit their answer to empty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265658/self-vandalizing-deleted-answers) it before deleting it. I don't understand that but it's not a harmful pattern.
- Since this is all in the first 5 minutes this leaves no mark on the revision history.
- In second thought and after more attempts you realize that you can answer it and you write a new answer.
- You un-delete the post, creating the pattern we've observed here.

Bartek's solution would still work in this case, not harming this use case but helping in the cases this is actual abuse. This scenario is likely given who the user in this example is which I intentionally picked since he is less likely to be abusive given his contribution to the community. I've invited the user to participate in this discussion and hopefully he'll clarify.

Comment: But it looks like he only entered in a dash(`-`) for the first post?

Comment: @staticx right, it does. This is because you don't see the first 5 minutes of editing in the revision history.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: He's asking how _any_ revision could possibly consist of just a `-`. The answer is, more than likely, zero-width spaces — the dash is, in fact, part of the _diff_ rendering and not part of the revision's content.

Comment: This is abuse of the system in just the same way as the guy you mention in your question. What the non-abusive author should do in this case is _write a **new** answer_.

Comment: @staticx see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265658/self-vandalizing-deleted-answers

Comment: it *may* be that he does want to be first and appear to be The One who 'inspired' everyone else, so you create a blank answer; then fill it in and undelete.  Some FGITW posters who skip the delete/undelete part get (non) answers flagged of DVed (then act coy about *why, oh why the downvote???*).  Deleting while it is a work in progress prevents that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So this could ensure a higher place if sorted by timestamp? What if you create a post with zero width spaces and essentially 'steal' the other answer which is right? Then you get higher upvotes because yours appears to be first and the other person looks like they stole your answer. After you undelete it.

Comment: But **why** edit the answer then delete it? **Just delete it**. The only reason to enter a minimal series of characters would be to create a placeholder.

Comment: @SW4: Right, that's what I am saying. It's a placeholder to ensure your spot in line. Then undelete it and it looks like the answer is older than it is.

Comment: @staticx - 100% agree

Comment: @SW4 you could have attempted to answer it, then deleted that and left an empty placeholder (as in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265658/self-vandalizing-deleted-answers) this scenario is what this answer describes.

Comment: @SW4: I just tested it on an answer. The answer if it is deleted retains it's age. Once you undelete it, the age remains.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - you're right, although that tends to be for answers left deleted- but yes, valid point

Comment: Good reasoning, but any idea why he went for a second round? After undeleting, he proceeds to redelete and undelete again. Possibly, he had an extremely undecisive moment...

Comment: This scenario is exactly what I did when deleted/undeleted my answers so far. No abuse! :) .. I'm pretty fine with an "undeleted at ..." timestamp.. Good answer and probably a good question (but never realized this as a problem myself)

Answer (score 9):

OP, if you looked at the exact timestamps in the revision history (which you should know you can do by hovering over them), you would see that the post was not deleted until a minute and a half after being posted, so it can't possibly have been a plot to game the system for rep. (In a minute and half, any empty placeholder answer would have already received downvotes.)

I looked at this user's last 300 answers (back to April 23). I found three cases where Arun temporarily deleted an answer while improving it ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24817149/revisions), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24304465/revisions), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23537665/revisions)). That's a good thing: it reduces the possibility of an incorrect answer causing confusion. There was no case where he had posted an empty answer initially, and no case where the deletion was instant, so I can't find any examples of the "abuse" you're claiming to have seen him do "often".

You claim to have seen "several others" do this "often" too, but you can't produce a single example of any of those. No-one else claims to have seen it either.

Most of all, it's unclear to me how you believe having an unvotable answer gets votes.

So -1 to your question for claiming abuse while having absolutely zero evidence, and for creating drama out of absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 5):

I've occasionally posted an answer and then realized that it isn't correct enough (by some criterion or another) and have deleted it to prevent FGITW down-voting while I fix the problem I see (or that's pointed out to me; mostly, though, I think it is because I see the problem). Then when I'm satisfied with the amended answer, I'll undelete it.  I don't usually nullify the original answer before deleting it (I don't think I've ever done that on an answer that is subsequently undeleted, but I've not formally checked to see).

I'd guess I've done this maybe 5-10 times in total, perhaps less; out of 8k+ answers,that's about 0.1%, which is not very often. I definitely don't do it for the reputation grabbing (I doubt if most of the answers got 10 upvotes, though again I've done no analysis). However, if 'avoiding downvotes' is reputation grabbing, then OK, I do it to avoid reputation loss (but it is to avoid loss rather than to increase reputation gain).

Answer (score 3):

So you claim this is malicious and abuse and done in bad faith.

Have you investigated if this is a regular pattern in the guys posts? Because your claim doesn't make any sense if it's an isolated incident. The guy has 7400 answers, and I looked at a few and they had completely normal edit histories (aka no deletes/undeletes, which would always show up in `/posts/id/revisions` afaik).

If the one edit history that you found suspicious is complemented by lots of edit histories that show no gaming at all (and this form of gaming would always show up in the revision history), then you're probably just misinterpreting the what happened on this post.

If this is a regular pattern you should collect some more evidence for that. There should be many posts with a similar edit history (delete/undelete), if that's really how this user tries to assure a "good position" for his posts. You should investigate further to see if your claims of abuse have any substance.

If it's only an individual incident that you are misinterpreting from the limited information given in the revision history, then I don't think any prevention, mitigation or other action is necessary.

Comment: A 1 time abuse is still an abuse, just the consequences that aren't the same usually.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: But the revision history is not detailed enough to really conclude anything. The claimed abuse is mostly interpretation and guessing.

Comment: I specifically said - "I'd really like to focus on fixing the problem rather than focusing on a specific instance". The reason I picked this user in the first place is _exactly_ because they are a high reputation respected member of this community. I've seen this in lower rep users but a high rep user example is better because a) they're less susceptible to revenge downvotes b) they'll likely not take offense in this question because they know the system and c) will show this is not an isolated example only some low level newbie does. If anything I've picked that user out of respect.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: The revision history *can* be interpreted the way you do, but reality could also have been completely different. You can't really tell. So I don't see how this establishes that there is a problem that needs fixing. Maybe the real problem is that people tend to over-interpret the revision history.

Comment: See [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266693/1348195) where I raise a reasonable scenario in which this revision history could happen legitimately.

Comment: How would you be able to see the revision history if it was done within the 5 minute window?

Answer (score -18):

The post, having been edited, will have a post revision history link on it.

If someone is upvoting a post solely because its timestamp is earlier than other timestamps, totally ignoring the fact that it has been revised in the interim, then they are utterly beyond help and nothing you do will fix their shoddy voting habits, *whether the post was also deleted or not*.

So I don't think you can "solve" the practical problems that this poses.

That being said, the author is clearly up to something and a stern word from a mod would seem to be in order. I'd simply flag it when you see it.

Comment: `If someone is upvoting a post solely because its timestamp is earlier than other timestamps` likely not- but if the questioner has answers sorted by time, and comes back to see the first one being a more fleshed out/better answer which works, they likely wont consider the others, despite the fact it was initially posted with `...` as a placeholder

Comment: @SW4: If someone is going as far as to sort answers by time, then they are a lost cause as above (it shouldn't be an option, even). There is nothing you can do to stop them from thinking that voting based on post time is a good idea. Consequently it is also entirely irrelevant as to how "honest" the post author was with their post's timestamp.

Comment: Personally, if I come back to my question and see two nearly identical answers, I wouldn't accept the one that looks like a copy of the older one, I would accept the one which looks like the original.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Time is the tiebreaker for posts with the same score.

Comment: I don't look at revision history for every answer I vote on.

Comment: @SantaClaus: If you vote on answers based on the time at which they were posted (don't), then checking the revision history is the _least_ you can do.

Comment: @Servy as far as I'm aware it's actually sorted randomly, not based on time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I usually sort answers by timestamp if there are more then three. Thats because I want to be able to reload the page (to see new comments or stuff, or browse away from the question and then come back) and I don't want the sorting order to be changed. If it weren't possible I'd instantly make a feature-request.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Answers posted within just a few minutes of each other are sorted randomly.  Answers more than a few minutes apart are sorted based on time.

Comment: I disagree completely with your claim that voters should disregard timestamps. I *absolutely do* take them into account when voting on duplicate answers, sometimes to the point of downvoting perfectly correct and clear answers because they added nothing to the page that other answers hadn't already provided. Duplicate answers are valueless noise, and as such they are harmful - they waste the time and effort of people trying to extract information from the page, and reduce the chance that people in a rush will see other, *non-duplicate* answers. Reflecting all this in voting seems right to me.

Comment: @Mark: _"sometimes to the point of downvoting perfectly correct and clear answers because they added nothing to the page that other answers hadn't already provided."_ Oh dear oh deary me. Well at least we've discovered who it is that keeps on exercising utterly ridiculous voting patterns, leaving unwarranted anonymous downvotes and frankly pissing everyone off. That's an upside.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You've made up the 'anonymous' bit, and it isn't true; barring an answer being obvious nonsense, I always comment to justify my downvotes (or upvote an existing comment).