# Mark a question as 'Still debugging / working' by the answer-er

Tags: feature-request, answers

When a registered user click on a question, below

Your answer box

should be created a button 'still working on this answer'.

[image: The button]

Then the name of the user who already clicked it will show under 'Still working' section:

[image: still working]

Then those who already clicked that button can answer later.

This is highly useful to prevent (2/more) identical answer to a single question. Also the ask-er can see if his question is going to be answered or not.

Also the ask-er will be notified if someone is working to answer it, the answer-er's profile will also what question he's/she's still working on

It will also prevent someone who is working hard to answer an unanswered question only to find up that it's already being answered.

Comment: And... what happens when someone just ticks the box and doesn't actually try to answer the question?

Comment: Slightly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266689/initial-edits-and-fastest-gun-in-the-west  and for extra background [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/9745#9745)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a solution in search of a problem. I have a better idea:

If you're "still working" on an answer, **don't click the "Post Your Answer" button!**

When you get finished working on the answer, go ahead and submit it. If you do think of something later to add, or a discussion in the comments prompts you to edit in additional information, then no problem. That's why we support edits. But there's no reason to support "in progress" answers.

If you *really* need a "work in progress" answer, then you should be clicking the "community wiki" checkbox instead. This is exactly what a wiki is for—content that is perpetually "in progress" and intended to be maintained by the entire community.