# If someone else answers a Q simultaneously, and there is no real difference, is that a good time to delete an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm not going to cite any example, because the example I would give doesn't quite apply, but got me thinking.

If I answer a question and someone else answers with an almost identical answer, and theirs is accepted, should I delete my redundant answer?

The key being that if there is anything substantially different that adds some detail or insight, I'd obviously keep it.  For the sake of reducing redundancy, if they are the SAME, is deleting it considered bad form?

I have seen situations like this where one answer is accepted, and then edited to include something mentioned in the other answer.  I don't mind that, because most people would probably read the accepted answer, and I'd want them to get all the information they needed.  If that happens, and the other answer is still there, just being redundant, I'd think to remove it. I'm not worryied about losing an up-vote here or there, in the interests of keeping things concise.

What's the protocol there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the answers are far apart in time (I guess an hour or more would count as such, and perhaps much less) it seems generally agreed that a 'duplicate' answer should not be retained. However this is not an issue for involving mods by flagging. I often downvote on the basis the later version is "not useful". Given time the poster may delete it - or acquire further downvotes.

The case where answers are posted almost simultaneously is different. Some believe that both should be retained as further indication (by repetition) that the answer is appropriate. Clearly there is no possibility of plagiarism from the other version in such a case so it might be deemed harsh to downvote just because one answer was a second or two after the other, but in my opinion that still makes the later one "not useful" and where not deleted by the person to post it I might well downvote if the answer is still evident some time later.

The alternative, to avoid what may appear lack of gratitude for the second answer or inconsistency between votes for two versions of the same answer, is just to ignore the later post.

Comment: It probably won't ever happen frequently enough to warrant any penalty for deleting answers.  but hypothetically, is the ratio known as to how many deletions in what time frame warrants a penalty?

Comment: Yes.  I'm not concerned if it isn't.  I'm just trying to educate myself as to the rules, guidelines, etc.  I trust this groups decision making more than any other I've been a part of.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: For the sake of the Question, they are within a minute or two of each other.  I see your point though.  That does affirm what I was thinking as well.  It's a case by case scenario, judging the content and "Usefulness".  In the worst case, if there was one nugget of info on the redundant post, I'd just delete that one and add the nugget as a comment to the Accepted Answer.

Comment: You are probably right. I tend to err on the side of caution.  Especially in a scenario in which I want to succeed.  It's better to be proactive and find out these details before committing faux pas.  I feel like I've done enough of that.

Comment: '*I often downvote on the basis the later version is "not useful"*' - so do I, and I encourage others to do so, but be aware that this is rather a controversial practice. I always explain these downvotes and get angry/abusive replies a little shy of 50% of the time - be prepared for this if you are thin-skinned. The estimable Lightness Races In Orbit was also [sternly critical](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266689#comment68031_266691) when I mentioned this practice on Meta, but it was just gone midnight on a Saturday morning so perhaps he was merely drunk.