# Is it wrong to substantially modify questions to have a broader audience?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

Yesterday I answered this question: [Alternative for 2 embed form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891582/alternative-for-2-embed-form)

After re-reading my answer today as well as the question; and after reading a number of times here on MSO over the past weeks how the site is meant to be for useful, generic, long-term questions; and after reading also in some comments that users should not hesitate to substantially edit questions to "[reveal the pearl](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254549/how-to-decide-which-questions-i-should-not-answer/254562#254562)", [I suggested myself a substantial edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4934696) (sorry for users who cannot see it because of rep, not sure how to show otherwise).

I am not claiming my edit was making a pearl out of the question, but I think it went quicker to the point and was clearer thanks to the more compact code. I also think I did not change the original meaning, as I kept the same example of buildings and products. My goal was to make a good complement to [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form) which I linked in my answer (the reason why I did not flag it as dup is the focus on the Enter key handling).

To my surprise, the edit was rejected. I did not came here to complain about it, but to understand why I was wrong about the "don't hesitate to revamp to make it good". Is it that what I read is only the opinion of a few? Or did I miss any less obvious aspect? What exactly is acceptalbe when editing someone else's question for more than just formatting and spelling?

I am especially interested in the asnwer as I am not so far from having edit rights, so I would like to understand better what is OK and what is not before my edits are not systematically reviewed anymore, and before I get to review suggested edits myself...

Comment: The reviewers seem to think that you changed the meaning of the original post, rather than clarified it's wording or fixed spelling errors or formatting, etc.  I think it's fair to say that it's easier to write a generic question from scratch than it is to try and make a specific question with specific answers more generic through editing.

Comment: So you suggest that carving a nice new generic question and post it (and possibly answer it) would be a better aproach?

Comment: Yes.  Be warned that it is not an easy thing to do.  Canonical/Reference questions are still a work in progress.  The best way to make one is to do your homework, write a good, clear question, and write a sensible, useful answer.  It helps to have lots of experience in the problem domain.  It also helps to use the "Answer my own question" option.

Comment: But then you face the dupe hammer. Seems like a catch 22.

Comment: Like I said, they're a work in progress.  Good canonical question/answer pairs won't get closed as dupes, because they demonstrate value.  If I were you, I'd pick my battles, though.  Only choose those topics that get frequently asked.