# Where did my points go?

Tags: support

At 5:44 pm today I left work w/ 102 points, went to the gym, had dinner and just got back on my computer now around 9:35 pm and my points are back down to 79.  There's no mention of any down votes or anything like that.

Sooo where'd they go??

Comment: Head to your [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4292644/miiinimallogic?tab=reputation) and make sure the "show removed posts" box at the bottom is checked. You should see that a question was removed, which took your answer and the reputation with it.

Comment: @animuson Why don't you receive rep change notifications for deleted posts, like you do for all other rep changes?

Comment: So, I lost rep points for helping someone because their question was deleted/removed?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi As mentioned in some other posts (including feature-request) which I forgot, the tooltip for the "Recent achievements" says reputation *earned*. It's an achievement when you get reps, but it's not an achievement if you lose it, so you won't be notified.

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic If your rep history says so, then apparently.

Comment: I wonder, is there a way to see which moderator removed it?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic why does it matter which mod removed it? they wont reverse their decision because someone lost rep, they are aware of that at the time of the decision making. It's frustrating, and there are already discussions about it over on MSE

Comment: Idk, I feel that my answer came from experience of being a newb and it helped another newb therefore should be a valid one.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but the common reply to that is "the question needed to be deleted for *good reasons*, your answer no longer exists, so you shouldn't have rep for a non-existent answer".

Comment: How often it happens depends on how many answers you have, and what sort of questions you answer (ie low quality etc). I find it more annoying when I'm typing an answer and I get "This question is no longer available".  grr

Comment: Also, if you value the question high enough to answer ityou should probably consider it worthy of polishing, so it won't be cleaned up for being trash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decide which questions I should not answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254549/how-to-decide-which-questions-i-should-not-answer)

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic Don't feel bad, I once lost 180 rep from a question being deleted.

Comment: This is why I don't go the gym.

Comment: @Deduplicator, 'polish'?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic: Look at the post I linked, especially what Shog9 says. The specific bit boils down to "if you think posting an answer is worth your time, making sure the question does not deserve being deleted should be too."

Comment: @Deduplicator, I'm a former educator, no question is a stupid question!  I don't have an elitist bone in my body, nor will I ever! End of story.

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic: It's not about being elitist, but making sure there's not too much crap to find something useful on SO. (And "there are no stupid questions" is a fallacy. I understand you want to be nice and helpful, but sometimes *not* answering a stupid question is the best help one can give. Also a good read: [Are we being “elitist”? Is there something wrong with that?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262446))

Comment: @Deduplicator, your opinions are greatly valued.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 6):

[A question that you answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258361/i-have-a-piece-of-code-that-i-want-to-turn-into-a-program) was recently deleted after being closed for being unclear. As your answer wasn't [visible on the site for at least 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), you didn't retain the rep that you earned from it.

We do grandfather in rep that was earned when something gets deleted, provided that the system can determine that the community *once* found it valuable. That's not to say that your answer wasn't helpful, the 60 day minimum just makes sure that the question (and answers) as a *combined* resource was something deemed good for the site, at least for some period of time.

In any event, you lost the rep for the acceptance, plus your answer got a down vote, which adds up to the discrepancy that you noticed. You didn't do anything wrong, it just wasn't a very good question, and was deleted by the community not long after being closed.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the clarification! This is the kind of info I was after.