# How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, on-hold

Many questions in the close vote queue have comments asking for clarification, as well as close votes because they're "unclear" or "too broad" or "off-topic/questions seeking debugging help ...". The question may only be a few hours old.

**How long is it appropriate to wait for clarification? Should close-voters vote differently, or hold off for longer, on questions with such comments? Is the software wired to take any of this into account?**

The only prior art I found was this

https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/if-we-ask-a-poster-to-revise-or-clarify-their-question-or-answer-how-long-sho

which was written for a smaller and slower-moving community.

Personally I'd give it a day if I were interested in the question (which others should recognize because I took the time to comment). I've seen comments elsewhere on MSO which suggest that some expect clarification within hours. Seems like we should all get on the same page.

Comment: And on Meta.SE: [How soon should I vote to close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close)

Comment: related: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You should wait for zero seconds.

If a question is unclear, or otherwise requiring clarification to be answerable, vote to close it *immediately*.  This ensures that low quality answers are not posted to incomplete questions, helps question authors to understand that their question needs to be improved, and even provides some additional guidance as to what they need to change.

If/when the question is edited to become answerable it can be reopened.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180886/discussion-on-answer-by-servy-how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a).

Comment: And, this ensures that stackoverflow remains a HOSTILE environment for new users who aren't savvy on the ways of posting good questions.  Stackoverflow has that reputation and the reputation is well deserved, especially when people think like this answer says.

Comment: The last sentence in this answer about "it can be reopened" simply doesn't happen in practice.  Those who vote to close are not notified of edits and thus rarely come back to re-evaluate and the general population is not looking at closed questions.  So, questions are very, very rarely reopened - the reopening process largely does not serve those who "fix" their questions.  The OP is generally left to take what they learned needs to be fixed in their question and post a new question where it will then get a new chance to be evaluated.

Comment: @jfriend00 Refusing to notify people that there are problems with their question and just ignoring the problem doesn't make it go away.  A new user needs the information that their question is problematic and how to go about fixing it just as much as any experienced user, and it's just as important that low quality answers not be posted on unanswerable questions of new users as of any other users.

Comment: @jfriend00 Questions don't need to be reopened by the people that closed them, they can be reopened by anyone with the permission to do so.  Questions aren't often reopened because they aren't often actually fixed properly, not because questions that are meaningfully fixed aren't ever reevaluated.  The review queues resolve that.

Comment: @jfriend00 A question being closed *is* feedback on the problems with the question.  It's *impossible* to close a question without the author being provided with the main problem with their question that they need to solve.  Likewise, users are encouraged (and in my experience, very often do) provide additional information in the form of comments.  **That is the point of closing questions**; to give feedback to the author on the problems with their question and to give them an opportunity to fix them.  Refusing to close bad questions you see makes it *harder* for the authors to fix them.

Comment: @jfriend00 Closing questions isn't being intolerant; the purpose of closing question *is to help them fix the question*.  Your assertion that everyone should just ignore the problems and stick their head in the sand doesn't make them go away, or help people get good answers.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's *very* easy to get questions reopened when they actually fix their problems and become good questions.  Closed questions *aren't* removed from the question lists, they *do* still show up in searches (unless explicitly filtered out with an advanced search option), edits to a question to fix its problems will move it to the *front* of the active questions list, giving it added attention, and most relevantly the reopen queue provides an opportunity for the author (or others) to get the attention of people specifically willing and able to reopen questions that have been fixed.

Comment: @jfriend00 The reason so many closed questions don't get reopened is because *people don't fix them*.  Lots of closed questions don't get edited, or if they do, it's just a trivial edit that doesn't address the core problems with the post and turn the post into a question that *actually merits being reopened*.

Comment: @jfriend00 Part of this is that *asking good questions is hard*, and lots of people are just unwilling to put in the work to make a clear question, construct an MCVE, do research on the topic, etc.  People here can only do so much to help, there are more people in need of help having their questions improved than people that are willing and able to coach them through it.  Hence why you end up with people (understandably) ignoring questions instead of closing them and trying to help the authors fix them.

Comment: Closing a question doesn't prevent people from posting comments explaining a questions problems.  Closing a question doesn't prevent people from posting comments explaining how to improve it to make it answerable.  Closing a question doesn't prevent people from asking clarifying questions to better understand it.  Closing a question doesn't prevent people from editing it to address problems others can fix such a formatting or phrasing.  It only (temporarily) prevents low quality answers from a question not yet ready to be answered.

Comment: Note how SO isn't proposing getting rid of close votes, or preventing questions from being closed for some period of time.  Your interpretation of the staffs understanding of the problem seems to be flawed.  Unlike you, they aren't trying to prevent people from giving feedback on questions. (Not that I'm the biggest fan of the company's policies, they're just not nearly as problematic as they would be if they were doing what you seem to think they are.)

Comment: @jfriend00 And yeah, I know it sucks when a system tells you that you've done something wrong.  No one *likes* being told that they did something wrong, that they made a mistake, that their contribution was problematic, or that they broke the rules. It doesn't mean that you wait an hour before telling them.  That doesn't make it *better*.  It makes it worse.  It might make you feel good to tell other people that giving feedback on a question is hostile and everyone should just ignore problems and hope they go away, but it doesn't help people.

Answer (score 73):

Cast your close vote immediately.

The whole point of closure is to put the question on hold while the OP improves it.  Waiting just delays the inevitable for most questions, and handicaps the closure system.

Comment: If that is the purpose, then either most questions are really bad and don't deserve reopening, or we are faster at closing than reopening. I honestly don't even know how reponening works. Do we have reopenening queues ?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Yes we have a reopening queue.

Comment: Closing a question does not put it on hold.  It sends the question to purgatory, never to return.  Close voters don't get notified of changes to the question.  They hardly ever consider changes to a question and reopen.  Once a question is closed, it's dead.  When working with users whose question got closed, I advise them to repost a fixed question because it's highly unlikely the question will ever get reopened.   The closer voters are gone.  FYI, this is one of the reason that stackoverflow remains a HOSTILE environment for new users who are still learning how to post a good question.

Comment: @jfriend00: I'm not sure how you fix that.  For the most part, the onus is on the new user to learn and understand the norms of the site before participating.  This is true of all participatory sites, not just Stack Overflow.  The alternative is to individually hand-hold each new user that comes to the site, and we're simply not equipped to do that.

Comment: What you're seeing is not hostility; it is rudeness.  Coming to an Internet site and participating without making the slightest effort at understanding the site's culture is not simply rude, it is also lazy.  You don't want to be [that guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyhy7Z71qzE).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Well, the folks at StackExchange don't agree with you.  They recognize that SO and other sites in the network have a pretty horrible reputation and experience for new users.  They want to do something about that because it would make the site more useful for all.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/introducing-the-staging-ground-an-attempt-at-improving-the-first-time-asker-exp) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416652/new-user-experience-deep-dive-into-our-research-on-the-staging-ground-how-do).

Comment: @jfriend00: Those are good first steps.  So is a better onboarding process.  Of course, none of that helps the individual who clicks past all of it and still manages to ask a poor question on the main site.  And of course, none of that changes the way close votes are properly used.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - It remains to be seen what they try to implement here, but if an experienced user steps in and engages with the author of a poorly written question both try to understand what the real question was and in the interest of educating the OP on what it takes to make their question better, I would hope the question doesn't get bashed with downvotes and closevotes immediately while someone is trying to help.  That, is NOT what happens today.  People love to throw drive-by close votes and down votes even when someone is engaged to help and clarify and hopefully fix the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - And, then the question gets closed right out from under you, even though you're in the process of helping them fix it, leaving both the OP and the one trying to help with a sour taste on their SO experience.  There must be a better way if someone volunteers to help a newbie turn a bad question into a decent one.  Oh, and the reopen process pretty much never works so editing a closed question is pointless 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 56):

Why wait more than zero seconds?

I guess people think they should "give the asker a chance" to fix the question before voting to close. This is fundamentally wrong headed.

- The asker had every opportunity to compose a well written question *before* they posted it. Why give them even more time after posting it? Being "nice" only encourages people to post first and then think.
- Voting to close a question does not immediately delete it. The system prevents answers but still allows the asker to fix it. So even if the question were closed within seconds of being asked,  the asker *still* has an opportunity to fix it and get it re-opened.
- People ask questions because they want answers. This is especially true for the numerous new members who post poor quality questions. The *only* weapon we have for making those people fix their crap questions is to withhold answers from them. The only way the community as a whole can deny answers is by closing a question. If you care about the quality of an SE site it is your *duty* to immediately vote to close bad questions.

Comment: In one sense, it would be nice if the "low quality question" filter automatically closed questions which it thought low quality, with a note saying "ask for guidance". If the asker bothers to seek guidance (whether in comments, chat or meta) then it bodes well that they might listen to any guidance offered. Like I say, in *one* sense...

Comment: @Damian Herrick First timers should act like professional or enthusiast programmers and follow the links presented to them telling them how to ask questions here and what each close reason means. If they can't be bothered to do that, they have no business being here.

Comment: @ClickRick Good idea. I have been advocating for a while now that even that doesn't go far enough; instead, all new questions should start out closed ("on hold", "awaiting approval", whatever verbiage doesn't make people immediately run away from a UX perspective) - perhaps with a rep threshold, or tag-based privilege, to bypass that filter. It's bizarre that we filter proposed edits from new users proactively, but *de novo* content only reactively.

Comment: @Goodies because there [are millions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1771855) of outstanding unanswered questions on the site already (even though many of such questions [qualify for automatic deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions)), and [on balance they're not great](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1771860). "Come on ! handicap what ?" - **the closure system**. Yes, it's important. We need it to work properly in order to filter the site. Yes, we are people - people who are *building a library, not operating a help desk*.

Answer (score 6):

There have been several attempted answers here in the interim that don't seem to understand the importance of voting to close immediately. For example, from a comment:

> Perhaps this isn't actually written down. It's just the way some set of people like to do things.

I agree that it's not feasible to write an algorithm that dictates the objectively correct behaviour of every Stack Overflow user. However, my claim is that the policy of voting for closure immediately **does**, in fact, directly follow from other explicit policies, considering the *stated justifications* for those policies.

So, I'm going to work it out from first principles, slowly and painfully.

### Why do we close questions?

**Every** formal reason why questions are supposed to be closed, is a reason **that potential answers to that question would be counterproductive** to the goal of building a library of high-quality, detailed answers.

Such answers *could not in principle* be high quality, because they are *necessarily* at least one of:

- **off topic** - because the *question* is off topic (including proposed migrations)
- **inappropriately opinionated** - because the question is *inappropriately subjective* (requests for third-party resources partially overlap this category and the previous one)
- **not researchable after the fact** - because the question is *unclear* (which for our purposes includes not being written in English), *unfocused* or *doesn't have a clear, sensible reproduction* (needs debugging details or was caused by a typo)
- **in the wrong place** - because the question is a *duplicate*.

That's it. That covers all the reasons we have.

We've been through multiple iterations of discussion trying to figure out those reasons, hammering on why people found previous attempts like ["too localized"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22too+localized%22) and ["lacks minimal understanding"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22lacks+minimal+understanding%22) and ["not a real question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22not+a+real+question%22) useful, but ultimately judged them inappropriate. It's been many years, and many clumps of hair have been torn out.

By now we are pretty confident that we have a pretty good idea of what's important for questions. And, again, **every last one** of these things **necessarily** interferes with answer quality.

### What are the consequences of question closure?

- First and foremost: the question **cannot be answered until it is reopened**.
- A question that is closed and *also* reaches a score of -3, becomes eligible for deletion votes (from an even smaller pool of users).
- "Abandoned" closed questions [can get automatically deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) after *nine days*, if *nothing* happens. OP, or anyone else with editing privileges, can reset this clock by making any edit to the question. Any accepted edit also resets the clock. The deletion is suspended *indefinitely* as long as there is *any* outstanding vote to reopen (unless another rule applies). The system will not delete questions with a +1 or higher score, ever, unless OP's *account* was deleted (and even then it takes *at least a year*).
- Users with a particular interest in curation can explicitly search for closed questions by adding `closed:1` to a search query.

#### What are NOT consequences of question closure?

- Closed questions are **not "deleted"** or in any other way gone.
- Closed questions [**can be found with web searches**](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+the+definitive+guide+to+form-based+website+authentication). In fact, questions closed as duplicates *play a vital role* in SEO; if you visit one as a logged-out user, it automatically redirects to the duplicate target. Search engine results find these *all the time*, and the company *wants* this to happen.
- Closed questions are **not simply removed** from feeds.
- Closed questions **can be edited** by *all the same people who could edit it before.* Those who edit the question can explicitly propose that the question should be reopened, which puts it in a review queue for express consideration.
- Closed questions **can be commented on** by *all the same people who could comment before*, which *includes the person who asked regardless of reputation*. Those comments can be used for *all the same purposes as before*, such as (without limitation):

  - specifically explaining *why* a question is a duplicate;
  - showing *where* the typo is;
  - noting what is missing for a *reproducible* example;
  - noting that there is a bunch of code irrelevant to a *minimal* example;
  - highlighting *what* is unclear about the question;
  - *proposing a way* to make a question more objective and thus answerable.

### Why should we, at all, close questions that meet closure reasons?

Of course, we are not actually *mandated* to do this. No specific person is responsible for it happening. Close votes are presented as a privilege rather than a responsibility.

However, a clear sense of *duty* arises from a simple logical argument:

1. When a question is closed, that **prevents people from answering it**.
2. If a question meets closure reasons, **any answer to that question would necessarily be "low quality"**, per the site's concept of quality, and by the construction of those reasons.
3. Low quality answers **do not belong in a library** of high quality answers; they inherently lower overall quality and are counterproductive to the stated goal of building such a library.
4. Therefore, closing a question that meets closure reasons **prevents an action that is inherently counterproductive**.
5. The world is full of people who don't understand the goals of the communities they belong to. Preventing inherently counterproductive actions, especially ones that are at least plausibly well intentioned, is a good and necessary thing for building strong communities.
6. QED.

### Why should we not wait to do so?

1. There is **no meaningful, evident benefit** to waiting. It isn't being nice to people to wait before telling them that they did something wrong. It needs to be said anyway. Telling them sooner allows for a quicker response incorporating that feedback, and doesn't abandon them in an un-educated state. The biggest effect that can even be argued for is that OP could be given, say, 9 days and 30 minutes to edit the question, instead of just 9 days - which is arguably not even a net positive anyway.
2. There **is a clear and obvious harm** caused by waiting, which is [commonly remarked upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22fastest+gun+in+the+west%22) (enough to merit an [abbreviation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=FGITW) and even an inconsistently-used [tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastest-gun) on Meta). Answers posted by someone seeking reputation from the [flawed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387550) reputation system - or "just trying to be helpful" - degrade the site, in aggregate. They encourage further inappropriate use of the site as if it were a help desk; they lower average answer quality by adding answers that duplicate or misplace good information or drown it in wild guesses and irrelevant debugging trails; and they inhibit automatic cleanup of bad questions (especially since people who ask bad questions and get a seemingly-helpful answer have a high chance of *accepting* that answer, which means the question can *never* be automatically deleted).

### How big of a problem has been caused by waiting?

Here's a simple search showing [**more than a hundred thousand**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+duplicate%3A0+hasaccepted%3A1+score%3A..-1) (as of this writing, almost 120 thousand) questions meeting these criteria:

- negative score - meaning they were **actively judged bad** by the community
- closed, not as a duplicate - meaning they **aren't helping find** a better question (and are difficult and disruptive to re-close as duplicates, for whichever of them actually are duplicates)
- have accepted answers - meaning they **can't be automatically deleted**

That represents *serious and widespread harm* done to the site, that would not happen if close-voters were faster than misguided answer writers (grace periods notwithstanding). This also, likely, greatly understates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to discuss the issues relating to closing the question in 0 seconds. "*Why wait for more than zero seconds?*" Here's why.

- Gold badge holders: Once a close vote is cast, the OP edits a question to clarify and you find it's a duplicate, you can't close it as duplicate again. I'm sure most gold badge holders prefer the dupe hammer than other close reasons.
- Better close reason feedback: Since you can't retract your close vote and recast it and multiple close reasons are not allowed, Sometimes you would want to give a better reason for your close vote. Commenting opens up direct   interaction/contention from the OP and is better avoided.
- Reopen queue tardiness:  It's painfully slow to get a question reopened, if at all. SOCVR and chat rooms help speed things up. But even then sometimes it takes days especially in tag chat rooms (relatively niche tag). In SOCVR, you have to contend with users without expertise in your tag that this question is worth reopening. The whole process leaves a bad taste. Sometimes you have a great answer and question is great too (except for a minor clarification), closing and reopening and going through the whole process to post a great answer is not worth the effort.

#### Related:

[We need to improve the chances of reopening closed questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402422/we-need-to-improve-the-chances-of-reopening-closed-question)

Unless the reopen queue is fixed, You can't convince borderline voters to cast close votes without reservation.

Comment: I agree that the reopen process is not useful.  The people that cast close votes are never notified when the question gets edited so, even if they were so inclined to reevaluate after edits (which most probably aren't anyway), they probably won't even know it was edited.  And, just practical experience on the site says that it's pointless to hope for a reopen.  Practically speaking, it's better to post a new question with better content and that's what I recommend newbies do after they get a question closed.

Comment: @jfriend00 Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401960

Comment: The close queue is where questions go to die. Most questions need some clarification so according to the zero-second crowd, most questions should be closed. Many can unilaterally close while reopening takes 3 votes. You don't need to leave a comment to close, so the poster and others can't even ask you to clarify the close. Closers are not notified of edits and are not forced in some way to reevaluate the close. I am all for closing either inherently bad questions or after clarifying questions are ignored. But since closing is much easier than reopening, not right away.

Comment: @tdelaney I agree. I don't understand `Many can unilaterally close while reopening takes 3 votes`. Those gold hammers can close as well as reopen with a single vote.

Answer (score -11):

Stack Overflow has a bad reputation for new users.  It's seen as a pretty hostile place.  If you don't post a good question, you get hammered with downvotes or close votes.  Seasoned vets may have survived the trial-by-fire here and now see it as a rite of passage, but the SO community loses tons of potential users because of the way newbies are treated and that reputation keeps others from even trying.

It should be possible to **maintain or improve overall question quality**, but have a **better process for newbie users who are still learning how to write a good SO question**.

The folks at Stack Exchange appear to be working on such a system to better onboard new users which is currently being referred to as "staging ground".  You can read about it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416428/introducing-the-staging-ground-an-attempt-at-improving-the-first-time-asker-exp) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416652/new-user-experience-deep-dive-into-our-research-on-the-staging-ground-how-do).

Some tolerance for people who don't have great communication skills, but who are willing to engage and clarify would also be useful.

Here's my process for dealing with an unclear question.

1. If the question is so far from describing anything relevant to SO (beyond salvage IMO), then I may just downvote and close vote regardless of how long it's been since it was posted.  I will try to leave a comment with a link to how to write a good question or a link to what's on topic here in hopes that the newbie at least sees that as something important to read before posting again.
2. If it was posted more than a couple hours ago and people have asked clarifying questions in the comments and the OP is not engaging or responding, I vote to close and may downvote also.  In my opinion, if people engaged to help and you weren't around to engage and the question doesn't stand on its own, then it should be closed.  When I'm feeling generous, I will leave a comment telling the OP that people tried to engage to help, but they weren't around to respond and on SO, you have to be around for at least the next hour after posting in case people don't completely understand what you were asking.  Don't post and then go to sleep or out to dinner.  Post when you can check back multiple times in the next hour.
3. If the question is new (like posted in the last 30 minutes) and has some skeleton of an on-topic issue and I have time to be around over the next 30 minutes, I will engage and ask some clarifying questions in the comments.  If no response in the next 30-60 minutes, then go to #2 above and close.  If the OP engages and is starting to clarify what they meant, I will try to coach them on how to edit their question to fix it and I will hope that other drive-by readers (who aren't participating in the coaching) don't just close the question that we're working on (though that happens a lot).
4. If the question is new and others have engaged with trying to clarify the question, I will just skip on by and hope that others can continue to work with the OP to clarify.  I personally see no point in dropping a downvote or close vote on a question that is "being worked".  If the question stays in bad shape over time (engagement to fix stops or question is just never edited to fix it), it will get cleaned up by others.  But, there's no great service to be done for anyone, by hammering the question while it's being worked on.

Comment: How many questions can you handle with this approach? How often do you think it works for the question or better yet the asker long-term?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - I think it works a lot better for everyone in the long term.  The asker gets a chance to get coaching on how to fix their question and often gets an answer to their question and isn't left with a bad impression of SO.  I'm not sure how that is worse than an avalanche of close votes with no feedback at all for the OP and I see lots of ways its better. I handle the questions I see like this that I have time for.  If others did the same, it would scale just fine.

Comment: Re *"Don't post and then go to sleep or out to dinner."*: The question wizard sets up an expectation of a time scale of several days (it talks about getting notification by email the next day) and says nothing about the real time scale of minutes to hours—at least the last time I checked (it could have changed).

Comment: @PeterMortensen - The staging ground will presumably have a completely different expectation for timing and will depend upon how many people are acting as reviewers. My comment about "don't post and then go to sleep" was about today's questions that are immediately public and can easily get closed within 30 minutes if the OP isn't responsive to clarify or fix the question. So, I advise people today that they should be online and checking in several times for the next hour after posting a question if they don't want their question to get downvoted or closed for being non-responsive to problems.

Comment: Closure of the question ***is*** the process. Closing the question prevents answers from rolling in, which will be invalidated by any edits that are made to the question. Closure doesn't mean that you are not allowed to work with the author to help them improve their post. In fact, that's exactly what you *should* do after closing a question. Once it gets to a point where it meets our requirements, you should even vote to reopen it. But you should not hold off on closing while this back-and-forth happens, as that creates new problems. **What you're suggesting here contradicts site policy.**

Comment: This has nothing to do with friendliness or new users, and the suggestion that it does is, frankly, offensive. The requirements apply equally to all users. Now, of course, if you can edit a post to fix it yourself, without any involvement from the asker, then, no, there is no reason to close it. That would be simply punitive (and wrong, since, after the edits, there's no justifiable reason to close the question). But if you need input/clarification from the asker, you are expected to vote to close until that is provided. No exceptions. **Closure indicates it is "being worked" on**.

Comment: @CodyGray - Which exact part of my answer contradicts site policy?

Comment: The "process" you describe. Specifically, the part where you describe waiting some time before close-voting and/or not close-voting unclear questions.

Comment: @CodyGray - Where exactly is the site policy spelled out that it is my obligation to close vote something when someone is working with the OP to clarify the question?  Please point me to the specific page on SO's site that says that.

Comment: That's an oddly specific request; no, there's no page that's going to say that. However, you can see clearly on *this very page* that the policy which has widespread support from the community is that questions that are unclear should be closed immediately. This is the entire design of the feature, as I have carefully explained in multiple earlier comments. Can we force you to follow it? Well, I guess not. We can't effectively force users to do anything. But that doesn't make it not policy.

Comment: @CodyGray Community consensus cannot be described as official site policy.

Comment: Where do you think site policy gets set, @TheMaster? The site is run by the community. If you're unhappy with that, then take it from a moderator, which is the closest thing you're going to get to setting and enforcing site policy.

Comment: That's what I was wondering.  Perhaps this isn't actually written down.  It's just the way some set of people like to do things.  And, the audience here in Meta is far, far, far from an average set of SO users so I take a vote here only as what high reputation users want - not representative of the avg user at all.  The avg reputation in this question alone is over 200k.

Comment: As the leadership of SO has found, the experience for new users is often not very good.  Slamming questions closed and mass downvoting within minutes of posting without any specific feedback directly to the OP on what they need to fix or any engagement to welcome them and help them fix their question leads to a crappy user experience and is why SO has the unfriendly reputation for newbies that it has.  Fortunately, the folks at SO are looking beyond what's in this set of answers from high rep users.

Comment: "Seasoned vets may have survived the trial-by-fire here and now see it as a rite of passage" - no; it is a tool for **curating the library** that is composed of those questions and their answers; questions which exist **to be part of that library, not simply** to prompt an answer that gets OP out of a jam. **Absolutely none of this is about** the people doing the asking - except insofar as they refuse to respond to the vital feedback which you propose to deprive them of (by allowing reputation-seeking ne'er-do-wells to attempt an answer that OP may mistakenly view as "helpful").

Comment: "Perhaps this isn't actually written down. It's just the way some set of people like to do things." - No; it's the natural and intended consequence of what is written down, as understood by consensus. It turns out that it's not feasible to write an algorithm that dictates the objectively correct behaviour of every Stack Overflow user. But "you should VTC immediately on something that merits closure" **follows naturally and automatically** from a) the purpose of closure; b) the consequences of closure; c) the justification for the standard reasons for closure.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - A VTC on a newbie question without any feedback back to them as to what is wrong or expected is just a crappy newbie user experience (which SO is known for). It's like sending your child to sit in the corner facing the wall as punishment for 20 minutes without telling them what they did wrong.  It's not a very effective way at teaching proper behavior. SO is nothing without users and all users start as newbies, not trained in the way of SO. The more and better trained SO users, the more valuable the community. Giving newbies a crappy user experience is not best for anyone.

Comment: "A VTC on a newbie question without any feedback back to them" - a VTC **is feedback**, and **does not in any way prevent** giving more specific feedback. This has been explained **repeatedly** and I don't understand how it can be made any clearer.

Answer (score -15):

So we've got 3 answers for zero seconds. I don't like them.

Unless I think a question is really bad I'll leave a comment and bookmark it and come back in an hour or so. If I haven't gotten an intelligent response then I close vote.

Reason: close votes can be revoked, but if you revoke your close vote you can't cast it again.

Comment: The fact that this answer has so many downvotes (along with the tenor of the other answers here) shows the bias (among the meta crowd) against any patience or tolerance for helping newbies get established here and learn the ropes.  Apparently, it's ***figure it out on your own or get out of here and I'm not going to help you in the least bit***.  No wonder SO has such a bad reputation for new users.  I think that's unfortunate and ultimately limits how many people SO can be useful for.