# What to do when a language barrier makes a post unclear?

Tags: discussion

Many people from all over the world can be found in this community. This cultural diversity is a favorable factor, but it can bring certain problems due to language differences.

There are often misunderstandings between askers and answers. For example, a user might ask a question that seems interesting and shows research effort, but because he explains it poorly, it is unclear. And vice versa—there could be someone who answers a question that provides the right solution, but whose explanation is a bit messy. (If the answer isn't correct, this isn't so much of a problem!)

I feel like I am personally an example of this. I think I am pretty good at English, but I don't have a very wide vocabulary, especially when it comes to technical terms. As a result, sometimes my explanations are not very clear.

So my question is, when we identify a question or answer (mainly questions) that is unclear because of the way it is written (probably because of linguistic difficulties), what should we do? Should we leave a comment asking the person who wrote it to improve it? Should we edit it ourselves? Downvote it? Vote to close it? Or something else?

Comment: Edit it.​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: The edit may make it unclear to the question poster. A comment would be the best bet - ask the poster to edit it himself.

Comment: If it is truly a language problem and not a laziness problem, then asking the person to fix it themselves is not a reasonable solution. They already did their best. You can dress it up all you want, but ultimately you're just commenting: *"Your English sucks. I have no idea what you're saying. Fix it."* The person is likely to think, *"I would if I could!"* Most people who really have difficulty speaking/writing the language are appreciative of others who make edits to their posts. They use it as a learning opportunity. Besides, the larger goal is to improve the site. If your edit does that...

Comment: You could also ask the asker to write the problem in his/her own language and run the question trough google-translator - I bet that makes it more clear. Google has given us the perfect means to communicate without knowing any other language than mothers ;)

Comment: If it's sufficiently unclear that you're not sure if your edit would change the intended meaning or not, ask "Did you mean..."? first.  Many people are better with reading comprehension than their writing skills might suggest.

Comment: I think I might have an example of that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308025/how-can-i-continue-to-play-my-gif-during-javascript-treatment-my-gif-freeze-dur#24308025. *Treatment* anyone?

Comment: Treatment is probably from *traitement*, a French word meaning process(ing).

Comment: @SickDimension Unfortunately, Google Translate to English only works well with languages that have similar sentence structures as English. For example, Google's Korean -> English is rather lousy, and its Mandarin -> English isn't that good either.

Comment: Not so much here, but in another venue where we often get questions that are unclear for language or terminology reasons, I'll reply with something like:  "To be sure that I understand your question correctly, let me re-state it. Please correct me if I've gotten it wrong."  And then rewrite the question, as best I understand it, as clearly simply as I can.

Comment: @Quincunx, yup I wouldn't seriously recommend g-trans to anyone I was being a bit sarcastic. More or less I think there is no way helping the poor bastards whom haven't mastered english to make the question more understandable. But should these questioners be put on hold or something else depends of the case.. Punishing for bad language skills seems bit unfair, but sometimes for the good of the community has to be done.

Comment: About a quarter of the edits I make have the reason 'Anglification' as the listed, or part of the listed, reason. That's part of editing.

Comment: @SickDimension I agree with Quincunx in that Google translate doesn't always work well. I use it to translate from spanish words or small sentences which I'm not sure about how to write, and in theses cases is very useful. But other many times I've tryed to translate longer things or spanish expresion that when translated to english don't make sense.

Comment: oh - in these cases I often tell the OP **go ahead and also write your question in your own language**. Due to the incredible busy-body factor on the internet, within 5 minutes there is a flawless, beautiful technical translation by a professor of that language, there on the site.

Comment: Well, english _is_ part of the site. So i really can't see a problem here.

Answer (score 24):

The usual quality rules still apply. We don't want to be a cesspool of crap.

That said, such a situation demands a little more patience with the user to give him the opportunity to clarify. If it is just a language barrier (and not an unwillingness to cooperate for example) a little patience can result in a great question or answer. Language problems tend to be temporary and resolvable.

If clarification cannot be obtained in a reasonable amount of time and with reasonable effort we do what we always do: close or downvote.

Comment: You should always close unclear questions immediately.  If/when they are clarified they can be reopened.

Comment: @Servy as long as it's actually unclear, and couldn't be made clear  from an edit. If you can edit it and make it clear, don't close vote it.

Comment: @hichris123 If you feel that you can edit a question such that it won't meet the closure guidelines, then yes, you're free to do so (thus leaving no need to vote to close).  However, you are not *obligated* to fix the post for the question author, and as such it is not incorrect to vote to close the question.  At the end of the day it is the responsibility of the question author to fix their question.  Other are welcome to, but not obligated to, help them do so.

Comment: link relevant to my first comment that I didn't edit in in time: [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing/260265#260265)

Comment: @Servy but does reopening work in practice? I don't think I have ever witnessed it.

Comment: @usr Sure it does.  Before the reopen queue it was rather hard to get to, but with it it's not a problem at all.

Comment: "We don't want to be a cesspool of crap." should be the new motto for Meta.

Comment: I don't agree that language problems are temporary.  Language difficulties have been around as long as farming has.  It does require a great deal of patience, and that same patience would be wasted on laziness.

Comment: @WalterMitty to clarify: I meant temporary in the sense that with a little back and forth a question can be clarified within minutes. I wasn't speaking of waiting for them to learn English to a higher degree of proficiency. (Not sure if this was just a misunderstanding.)

Comment: Calling non-english speakers efforts to help people out *cesspool of crap* is really offensive to them and discouraging nonetheless.

Comment: @abdellahmansur if a post is crap because of a language barrier it is still crap and invites even more crap. The broken window syndrome. This is not a negative judgment of the people creating unclear posts. It is a value judgement about the posts themselves. No matter who wrote them or why. The standards are the same for everyone.

Answer (score 6):

You do the same thing that you do with any unclear question you ever come across.  You vote/flag for closure, to prevent low quality answers until the question is clarified.

You can then do any (or none) of the following options as you see fit:

- comment with clarifying questions or information on what should be improved
- edit the post to improve clarity, to the degree that you can
- downvote to indicate to other potential readers that the questions is unclear

Comment: I try to edit first. It's difficult, but I kind of enjoy it, and after years of doing this sort of thing, I've gotten rather capable at it. I can even sort of tell sometimes what the mother tongue of the author is by the very characteristic errors they make. I hate to just downvote without atleast asking myself if I couldn't improve the post. It seems weak and petty somehow....

Comment: I'm with you on waiting zero seconds to close vote. In the normal case. If I feel *confident* that I can edit a post into a perfectly reasonable state, something that I might even post myself, I will do so without casting a close vote. This is, however, quite rare.

Comment: @Servy asking from my ignorance, suposing that instead of editing the question you decide to close it and ask the writer to improve or clarify it (this supposing that the writer hasn't done it it's best) and he improves his question... how does he notify that he has improved his question and asks to reopen it? Is there a way to do this once the question is closed? Or must he wait till someone reviews his post to reopen it?

Comment: I am strongly against this. It's basically bullying. You don't want to chase people away before they know what they are doing wrong.

Comment: @ouflak If you want to do that that's great.  Keep in mind the vast majority of people aren't *capable* of doing that (at least for a lot of the really bad posts), even if they wanted to.  It also tends to be rather time consuming.  Between those two factors, along with the shear volume of bad questions that the site gets, it's just not *possible* for the community to fix every single bad post that it gets.  And that's not even considering posts that just straight up don't have enough information, clear or not.

Comment: @masmic_87 The act of editing puts it in the reopen queue, so these types of questions can very easily get reopened.

Comment: @reinierpost This is a site that has standards.  It's here to have quality content.  This is made *abundantly* clear to new users in *several* ways before they are *allowed* to post a question.  When someone is so inconsiderate as to make no effort to understand or follow even the site's most basic rules before asking the community to spend considerable time helping them solve a problem that they have, informing them that their question is not acceptable is not bullying.  Not even close.  It's not even impolite.  *They* are being rude and impolite.

Comment: @reinierpost   Closing, commenting, editing, and downvoting is *how you tell someone that they are doing something wrong, and how you help them fix it.  It is being *actively helpful* to them, as it is teaching them how to ask a good question, which is a very valuable skill.  Trying to answer an unclear question is *actively harmful* to them, much more so than helping them fix their question.  If users are unwilling to spend the time and effort improving their question and are only willing to accept being given an answer to a poor quality question then *we don't want them here*.

Comment: @Servy: exactly. Now the question is how these means should be used. I say: comment, edit and dovnvote right away, but only vote to close after the OP has passed on a chance to clean up.

Comment: @reinierpost Voting to close immediately prevents poor quality answers to the unclear question, informs the user that their question, as it stands, is unanswerable, provides them information helping them understand (to a degree) why that is, etc.  All good stuff, all things that should be done *immediately* for the greatest benefit.  There is no benefit in waiting, and a lot of potential harm.

Comment: @Servy: Well, we'll have to agree to disagree then until I see some statistics on the effects of immediate closing vs. waiting.

Answer (score 3):

Simply edit it, and leave a very short comment: "I possibly had trouble understanding what you meant in English, I've edited it a little."

Note that Cody's first comment was "Edit it".  It's that simple.

This question goes to the whole overall bizarre...

## "People seem scared to edit for some reason..."

..issue.

Just edit everything all the time.

When in doubt, click the edit button.  Edit, edit, edit.

Someone go ahead and edit this answer.

It's possible that the entire "meta" thing in SO should be programmed so that, whenever anyone tries to post a question here on Meta, the computer first says "Wait, why don't you just edit the post in question first ..."  Heh.