# Are we giving new users the wrong impression by the way we're writing and displaying our posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, design, etiquette

<sup>Note: Due to the post's complex-ish nature I've had to split this proposal into 5 sections; therefore, I could not completely summarize the entire post into one paragraph. Simply put, **there isn't a "tl;dr" section**, there is however, an "In conclusion" section. I'd also like to point-out that I do not expect *any* of my *suggested* solutions to be implemented, as they are just that, suggestions; for all I care, none of them could materialise. The core reason why I'm posting this is to simply make known the issues I have observed.</sup>

### Why do we even exist?

Before I start explaining the problems I've noticed (and the proposed solutions), I would just like to remind everyone *why* SO exists,

> > ...to build a *library* of detailed answers to every question about programming.

<sup><sup>(Emphesis mine, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/tour))</sup></sup>

There are several things we can take from that,

- We are a **library**. Not a forum, not a [sorry excuse](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111111001245AAqtc3G) [for a](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140329212721AAUMKuF) [Q&A site](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111003103359AAXyFS6), but a *library* (albeit in the form of a Q&A site),
- Answers (should) have greater dominance than questions. We are aiming to be, "a library of detailed *answers*", not, "a library of detailed questions",
- Questions must obviously relate to programming.

Try to keep those points in mind while reading.

### The problems...

First of all, if you open the first 5 posts<sup>1</sup> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), I can *guarantee* you'll find that one of those questions are,

- Laking teh must basik prinsipals off inglish landguage (spelling, grammar, structure, etc),
- Too informal (displaying too much of an "informal social connection"<sup>2</sup> with the community). It's written as though it's the start of a forum thread, meaning the post usually contains one of the following: "please help", "i'm a newbie", "hope this helps", etc,
- **Overly** <sup>(or <sup>incorrectly</sup>)</sup> `form`*atted* (or completely missing even the most basic markdown),
- Not detailed enough (or the OP has dumped his entire codebase).
- A nice mixture of any of the above.

These *are* problems, as they,

- Reduce the site's professional appearance,
- Are cluttering the site with "undesirable" questions. Which also (unintentionally?) results in users subjectivly upvoting answers to said posts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23811669/2246344), note the answer has *6* upvotes),
- Are putting an unnecessary strain on the system (e.g, the Close Vote queue).

And yes, there are [users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14348808/2246344) that think we're a forum. One source that's giving them that impression is how most posts are constructed. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16376394/2246344) a typical example; note, the question is written in the [first person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_narrative#First-person_view) and also has "Please help..." slapped on at the end (and of course, the answer ends in, "Good luck!")<sup>3</sup>. Yet again more characteristics of a forum thread.

Overall, posts that are written like that just aren't helping us reach our goals; the question itself may be great, but the way users are conveying their question/answer is, itself, questionable.

### We all need a little reminder

Therefore, I suggest we should remind *all* users while typing up their post (display an uninterruptive<sup>4</sup> message somewhere). Maybe saying something like this,

> > Stack Overflow is **not** a forum.
> >
> > [Salutations](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/salutation), [valedictions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/valediction) and [informalities](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/informality?q=informalities) of any kind, *are not necessary*. Please try to write your post in the [third person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_narrative#Third-person_view) (with a [passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice)). That is, write the post as if it were going to be displayed at a royal public library.

### Post layout 2.0

The current post UI layout is fine for smaller posts that only require a couple of flicks of the mouse wheel to reach the page's bottom. But for very detailed/long posts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/2246344)) the layout can become very clubersome and cluttered, even "inconveinant" at times (due to the question's and answers' large size it can take noticablely longer to find a specific answer).

Therefore, I finally propose a post design clean-up, that is,

- Fade out the rest of the post's body that reaches over a certain size and add a "hide/show" button,
- Hide all comments and just show the "add/show comments" button,
- (Optional) And for users without an account, hide the post's: favorite count, score (votes) & and bounty awarded.

Here's an example showing only the first two answers with the question; [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izKKh.jpg) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQEXc.jpg). As you can see, the after shot is considerably "cleaner", and we still get to keep the same old functionality.

So how do these UI improvements help?

1. The (non-loggedin) reader is less distracted by "unnecessary" information, such as: comments, score, favorites, etc. (As previously stated) with posts being shorter, this also helps users find the answer they're looking for,
2. By hiding comments by default we increase the site's professional/formal appearance. Which gives new users a "subtle" reminder that we're not an informal Q&A site/forum,
3. Increased flagging/editing efficiency, as users don't have to scroll to the very bottom of the post in order to flag/edit it.

### In conclusion

I know I'm probably overemphasizing SO's "informalness" and the idea of SO being a Q&A library. That is due to my observations, which have lead me to feel as though, "the scales are leaning too far on the 'informal' side" for most new users (I know a *little* informality is fine, but it's a matter of correctly judging how far is too far). It seems they either don't understand that there's a distinction between being informal and formal, or, they have inaccurately decerned what is and isn't being (in)formal. Either way, I believe these users could do with a helping hand from the community.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Although, post quality does seem to fluctuate with date and time. At one time 2 out of 3 posts were edit/flag worthy, and at other times this would drop to 1 in 5.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> I'm not a sociologist (or a psychologist for that matter) so that probably isn't the most accurate way to describe it. If you know of a better term/phrase feel free to edit away.</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> I don't by any way mean to criticise/pick-on the OPs in that example. The fact of the matter is there are simply many, *many* posts of this style, not just that particular one.</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup> A message that *does not* force the user to stop and read it in order to continue.</sup>

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I think it's wrong to attribute wider problems with posts to things like use of the first person. The idea of a "forum" vs "library" mentality might have some merit, but honestly with most of the big problems, a perceptive user would already know "compared to the other questions I've seen, my question is impossible to understand", etc. So really all you'd cut down on by discouraging informality is informality, not actual low question quality. The cost, in terms of reviewer, editor, and site dev time wouldn't be worth it

Comment: "Salutations, valedictions and informalities of..." Someone with poor English is going to read that, wince, and move on, ignoring it entirely!

Answer (score 4):

### Stack Overflow was never a library

Is that what we aspire to?  Absolutely, especially with posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).  But that's never going to happen on Stack Overflow organically.  It requires users [like these](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) who are willing to spend their time contributing high-quality content.  Let's face it: most of us are not up for that.

What Stack Overflow is (mostly) is a better alternative to forums.

### Moderation is an active process

The way you reduce shoddy posts on Stack Overflow is by availing yourself of the tools that have been provided to accomplish that.  There isn't going to be any text you put in front of people or automated tools that will solve that problem completely.

### Communicate!

Comments are very useful, if you use them properly.  If you don't feel like typing them, use [this proforma script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).  The key to writing good comments is that they must be informative, authoritative, firm but neutral in tone.

> - [Please don't put greetings, signatures, pleas for help or thank you's in your posts.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)  Every post you write has a signature card at the bottom right-hand corner that shows your user name and gravatar.  On Stack Overflow we show our appreciation by [upvoting and accepting answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).
> - In English, `I` and the first word of every sentence is always capitalized.  If English is not your first language, consider running your posts through a spell checker, or have someone proofread your posts first.

### Edit or close/downvote!

After you post your comment, edit the post to conform.

*Know when to edit.*  If the post is too much work or is not salvageable via editing, just vote to close and downvote it.  [Don't wait for the OP or someone else to clean it up.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/102937)