# Add a flag for the most frequent comments to questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've decided recently to give back to Stack Overflow for all the good it did to me in my programming career. But the more I answer questions, the more I become frustrated at some things. Let me explain :

Every second question is posted by a beginner/new user and it typically involves a desperate plea for help and a cryptic error message.

A few seconds later, these questions are invariably reacted to in 3 ways :

1. the angry users downvote (and sometimes voice their anger in some
   unconstructive comment).
2. the less angry users comment : "Show us some code", or "What have you tried"
3. the phlegmatic users ignore the question.

I'm currently in the second category, but increasingly going towards the third... I guess in a year I'll be a 1. 
Could it be a way to flag these questions in one click with a 'request for code' or 'show what you tried' without making the OP feel slapped in the face (the angry commenters will take care of that anyway). It could include a link to the guidelines.

I'm not saying that anyone should have this possibility, maybe we could restrict it to trusted users only, or users who have one of the tag badges the question is related to. Just an idea, what do you thin?

Comment: [see this](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) But please don't make your comments snarky like _Show us some code_, etc. I understand the frustration but there are better ways to ask for code.

Comment: That's awesome! Although it could be useful to make it a per-site feature as I'm sure that not many people know about this. I'm sure the gods of SO have some analytics on the most used comments.

Comment: VTC Unclear what you are asking, move on.

Comment: @bluefeet I'm not angry yet! I'll at least make it courteous, it doesn't cost much as I'll type it only once. Thanks again

Comment: I like this idea. If there was a secondary voting paradigm to nudge the OP to provide more information/code, that would be useful. It would relieve frustrated commenters of writing "snarky" comments while at the same time provide the OP with a notification (or series of notifications) for more thought on their behalf. I wouldn't however call my suggestion as a fix to this issue pre-populated comments but something else.

Comment: @AlexSmith Yes, maybe a notification similar to the flags, very visible. But in a non-blocking way so OP can make his question better and maybe get an answer if the question is trivial.

Comment: The way this is going, why not just ask that when a question gets a close vote, the reason be visible to the OP? I'd rather not see close-voting be diluted with some sort of parallel system that does not actually close questions.

Comment: A cryptic error message is a step up the ladder from many questions.  Pages of nasty multidimensional-array code with 'i,j,k,l' indices, no comments, no input data, no output data, no aparrent attempt to debug at all, no error messages and 'Doesn't work right, do all the hard, boring debugging for me' are at least two rungs lower.

Comment: There used to be a couple of closing codes that fairly well covered these situations, but they were yanked in the closing code massacre about a year ago.

Comment: @HotLicks "why isn't this code working?" and "unclear what you are asking" VTC reasons still easily cover more than 90% of such questions, at the same time giving more or less clear feedback to the OP. Of course it won't help with specific cases that do not fit those reasons, but they are usually far too peculiar for either VTC or autocomment to really change anything.

Comment: You should already be in the "1" category and not feel bad about it; these crap questions deserve downvotes and the more they get the better.

Comment: Downvoting crap is fine, but ... it's not a good introduction to the site to get trampled without figuring out why. It feels a bit snarky to repost 'how to ask a good question' links, but I think it at least helps steer in the right direction.

Comment: @EugenePodskal - There needs to be a "read the damn documentation" closing code again.  There was once a "poorly researched" code that fit pretty well.

Comment: I'm more in the #1 camp, but i'm not angry. Downvoting, while it may seem like a hostile action, is more constructive than posting comments such as "what have you tried". Downvote and move on. they'll get the message and ask better questions or they won't and we won't have to see their questions for much longer due to the rate-limiting system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could it be a way to flag these questions in one click with a 'request for code' or 'show what you tried' without making the OP feel slapped in the face (the angry commenters will take care of that anyway). It could include a link to the guidelines.

This [feature](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) already exists IMHO, but few extra clicks away from your current expectation.

> [image].

There are few other close reasons as well, such as *unclear what you're asking, too broad etc*.

Once 5 `3k+` users vote to close for the above reason, The question will be put on hold (*It doesn't accept answers*) and the OP is presented with a label similar to the following:

> [image]

It does include helpful links to [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), as well as other relevant ones such as  [how to create a Minimal, Complete & Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the close reason mentioned above.

Closing such questions as soon as possible will prevent low quality answers - Such Answers prevents Low Quality or Off Topic questions from eventually [getting deleted automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion). If the question could be improved to fit the rules of community - OP can improve it while it is on hold, and It'll receive quality answers once it is opened.

So, personally I don't like this idea. I like what [Servy says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/2333214): If the question is not clear, close it ASAP.

---

If you patiently keep contributing for a little while more, You'll get this [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: I think very few people -- questioners or answerers -- would interpret "too broad" to mean "show what you've tried".

Comment: Which is why i mentioned *"the currently available option"* - I've seen plenty of questions showing no effort getting closed as *too broad*... In most of the cases, there will be many ways of doing one thing - if the OP doesn't show the path he's currently on - then it's kind of *too broad*, even if it is a silly thing - **there are too many possible answers** in general

Comment: But that's a misuse of the closing code.  "Too broad" is "Explain Java to me".  Opie is very unlikely to understand it to mean "You should have provided some code".  What's the point of closing if Opie doesn't understand the reason?

Comment: So what about questions which can be answered in a `1000` ways due to the lack of details (*read no effort*) i don't think that is accepted as well..

Comment: Just like an answer, a closing code is of no use (other than to irritate Opie) if it's not understood.

Comment: I think *there are too many possible answers* - is well understandable - if it was me, i'll do a google search and find one of the possible the answer. Anyway i'll remove it from the ans since it's not *officially* accepted.

Comment: @HotLicks TJ's example is not a misuse of the "too broad" close reason. When someone posts a question about "how to code X" without code, how do I know that their problem is how to use the language itself, how to use the API of library X, or Y, or Z, how to perform math, how linked lists work, etc? The question is "too broad" because I don't know what kind of help the person needs. If they do include what they've tried, then at least I have an idea of where they stand and what the specific problem might be.

Comment: @Louis - In general I know *exactly* what kind of help the person needs.  The trick is to get them to seek that help.

Comment: @HotLicks The rest of us do not posses the crystal ball you have so we close as too broad.

Comment: @HotLicks "What's the point of closing if Opie doesn't understand the reason?" Main reason: so that the question can be deleted. Secondary reason: so that the poster learns via [conditioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning).

Comment: @CareBear - Like I said, a closing code is of no use (other than to irritate Opie) if it's not understood.