# Is Breaking Bad actually Breaking Good?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

To unlock the [Breaking Bad hat](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/breaking-bad), one must:

> vote to close a question, edit it when closed, vote to reopen

Am I alone in thinking this is a silly thing to encourage?

If a question can be salvaged with edits, why would I first vote to close it and then wait for it to be closed before fixing whatever is wrong with it, then finally voting to reopen it?

Wouldn't an edit and a comment to the user be more beneficial than the hassle of going through this close and reopen process?

Comment: I asked this question 7 seconds ago and it's already received a down vote. Impressive...

Comment: I got the badge because the question was unclear; it was a mess. When the OP had finally added the required info, I edited it into shape and voted to reopen. The post was *not* in any shape to stay open to begin with.

Comment: "Am I alone in thinking this is a silly thing to do?" - doesn't this apply to all of hats?

Comment: @l4mpi perhaps "a silly thing to encourage" would have been a better way of putting it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hmm, that would be a perfectly valid way of obtaining this hat. Perhaps the hat would have been better as a secret hat instead. I just get the feeling people are likely to abuse this, so to speak, by waiting until a salvageable question is closed before bothering to fix it.

Comment: Secrets only last for so long (solutions are posted) so I doubt that would have been a solution.

Comment: I voted up but I can understand those who voted down. They may believe that fast closure is overall better (including better chances to reopen) than chewing gum waiting for [fastest gun hyenas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all#comment798506_244290 "'just to get some extra points...'") to pollute a question with low quality answers. See eg [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601) -- _"You should wait for zero seconds..."_

Comment: @gnat Oh I was just commenting on how fast the vote happened. The page had barely refreshed after submitting the post before the vote was given - if anything I was more impressed that another user could have gotten to this post so soon after submission; shows how active Meta is!

Comment: @gnat good analysis, but nope. I dovnwoted this question, the reason being that it is about hats and I'm quite sick of seeing questions about hats. I didn't see one yet that I'd consider useful. The exception being the original "do we want hats" question, I actually upvoted that one as it's nice to be given a choice (even though the outcome was rather obvious from the beginning).

Comment: @l4mpi I see, that one is also a sensible reason. I also tend to vote down most questions related to hats. Sometimes though these happen to make a case for an interesting _non-hat_ discussion. Quite a pity that this happens rarely

Answer (score 6):

It can also encourage positive behavior, I voted to close the following question because it didn't include a schematic showing how their temperature sensor was connected. The OP added the schematic, I gave it a further tidy-up and voted to re-open and then answered it:

[LM35 output varies when connected to microcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144113/lm35-output-varies-when-connected-to-microcontroller/144262#144262)

To be honest I'd kept an eye on questions I'd voted to close for a hat to see if they could be saved, normally I probably would have just forgotten about it and it may well have stayed closed / unanswered.