# Failed triage audit for the 2nd time

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, triage

I've failed a triage audit for the 2nd time. Maybe I'm misunderstanding triage, but I treat them as if the only two good answers are "Looks OK" or "Needs Improvement".  I will occassionaly vote to close, but 99% of the time I choose Looks OK or Needs Improvment, because - triage.

So, now the question I failed the audit for doesn't even exist: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7621960

But I've been banned from reviewing for 30 days.  What am I doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding the term triage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was the question you were given to review:

[image]

tl;dr: he's soliciting volunteers for a project he's working on. He's not asking a programming question, or looking for help with a programming problem, or doing anything else that's on-topic for Stack Overflow. There's no salvaging this question, not by you, not by the author, not by anyone else. It's **unsalvageable.**

> Am I misunderstanding the term triage?

Yeah, probably. [I explain the meaning of the term in the introduction post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage), but the instructions in the queue itself are shorter:

[image]

You're separating questions into three buckets:

- Into the first one go questions that can be answered straight away.
- Into the second go questions that need work - perhaps a lot of work - in order to be acceptable.
- Into the third go questions for which there is no real hope.

Now, here's the kicker: you have to have at least *some* idea of what the question is asking to put it in either of the first two buckets. If you can't understand it, either skip it or - if you find it unlikely that *anyone* will understand it - put it in the third category. Also good for the third bucket:

- stuff that isn't a programming question
- stuff that isn't a question at all
- stuff that shocks the conscience

Never put *any* of that in the first two buckets. You can make a mistake here and there when it comes to identifying questions that are unclear or missing details or whatever, but if it is in no way shape or form a *programming question* then you can be damn sure it has no hope here - so put it out of its misery ASAP.

Comment: This explanation is better than the current review help text.  Perhaps that text could be enhanced with the information here.

Comment: How do you find this explanation better than the current?

Comment: Your explanation makes it clear that a question that is at all salvageable belong in the second bucket, even if it would take a great deal of work to fix it up.

Comment: "edits by the author... would result in..." -- **why then send it to H&I queue?** ["If a question is unclear, or otherwise requiring clarification to be answerable, vote to close it *immediately*..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601)

Comment: ...why not just change text to "edits by readers would" etc. Options I see in H&I queue suggest just that - readers are presented only with "Edit" and "Skip", and there's no trace of anything like "ping the author to explain what they need to change to make it answerable"

Comment: So the short answer to that is simply that differentiating between "edits by readers" and "edits by author" is too nuanced a decision to be made in *triage*, @gnat. Is it sometimes possible? Sure. But expecting that decision to be made both *quickly* and *accurately* is doomed - ideally, that decision is made by topic experts. H&I throws a bit of a wrench into this by being currently the *only* effect of Should Be Improved, but it's certainly not the only *potential* effect. Working on guidance for both askers and answerers to augment this.

Comment: I understand. I think I even got the point of queues playing ping-pong. Idea looks rather beautiful but implementation appears uncomfortable for reviewers. Implicitly casting flags on their behalf and explicitly disputing these feels... counter-intuitive. Compare to recommend close from LQ queue, which didn't raise flags. Too much drama around explaining that disputed flags are painless ([and will remain as such?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243187/165773))

Comment: ...while we're at it, do "unsalvageable" Triage/H&I actions feed into close queue? if not, why?

Comment: Can you please explain why https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27787972 should go in the 3rd bucket? (If that is the correct one?) Or if not, why 2nd bucket is wrong?

Comment: Why does it need an author edit, @dagelf?