# Radical edits by the OP after answers were posted

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539448/how-can-i-assign-the-output-of-a-function-to-a-variable-in-jquery), a few answers were posted, then the OP made a fairly extensive edit that changes the question and invalidates a number of answers that had already been posted. This has caused some confusion and I'm not sure how best to handle that.

For the time being, I've rolled back the edit so the answers make sense, and asked the OP to post another question if they do, in fact, have a different question.

Is this the appropriate way to handle such things? Is there a better solution?

Comment: related: [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The OP wasn't completely changing what he was asking, rather his first revision failed to articulate his question in a way that was understandable to other readers.  He simplified the problem to such a degree that the problem wasn't understood.  The OP realized that others had failed to understand the question, and as such, he edited it to make it closer to his actual situation, and to allow readers to be able to better understand his situation.

Since it is the answers that simply misunderstood what the question was really asking (understandably, given it wasn't clear, but still) rather than a sensible question being asked and then changed to an *entirely different question*, the edit was appropriate and should stand, and the answers are simply failing to answer the question.

Comment: The edit changed the question from asking about a normal function call (and getting the return value) to an event handler and accessing a local variable later. At least, that's how I read it. If that's a correct interpretation, those *are* very different things. Am I missing something in the question?

Comment: @ssube The original version of the question was woefully unclear as to what was really being asked.  it should have been closed as unclear, not answered.  This is exactly why unclear questions should be closed, not answered; answering them only causes more confusion.  When looking at the edit, I can clearly see how the original question is asking how to solve that same problem, it just doesn't adequately express it.  You had to make some assumptions in your interpretation to read the original revision as you did; they were wrong, and the OP clarified it with his edit.

Comment: Fair enough. What should be done with the old answers, now that the OP has clarified their question? Deleted by the author?

Comment: @ssube To be a bit more specific, the example he showed in his *first* revision was a function, an execution of that function, and then code trying to get the return value of that function *after it has already been executed*.  That, not coincidentally, is *exactly* the problem that the edited version is, just with some jQuery added in to demonstrate *why* he needed to do it.  Now, the original revision should really have had a better English explanation of what he needed to clarify this, which is why I wouldn't have guessed it based on the original revision, but the OP was right to clarify.

Comment: @ssube Same thing you'd do with any answer that misunderstands the question and gives an incorrect answer as a result.

Comment: I've undone the rollback and will leave things as-is. That seems unfortunate for the folks who answered, but since the question definitely should have been closed, still reasonable.

Comment: @ssube "Answer [well-asked](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions --

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem..." ([answer])