# What option should I choose when reviewing a question that the OP has not returned to?

Tags: support, review-queues

I'm fairly new to the reviewing side of things, and I've noticed that there are lots of questions asked by users with very low rep.

I assume most of these are people who have signed up to ask a question, not got an answer straight away, and have no intention of coming back to follow up the question (I'm sure most people have experienced this when answering a question or commenting to get no response).

I'm uncertain as to what action to take on these questions that aren't strictly "off-topic", but require input. Currently I'm skipping them (which seems to be a waste of time).

If the OP needs to clarify something, or just needs to provide some input before answers can be given, then what is the appropriate action to take?

**Update**

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739429/jquery-mobile-vertical-slider/) to a question I have stumbled across while looking into one of the review queues. Would the appropriate action be to use the custom text area?

**Update 2**

My question is not a duplicate of the proposed question, because that question is asking on how long to wait. I'm asking on what should be done in the scenario provided.

The question is OK, however, it has been left to die with no activity for months. So, what is the appropriate close reason?

Comment: Your example question isn't even an hour old yet. How do you know something didn't come up just after they asked that question? It's hardly been long enough to assume the OP won't return to that specific question.

Comment: @Kendra this is not one I was going to action, but it was the first example I could find for the sake of this question

Comment: I would like to second what @Kendra said. But if the question is unclear or lacks information then use the correct CV for that ("unclear" or "off-topic-->"why isn't this code working blah blah"). If it gets closed then it will be taken care of by the system or users who can delete as appropriate for the post.

Comment: I would try to find a better example in that case, otherwise it looks a little more like impatience with the OP of the question. You want an example that really shows what you're talking about, so people can give you the most accurate advice on what you're seeing.

Comment: @Kendra - ok that makes sense I'll remove this Q and create one if I come across one, i was more asking in preparation so I knew what to do. - thanks!

Comment: No need to remove this one exactly. It's still a decent question. Your example just doesn't match your situation very well. :) It may help to know which queue(s) exactly you're working out of- The advice you receive might differ a bit dependent on queue as well.

Comment: @codeMagic - Thank you, I sort of assumed there would be a specific "question has been forgotten about with no answers" type thing, but I'll follow your and Kendra's suggestions

Comment: Nope but there is a custom box if you so wish

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing)

Comment: @gnat Not quite- That is asking how long to wait before closing, this question is asking how to handle inactive questions. Not how long to wait to close them, just what to close them as, if they need to be closed at all.

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ Inactivity of a question is not a reason to close. If the question is otherwise on-topic, clear, and reasonably scoped, then it does not need closed. Who's to say that in a week, someone won't come along and answer whatever question you're trying to close?

Comment: @Kendra that's all the clarification I need, I did not know the procedure and/or if there was a "cleaning up" process users do for old unanswered questions. But I'll look at it from the perspective you've just shown me.

Comment: @Kendra per my reading, duplicate covers exactly the kind of troublesome questions asked about here: "what to choose on these that... require input... If the OP needs to clarify something, or just needs some input before answers are given..." ==> ["vote to close it _immediately_. This... helps question authors..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601)

Comment: @gnat The question here is mostly dealing with otherwise fine questions that are just inactive. So that advice does not help the OP here, and does not answer the question asked. In other words, the answer to your proposed duplicate is "Close it, and quickly." The answer to this question is "Close the question if it should be closed, but do not close just because it hasn't been active."

Answer (score 4):

If a question still requires input from the Op to be clear, close it as "Unclear" or "Off Topic - Needs MCVE".  Vote based on the merit of the question alone, not for the user's presence or responsiveness.  A closed question can be edited and reopened later if appropriate, or deleted if it's really not on-topic.

If a question is on-topic and clear, remember that other users besides the OP will benefit from answers.  Just because they aren't around to mark an accepted answer doesn't mean the question needs to be closed.

Comment: I've just updated my question with a better example, would this be a case to use the custom text to explain?

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ either that question is looking for a library recommendation, or it's unclear. It should be closed. But that has nothing to do with the activity of the user.