# How to help if solving the question needs a lot of step by step questions to get underlaying problem?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

If we have a question where OP only can explain his problem but a real answer to the problem depends on the real problem behind the given effects how we should assist?

My question belongs to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179825/getting-no-command-gcc-found-did-you-mean-error-while-trying-to-compile-

I gave an answer which is more or less list of steps which the OP should do and post the results. Call it a diagnostic question and answer session or something.

Seconds after I post this list of questions I got a comment "This is not an answer" which is true but also not helpful.

How should we give the OP support if it is not allowed to post a step by step instruction to solve the problem?

I deleted my answer to not get the typical down vote bashing.

Additional thoughts why I think it is not a duplicate of 
[How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing)

For me the question was clear enough to find out which `problem` the user has. But if I want to find out what is the `reason` for the problem, I need more infos, which, without further questions from an "expert" a user can't give. From this point of view, it was necessary to give the questions to get the way to the underlying problem.

This is quite different to a "bad question" I think.

So my question here is simply why it is "not OK" to give a question and answer session to analyze the details to find the correct reason and AFTER that find and describe the correct answer to the underlying problem. This intermediate step can't be done in comments I believe.

Any ideas?

Comment: You undeleted your answer and it's been marked as the answer. Is it worth pursuing this any further with a meta post? The real lesson is: you can help in many different ways, but make sure your help is effective/useful and addresses the question. Use comments to prompt the OP to supply further information.

Comment: My problem in this case is, that comments can't be formatted properly and a conversation tends to be unreadable.

Comment: @Klaus: Then invite the OP to a chat room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that questions for more information (like *"Please provide the output of command ..."* belong to the comments under the question, then the user should update his question with that information and if you finally have enough information to identify the correct underlying problem you can give the correct answer.

This answer might - in addition - of course also explain the meaning of the output of the *"diagnostic commands"*.

Comment: Strange downvoters here.

Answer (score 4):

That sound like the question itself does not contain the information necessary for it to be answered properly. If that is the case, then it needs to be put on-hold until the missing information is addded.

Concerning your comment, I agree that sometimes additional information might be needed, but even though many questions can be answered by guessing at what the asker is talking about, that doesn't mean they should be answered.

Comment: As sometimes in technical problems the cause and effect is not a one to one relationship. In the actual case the given effect can result on many underlying problems. From the OPs view it was simply impossible for him to give all the answers to the questions he can't know as newbie. Setting the answer "on-hold" did not help to comes closer to the answer or a good question. I believe the question session is also the learning part for the OP. But yes, from the rules of SO the question was not perfect. But it was good enough to find the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The question is off-topic if this is the case.

Stack Overflow is a Q&A, not a chatroom… though it does have chatrooms so if someone needs "guiding" step-by-step, it can be done there.

Note that "helping" one person is not a good enough reason to break the model. Stack Overflow was created for the *very* purpose of getting away from the messy Experts Exchange/Yahoo Answers models. Let's not go back to that, eh?!

Comment: I agree that we should record the correct answer for all the people which will later run into the same trouble. But asking some questions as intermediate step can solve the problem of the originator of a question as well as finding a good answer. I agree that leaving only a question session will not fit to the rules of SO.

Comment: _"But asking some questions as intermediate step can solve the problem of the originator of a question as well as finding a good answer."_ Yes, that is what the comments section is for.

Comment: Strange downvoting going on. Which part of this is not factually accurate? (hint: none of it)

Comment: Not from my side! I like discussing and it is not a problem to have different opinions and maybe after a while the arguments comes clearer. Voting in this kind of, especially meta-dicsussions, are not helpful. Only my two cents.

Comment: @Klaus: Just because you like discussing doesn't mean SO is a discussion forum. One last time: it categorically is not one.