# Why can't one answer a question when it's put on hold? How should I improve my question to get it reopened on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

When a question is put on hold, shouldn't Stack Overflow wait at least a few days before disabling the answer section? What if someone wants to answer that question?

For example, my question was put on hold within 24 hours, after I posted it and I edited it many times. I noticed that the answer section was disabled after it was put on hold. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186684/canny-edge-detection-algorithm-java

Comment: If you could still answer it, what would be the point of putting it on hold?

Comment: For your information, the question has been put into the Reopen Queue with your edits... and that review isn't over...

Comment: I think the real question here is, "how can I improve my question on Stack Overflow?" I've had a look, and it's not a bad question. Perhaps a little broad, but it shows effort and a clear problem statement. Voting to reopen.

Comment: You can only edit your own posts on SO 5 times per day, so you will need to consider your next edit carefully. I suggest asking how to improve your question. A humble approach works best. My own take is that putting the desired result at the top could help. The code is a bit long; remove the unnecessary newlines, and see if you can shorten the code sample. But I'm the one who thinks the question is OK, so maybe you shouldn't take my word for it - ask the community (that is, Meta) how to improve it. Good luck!

Comment: also related: [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing)

Comment: Please ask one question at a time - right now the title has two.

Comment: @S.L. Barth Finally, My question is off hold. Can my question be put on hold again by someone or is my question freed forever.

Comment: @Project-A Yes, that's always possible. So always try to ask your question as clear as possible. Meanwhile, I'm glad to hear it's reopened, and I hope you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 14):

The point of putting a question on hold is to encourage the question asker to fix the issues with the post *first*. Letting people post answers would go counter to that goal.

We are building a repository of quality questions and their answers for future visitors here. That the author of a question also gets their issue solved is almost just a side-effect, it is *not* the primary goal. As such we need those questions to be useful to those future visitors; they need to be able to determine if they have the same issue and they need to be able to *trust* that at least some of answers are going to be useful to them, and not contain more rubbish than helpful feedback.

When a post has been put on hold is edited, it automatically goes into a review queue to consider reopening. Your specific post is currently under review; if enough the reviewers agree that the post is now on-topic it'll automatically be re-opened for answers.

Comment: I think this MSO question is a bit of an X/Y problem. That question on SO could do with a little improvement. But it shows effort and could be useful for future visitors. The real MSO question, IMO, is "how should I improve this question on SO to get it reopened".

Comment: @S.L.Barth: perhaps, but right now I'm answering the question stated. Feel free to answer the underlying unspoken question. :-)

Comment: @S.L.Barth I assumed that was just a randomly-chosen example, and the fact that it was also the OP's question was purely coincidental...