# Should I flag a question or not?

Tags: discussion, flags

Last week I encountered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368397/uncaught-typeerror-fullcalendar-is-not-a-function-event-calendar-in-la) which looked alright to me and I thought I could answer it, but communicating with the person who posted the question is quite hard and I think he/she does not understand me.

This created such a lengthy comment chain which made everything more vague and everything is now at a point at which I would like to flag it, but I don't know for what specifically and I wonder if I should flag it in the first place.

All the similar topics / questions that where shown do not cover the problem I have with the question I linked and even searching for a while did not return any results that helpt.

**Edit**:
This question was flagged as a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing) question, but that question only covers the case if the question was unclear, but the problem was fixed after the first comment and OP encountered another problem after that. Which now reminds me that separate questions need their own question on StackOverflow, but it seemed easy to also answer the other question OP had.

Comment: I would personally leave a comment saying to the OP _Sorry, I don't think I can be of any use here. I'm going to delete my comments in an attempt to clear up the comment section. You may want to do the same as it's become quite confusing_ or words to that effect. Then delete your comments (leaving the last one in place of course).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you have hit what is generally known as a "chameleon question". When reviewing the edit-history it is clear that the question as it is now has nothing to do with the original question that was asked. Had you provided an answer instead of offering help through comments your original answer would have been invalidated several times by now.

The problem is that the OP has layer over layer of problems and with each problem solved a new one appears. To make this useful for SO's Q&A format each problem should have its own question with its own answer.

Considering the history of the post I doubt anything useful will come from it, but I don't think it warrants flagging in its current state. If I were you I would just leave it alone and move on.

Comment: That sounds quite right. Thanks for introducing me to the term of chameleon question, that will help me identify questions like that in the future!