# How to give a proper answer to questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions

Recently I stumbled upon [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514499/c-how-to-convert-seconds-to-minutes-hours-and-days-explain-please).

As a new user I wanted to answer it as good is I was able to, but:

1. This post is locked or on hold due to 5 people not understanding the question.
2. Since I am new I don't have a reputation of 50 so basically I'm not allowed to comment.

To number 1:
For me it was very clear that there was a basic understanding issue of the language in use. So a good answer would explain exactly what happens in the given code.

To number 2:
Watching the comments I only see 2 helpful comments, 3 comments by the user. The rest of the 12 comments is not helpful.

So not being able to answer or comment I took the route to write an edit of the existing post to include my answer only to get it rejected with the notice I should place it as a comment or as answer.

So my question: How can you answer such a thread?

As to my next point: Questions with similar titles have frequently been downvoted and/or closed. Consider using a title that more accurately describes your question...That being said as a new user I don't get the feeling some people are actually interested in helping unknowing people. Don't get me wrong: I'm very thankful to the people that helped me with my questions this far.

P.S.: Not enough reputation to ask on meta Stack Overflow. And not enough to create a new tag. Sorry about that.

Comment: BTW, questions which can easily be answered by books or reference sites are off topic

Comment: There are 14.6 million questions on Stack Overflow. I'm sure you can find some other question to answer.

Comment: Did you look at the help center? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: If a question has been put on hold, that means there are serious issues with the question. You can't answer questions that are on hold, regardless of your reputation, until someone edits the question and fixes the issue, and the question gets reopened.

Comment: also a duplicate of [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/839601)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Uhmm... what? That is absolutely false. If the information cannot be found on Stack Overflow, it doesn't matter how many books or other resources it _can_ be found in. We don't close questions as duplicates of reference documents. We have many reasons to close questions, but that isn't one of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[screenshot in case the question gets deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InOrk.png)

> This post is locked or on hold due to 5 people not understanding the question.

Don't make that mistake. We have the most brilliant minds among our users. There are hardly any questions that no-one understands. There are however plenty of questions that are either repeats of existing questions, no-effort dumps, non-researched attempts or just plain low quality posts. As we try to curate a list of high quality questions and answers, we don't need *every* question to be asked here and they certainly don't need to be answered.

> Since I am new I don't have a reputation of 50 so basically I'm not allowed to comment.

Then gain some rep that you can comment. But if you do make sure you leave a comment to help the OP to improve their question, not by answering it.

> To number 1: For me it was very clear, that there was a basic understanding issue of the language in use. So a good answer would explain exactly what happens in the given code.

The point isn't that the problem is unclear, it is unclear what the OP fails to understand in their attempt to figure out what that code does or how it behaves. Because that allows us to expand on their current knowledge and/or rectify their misconception. In the current state of that question we have to guess what is causing the trouble for understanding what is going on. I can make a guess but that is not useful for future visitors finding that question (and the guesses as answer).

> To number 2: Watching the comments I only see 2 helpful comments, 3 comments by the user. The rest of the 12 comments is not helpful.

I beg to differ. All comments try to work out if the OP has a problem understanding time calculations or the specific language constructs used in their question. The suggestion to do some more studying are offering links to an awesome set of material. None of the comments are in anyway off or flaggable by my standards. In general though, if you see comments that you think are rude, do flag them.

> So not being able to answer or comment I took the route to write an edit of the existing post to include my answer only to get it rejected with the notice I should place it as a comment or as answer.

That is certainly not how you should proceed. Don't try to circumvent features you're not allowed to use yet due to the lack of privileges. Your actions are another proof that we need people to first be accustomed somewhat to the site and its specific needs. If everyone would be allowed what you tried these site would become a wasteland over a short period. Just don't. Gain some reputation instead.

> So my question: How can you answer such a thread?

You don't. These low quality questions are not worth keeping. Close votes, down votes and delete votes is all that is needed. There are for sure better questions already on the site and if not they will be asked in the next couple of days. Wait for it.

> As to my next point:

Can you please stick to one question at a time. How would we need to vote if I value your first points but hate the rest? What if your second question is on-topic but your first isn't? What if it is partly a duplicate?

> Questions with similar titles have frequently been downvoted and/or closed. Consider using a title that more accurately describes your question...That being said as a new user I don't get the feeling some people are actually interested in helping unknowing people. Don't get me wrong: I'm very thankful to the people that helped me with my questions this far.

That is right. We are not here to help unknowing people. The goal is to have a collection of canonical questions and their answers so future visitors facing the same or similar issues will find their solution here. Yes, that does mean we need *unknowing* people to ask a question and they are invited to do so but they get plenty of guidance to make sure it is a *good* question. We have a help center, [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq)'s and a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). All kind of guidance that is happily ignored once they copy/paste their assignment in the ask question box.

> P.S.: Not enough reputation to ask on meta Stack Overflow. And not enough to create a new tag. Sorry about that.

If you know about meta and know about tags, why did you even post an off-topic question on Stack Overflow? Where does that idea come from that everybody is entitled to ask their question and get their answer? Why does it seem no-one cares about the established house rules on this site? Why does it always ends in a complaint about the current users that care for their site and the effort they put in it? Why does it always feel the users that have made this site great have to defend their selves? Why? Just why?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. As for the last point...I guess simply because once you google something the often times stackoverflow is one of the first pages to show up. And secondly: If you have a problem with one of googles APIs they send you to stackoverflow. Thats how I ended up on this side. So as a new user with a problem the first thing I do in that case is to post a question, simply not knowing of better alternatives.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the feedback @Shruiken

Comment: *"There are hardly any questions that no-one understands."* Uh, false. I don't understand ~80% of the questions that get asked here. Oh wait. That means I'm not a brilliant mind. I get it now...

Comment: In my opinion there isn't a question NO-ONE understands. It has nothing to do with one person not being a brilliat mind. That being said...even a brilliant mind in computing or programming might not be so smart if it comes down to understanding people. That being said: In my example he said he just began with the c++ language. So i guessed (as rene pointed out you had to guess) he doesn't understand the code. And for the second part: He had a problem with (60*60*24) seconds being hours. It isn't hours. It's days. So faulty code + new to the language => problem @Cody Gray

Comment: My comment was a bit tongue-in-cheek. As a moderator, I see a fair number of questions that objectively do not make sense. No one but the person who asked it could possibly understand the question. Those are not good questions for Stack Overflow, at least not until they are edited to be clear. And, in this case, while the question might have been clear enough to answer, it was still off-topic because the problem was the result of a typo or other silly error where the answer won't be helpful to anyone else in the future. This site is meant to be a database of information, not a help desk.