# How should I triage an unclear question that could be fixed by OP?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I'm learning to help moderate the review queues and I'm unclear on one point.  What do I do if a question is clearly useful but can't be answered until the OP adds more detail.

I have three options:

- "Looks Okay"  But it isn't okay.
- "Requires Editing" I understand this to be for questions that could be edited by someone other than the OP.
- "Unsalvagable"  But it isn't!

The relevant documentation is this:

> Do not choose "Requires Editing" if you know the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author. For example, if an android question asks for an explanation of errors found in logcat, but omits specific errors and/or logcat listing, the question doesn't require editing — it requires more information, so choose Unsalvageable → should be closed → unclear what you're asking.

Do I really have to be that mean?

Comment: Unsalvageable is also for when the required edits are provided by the OP. Just because they can fix the question by providing more information doesn't mean they will ever do that.

Comment: You've been around for a bit... Does it seem at all likely that it *will* be fixed?

Comment: I linked to the guide (which is also linked from the triage queue itself) because I feel it addresses this concern... But let me know if you're still unsure.

Comment: @JoeW Thanks, I think your comments mostly clear things up.  Mainly was worried that the OP wouldn't get another chance to fix things, even if they wanted to.

Comment: @Shog9 I think in this case an even better dupe would be [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601)

Comment: Flagging a question as "unclear" because it lacks sufficient information to be answered is ***not*** "mean".

Comment: @CodyGray Flagging a question as "Unsalvageable and should be removed from the site" because the OP overlooked something that ey can correct is indeed mean.  I bet there's a more respectful way of expressing the middle ground in which these questions lie.