# How to deal with misguided comment when voted to close on a question?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

Recently I have voted to close a question in Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196645/cant-add-image-to-viewholder-with-glide#52196645

The user is stating that his code shows some errors but not added that error in question.

I have added the comment below on the question:

> it shows error What error? you need to share it with question

but the user does not give feedback and question is closed as off-topic.

Then one user added this comment:

> The people who put this question as Off-Topic must know that the person who is asking this question is a beginner. Your job is to help him/her by answering his/her question. Instead you guys just close it and you don't even allow others to help him. Shame on you guys.

NOTE: the user is not a new contributor

So my question is how to deal with this situation:

- Should I ignore this comment and continue my VTC-ing?
- Should I flag that comment?
- Which flag is good for that type of comment?

Comment: @gnat i'm not asking for how long i should wait to close a question

Comment: per my reading your question title ("is it wrong to close etc") is exactly about that, and duplicate addresses this: ["You should wait for zero seconds..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601) If you prefer readers to focus on a topic that is laid out in the last lines of the question text, consider [edit]ing the title accordingly

Comment: "I'm a beginner and you're supposed to help me" I only have words for this that do not comply with the CoC in multiple ways. :x

Comment: It's our JOB?   I demand my back-pay!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The people who put this question as Off-Topic must know that the
>   person who is asking this question is a beginner. Your job is to help
>   him/her by answering his/her question. Instead you guys just close it
>   and you don't even allow others to help him. Shame on you guys.

---

Let's dissect this:

> The people who put this question as Off-Topic must know that the
>   person who is asking this question is a beginner.

Okay, but that is pretty irrelevant to the question itself. The only thing "I'm a beginner" signifies is that answers should maybe be a bit more verbose and add more links to supporting documentation or such. It doesn't magically lower the quality standards for the question itself.

> Your job is to help him/her by answering his/her question.

Stack Overflow isn't anyone's *job.* It's a voluntary effort. Nobody is obliged to do anything here. But if you're going there anyway, the job of an *asker* is to *ask answerable questions.* If the question isn't answerable because it lacks information, the asker didn't do their job. So potential answerers can't do theirs.

> Instead you guys just close it and you don't even allow others to help him.

This assumes that one set of users judged the question to be unanswerable, but another set of users may be able to answer it, so it should be left open until those other users can step in.

By that standard, no question should ever be closed, since, who knows, somebody out there may one day find it and answer it. But that simply doesn't scale. We close questions so people can be more focussed on the things that *are* answerable. A handful of users get rid of the obviously unanswerable questions, so everybody else doesn't need to do that same judgement for themselves and waste their time reading unanswerable questions. We already get more questions than can ever be answered, leaving them all open and letting everyone individually discover for themselves which ones are answerable and which ones are a waste of time amplifies that problem even more.

The other interpretation of "allow others to help" is that maybe no direct answer to the problem can be given, but perhaps an answer could provide some tips on how to approach debugging the problem. That may help the asker. Okay, but that probably won't help anyone in the future, and it requires future visitors coming from Google et al to wade through a bunch of vague hand-holdy posts which do not contain a clear-cut solution. That is precisely what Stack Overflow **tries to avoid being.** Questions must be precise so future visitors can identify quickly whether it applies to their problem as well, and answers must be to the point so nobody else has to waste time in the future tackling the same issue.

---

So, no, that comment is very misguided. Close away. Please don't flag such comments for moderator attention, as there's nothing much to be done. Unless the commenter is unnecessarily aggressive, just leave it be.

Comment: Wait, intentionally *shaming* other people for doing the proper course of action is appropriate and doesn't merit moderator action?  That's pretty absurd.  Why is it appropriate to remove polite, professional, and non-accusatory comments pointing out problems with a question, but not appropriate to remove actively harmful and intentionally abusive comments just because they're advocating that new users are above the rules?

Comment: @Servy I don't find a stray "shame on you" particularly insulting; more amusing. That just makes such a comment *wrong*, and that's not really a reason to do anything. Perhaps link them to this post then. But I'll happily concede that this may be different for everybody. If you feel such a comment is *unwelcoming*, which may well fall under the "unnecessarily aggressive" category for you, then flag it as such.

Answer (score 8):

It is wrong to close a question because the user does not talk to you. It is right to vote to close a question because it is unclear or does not include important details. [You should vote to close such questions **immediately**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing), and *then*, if you want to, add a comment asking the OP to provide what is missing, then move on.

If the OP responds to your comment,  others will not vote to close the question,  or will vote to reopen it. If the OP does not respond,  their bad question will be closed and eventually removed,  as it should be.

Comment: *`You should vote to close such questions immediately...what is missing.`* Thanks for quick response i have followed the same  and added a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196645/cant-add-image-to-viewholder-with-glide#comment91342507_52196645) and what about the other [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196645/cant-add-image-to-viewholder-with-glide#comment91344074_52196645) how deal with it?