# Can we please have a shortcut for "Do not post code or errors as images"?

Tags: feature-request, images, code, magic-links

I find myself typing this phrase multiple times a day.  A shortcut that led directly to the [FAQ explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) would be really helpful.

Comment: What is wrong with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) explicitly stating "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc". You can use `[ask]` as a shortcut. I renders like this: [ask]

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of "ask" - I use it frequently.  But I often see otherwise good questions make the mistake of posting images of code, and the ability to easily point them to specific guidance for that particular issue would be helpful.

Comment: If it good question without code - just delete the link (or do nothing) - why to add any comments?

Comment: no, it would be a good question if the code were posted properly

Comment: I see. I have a file on the side with 250 different comments. One of them is "Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)". There are also user scripts with canned comments, if you prefer those, like [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

Comment: I just retype the common messages over and over. I need the typing practice.

Comment: Personnaly, I don't see the special need to link to a FAQ about it. I mean, what more there is to say? I just type `please don't post links/images of code. All code should go as formatted text inside the question`... If you really want to put the effort, you can use the auto comments suggested by Scratte and write there scrolls to be copied as a comment in a sec

Comment: Since the image-questions are often rather awful in my frequented tags: When you say the image-questions are "otherwise good questions", are they actually *good* or merely *not bad*?

Comment: Makes me wonder if "Needs debugging details" should actually be a category rather than a close reason. Because "Needs debugging details" -> "Code or error posted as a picture" makes a lot of sense to me personally. No need for links if the close reason is specific enough.

Comment: I just use this: "According to [ask], don't post images of code." If you can't type that, then copy and paste it into a google document.

Comment: That FAQ explanation is still inferior in terms of simple readability to the [unspeakable simplicity](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). And one is *not* obliged to *downvote because* they referred to that site. (No affiliation.) Maybe SO could license content from elsewhere.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, but no.
Let's stop fixing symptoms.

It's great if you haven't given up on user education. But the priority should be on prevention, not cleaning up. SO could easily avoid most of these cases with minor effort. It's not rocket science:

[image]

Same thing for the hyperlink editor button, of course.

The FAQ shortcut by itself won't do us any good.

Comment: This actually seems feasible.

Comment: Normally people drop in with "But they'll just ignore the warning sign" on this type of suggestion, so to anyone thinking that, I say that's not a problem here. If we know every person who posts an image as code has done so ignoring a big honking warning, then there's no reason to hope that a comment will change their mind and curators can feel more confident about straight up voting to close.

Comment: Legit that is the best solution. Why hasn't SE implemented this?

Comment: @10Rep I'll give you a clue: it begins with "unw" and ends with "elcoming" (also known by its alias, "BS").

Comment: @IanKemp Ahhh, I see. SE took 10 years to fix triage, and by fix, I mean change the text on a few buttons (something anyone could do in a few minutes).

Comment: While this looks easy to be implemented, it will add more fragmented features for the SE devs to add this image only on SO (and possibly other code-related SE sites). Though, I have to admit SO is already specialized with additional features (e.g. Triage review)...

Answer (score 9):

What's more expedient:

- Closing the question as "Needs debugging details", or
- Posting a link to an FAQ?

If the end goal is to close the question so that the OP has a snowball's chance of updating the post, then **just** do the former.  If you want to chat with the OP, then **just** do the latter.

I would actually recommend only doing the former anyway, since the message about putting code in the question would be best broadcast there anyway.

Comment: my goal is to get the poster to fix a flaw in what is often an otherwise decent question by pointing them to specific guidance about what they're doing wrong.  What's the point of having any shortcuts like `[ask]` available if we should just close flawed questions?

Comment: Also, a question with a link to an image of code can become decent if only the code was posted properly. Simply pointing out the OP to this problem and make them fix it will avoid the whole cycle of close-reopen in the first place...

Comment: *What's the point of having any shortcuts like [ask] available if we should just close flawed questions?* @Jason You can't vote to close until you reach 3K and there are daily limits on both close votes and flags.

Comment: @Jason:  I'm of the impression that those were added as a band-aid to fix the overarching problem: people need to be pushed *more* towards taking the immediate action of curating and fixing the problem question *rather than* trying to talk to the OP and hope that they'll be swayed by our words... (when the words about needing to include more information in their question were just ignored anyway)

Answer (score -20):

I believe we should try very hard to use alternatives to closing questions.

Closing a question is similar to slapping a person. It's appropriate sometimes but very very infrequently. When was the last time you slapped someone in real life?

I think Jason's shortcut suggestion is an excellent idea. I haven't yet found anyone who is deliberately asking a poor question.

Comment: We don't need hyperbole on Meta SO. Stick to political ads. Closing a question is nothing like physical violence and equating the two increases the rhetorical cost of discussing closing votes and decreases the moral cost of physical violence.

Comment: Aaah yes, SO reasoned discussion! Love it!

Comment: I never cv a post which has potential to improve, since that is going against SO's mission to provide a repository of knowledge.

Comment: @10Rep Voting to close a post does not go against SO's mission to provide a **high quality** repository of knowledge.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ususlly I follow a post that has potential. If it isn't edited within a set period, then I flag for closure. Sometimes it is indeed edited.

Comment: @10Rep And that's your prerogative, although I would argue that leaving it open simply allows for answerers to wildly guess and post low-quality answers as a result. In any case not waiting to close does not go against SO's mission. As the majority of votes show in the answers to [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Is it hyperbole though? Your comment basically disagrees with the comparison  because you value closing  lower than physical violence in  the pain scale. In contrast, OP's values are probably different from yours as they seem to be the same on a scale.

Comment: @TheMaster You're right. I had assumed that the human race had progressed to the point where preventing someone from asking or answering a question about computer programming was less important than subjecting them to physical assault. And that suggesting equivalence between the two would be considered outlandish. Recent political news should have warned me that this was not the case.

Comment: Also I agree Jason's suggestion, but... I believe most of the errors-as-screenshot posts are crap, and what their OPs lack, is not the knowledge, but the motivation. Killing their posts gives them the motivation; while the site does not lose too much.

Comment: @10Rep FYI SO's mission is to provide a repository of *useful* knowledge. You can CV a lot of posts safely in the knowledge they aren't ever going to be *useful* :-)

Comment: @TylerH IMO, That's a very lax attitude. Someone Somewhere might have a  rare question and you could've closed that question. "Repository of useful" doesn't mean "famous/popular questions only". It's the rarest of rare resources, that is  rarely going to be searched by  another human being is what makes  useful.

Comment: @TheMaster I agree, "useful" doesn't mean "famous/popular". Luckily, that's also not what I said :-).