# Is this site of any good for new users to actually ask questions?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [HTML Submit sends only the last entry of a table, not the selected one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70134552/html-submit-sends-only-the-last-entry-of-a-table-not-the-selected-one)

Is this site of any good for new users to actually ask questions?
My post lasted for less than 20 minutes before being closed.  I tried to keep it up with new information as people asked for it. Still, it was closed before I could even try to make it better for the people trying to answer my question.

This site is really good when I look for already answered questions, but every time I try to post here, I have a really quick and bad experience that I can't keep up with why this is happening. It's like it's expecting me to in less than 1 minute after an answer, to edit all my code AND the thread, even though I said I'm only a beginner.

Comment: This site accepts everyone, provided they also follow [Stack Overflow's policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). However, this site attempt to be a knowledge repository, not a help desk, so questions that are unanswerable (e.g. unclear, unfocus, off-topic) will be closed. I noticed there are some comments asking for clarification, have you edited the question to address all of that?

Comment: Closed doesn't mean it's the end. You can still edit the post and get it reopened.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Comment: All old users were new users one day, logically

Comment: One thing that I've noticed is that often the first 15 to 60 minutes of a question's existence is often critical time, time where the question gets a lot of attention, votes, and often comments. If the poster is very attentive to any comments received and responds to them in a positive way, including with replies to comments and most importantly, with edits to the question that attempt to improve it (as per the comment suggestions), then this greatly improves the question's chances of getting up-votes and decent answers.

Comment: Well, I also once was a new user, and had an unfair dupehammer closure on my question to another question that wasn't even related. If something's unfair, bring it up on Meta. Otherwise, read [ask] and ask a better question. Then the [Community-bot](/users/-1) deleted it. And I just moved on.

Comment: Related: [How long to wait for clarification before closing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing)

Comment: Re *"any good for new users to actually ask questions"*: I assume it is a rhetorical question, but if we take it literally, yes, it most certainly is. Here is a ***complete (Git) beginner question*** with an absolutely ***awesome*** and drum roll................... ***comprehensive*** answer: *[Can I use Git to pull from server 1 and push to GitHub from desktop 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70052276/can-i-use-git-to-pull-from-server-1-and-push-to-github-from-desktop-1/70052374#70052374)*. It was asked ***six days*** ago (not six weeks, six months, or six  years ago).

Comment: Interestingly, I see no comments from you, either here or on your question on the [main] main site (unless you made some and they have been deleted).

Answer (score 25):

**Not really**

Stack Overflow requires you to do lots of things before asking a question, and some are not minor tasks for beginners.

The two major obstacles I often see are:

- Stating the problem

  Clearly formulate *exactly* what the problem is. The difficulty here varies greatly between programming languages and types of problem, but quite often, we will expect example data, an explanation on what each part of your problem, an explanation on why you expect the program to do something, and what exactly happens which differs from that explanation.
- Creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

  Reduce your program to the exact minimal amount of code to demonstrate the intent and the problem of the program. This often requires scrapping significant portions of the program while continuously testing if you haven't accidentally fixed the issue, and requires a significant investment of time. When I think: I don't have a clue what's causing the issue, let's ask a question here, about 90% of the time creating a minimal reproducible example fixes the problem. For beginners this is no trivial task, as it requires substantially rewriting the code and thorough knowledge on what is and isn't relevant.

Then, there are lots of minor obstacles, including but not limited to:

- Ignoring security issues

  While your code may be slightly more minimal if you ignore XSS/SQL injection/other issues, you may get downvotes for it, since we strive to be a repository of knowledge and don't want insecure examples for others to see
- Poor writing

  This makes it harder to understand the problem, and is often hard for beginners that do not know what's most likely to be relevant so should be emphasized, or what can be omitted. If you don't have a clear idea of exactly what the problem is and what the likely causes are, questions tend to become disorganized
- Focusing on the goal and not the problem

  Beginners often have a specific goal and write their question with it in mind (e.g. "Error when adding notes to list"), while we want the programming context (e.g. "Syntax error when performing insert on MySQL database")
- Focusing on the problem and not the goal

  Sometimes, people omit the goal and context necessary to answer the question. We just get a blank "this code is causing an error", and we can clearly see why the code doesn't work, but not what it's supposed to do when it does work. So we can explain why this causes an error, but not how to fix it, since that requires knowing what it should be doing in the first place. As hinted by the point above, this is a balancing act and it's difficult for beginners to do this properly
- Asking duplicates

  Beginners often do not have a sense of common issues, and find it harder to search for the technical terms for their issue, so ask duplicates more frequently. While that's not a sin nor a good reason to downvote if the duplicate is hard to find, it does often lead to a worse experience. My advice is: research both the issue before asking a question, and after writing but before posting it. If you've properly distilled the technical issue (reproducible example) you might have a better understanding of which search terms may lead you to the answer.

Of course, just because something is hard doesn't mean it's not worth it, or you should stay away. Just be aware that it's not a minor task to ask a good question, and for most beginner errors, writing a good question about it is much harder than solving it yourself.

Also keep in mind "I'm a beginner" is considered noise here. It's all about the questions and the lasting repository of knowledge, not about the people. Stack Overflow is not a programming help site, it's a knowledge repository, and that's often hard to understand.

Answer (score 14):

The site is good for new users to ask questions, but you really need to do a lot of research and learning about the site before posting anything here.

On the other hand, posting questions on Stack Overflow is probably not a good idea if you are new to programming in general. Asking good questions is a very difficult skill to master. You need to know what to put in the question to make it answerable and useful to other people. You also need to know the basics of coding so that you can at least use the right terminology and be sure the topic hasn't been covered already.

> it was closed before I could even try to make it better for the people trying to answer my question.

That's the idea. If the question is so unclear that we have to ask for clarifications in comments, then it means that it must be closed for the time being. Otherwise, we would be getting guess answers or wrong answers.

> This site is really good when I look for already answered questions

That's the goal of Stack Overflow. We don't want you to ask questions. We want you to be able to find an answer on one of the existing questions. If you can't find an answer then either you are searching for the wrong thing or we really haven't covered this topic yet, in which case you can ask a new question.

> It's like it's expecting me to in less than 1 minute after an answer, to edit all my code AND the thread, even though I said I'm only a beginner.

No, the site is expecting you to do this **before you post a question**. The question must be clear, without any noise, personal information, or known security vulnerabilities/bugs. Don't mention known issues, fix them before you post it. Why should we see broken code that you already know how to fix and isn't related to your question? Focus on a single problem. If you have a question about the code you have written then post a **minimal verifiable example**. If possible, provide a link to an online executable, e.g., in PHP it is https://3v4l.org/ or https://phpize.online/

Make sure we can understand the question before you post it. This often requires you reaching out to someone else, like a friend or your tutor, to ask them to review it before you post it.

Most importantly, make sure you take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help). If you don't, then you will have really bad time contributing anything to the site.