# Average Stack Overflow user over the course of their career

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I'm not great at using the Data Explorer. I am relatively new to programming, and I'm curious as to how the average Stack Overflow user interacts with Stack Overflow over the course of their career.

Ideally, more experienced programmers pass on their wisdom to less experienced ones, or exchange ideas amongst themselves. Unfortunately, I get the sense that there are many people who only use Stack Overflow to solve their own problems without contributing.

Do most programmers start their careers with significant use and taper off as they become more experienced? Do users transition to answering more questions as they gain experience?

I guess my real curiosity lies in whether askers remain predominantly askers or if this role actually shifts.

Comment: Predominantly, people seem to ask a question only *once* - ever. Also, predominantly, it's a bad question. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266506/2564301 for a nice graphic. You may want to exclude the huge 1-rep crowd from your question. (And it is huge. Another post proved convincingly that the average reputation on SO is "1". That's how huge it is.)

Comment: @Jongware but the median is [92](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296970/578411)...

Comment: While this doesn't specifically address transitions between asker to answerer, read about Nielsen's Participation inequality theory, which suggests that most people just... lurk: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/participation-inequality/

Comment: @yochannah wow that's very interesting... thanks for that link! I think the "How to overcome Participation Inequality" section is particularly interesting because I've seen many social media outlets use some implementation of these suggestions.

Comment: "Do most programmers start their careers with significant use and taper off as they become more experienced? Do users transition to answering more questions as they gain experience? "  I think Stack Overflow is still young enough that most programmers started their careers without Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: Most of the women developers I know have never even bothered to create a stack account. The handful that do have accounts participate minimally. Given the context and wording of your question, not sure how you'd handle ghosts, if they're even relevant. If it is, there's also that closed-circuit mentoring network that is likewise not represented in these numbers. But I digress.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Interesting question! Here's a *small* start, open to critiques as I feel I'm bound to've made some kind of reasoning mistake...

First things first, this is what my *hacking around* initially results in:

[[image: SO Transitions] (click img for "high fidelity" / meta-proof version by @jeeped)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML9J5.png)

<sup>Note that -since the question is mainly about *transitions*- only the *arrow* widths are meaningful. The size of circles obviously isn't, as there are different number of users in each group.</sup>

My initial thoughts here was: "Askers will be askers, answerers will be answerers.".

Here's the terms I've used:

- `Answerer` is a user that has answered more questions than (s)he's asked in a certain period;
- `Asker` is a user that has asked more questions than (s)he's answered in a certain period;
- `Undecided` is a user that has asked exactly the same number of times as (s)he's answered;

In addition:

- `MidPoint` is the moment exactly between "now" and account creation date;
- `Part1` is the period between creation date and the `MidPoint`;
- `Part2` is the period between `MidPoint` and now;

Also, for now, let's look only at the more "interesting" accounts (>101 rep total). Though (over?)simplified, this should get us started.

[The data.se query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342473/askers-answerers-undecided) I hacked together for this (suggestions welcome!) gives the following pivot table:

```
Part1       Part2Asker   Part2Answerer   Part2Undecided      SUM
----------  -----------  --------------  ---------------  |  --------
Asker       72837        23149           40315            |  136301
Answerer    28340        112078          74333            |  214751
Undecided   4724         12132           5215             |  22071
----------  -----------  --------------  ---------------    --------
SUM         105901       147359          119863
```

So, to get to your question:

> Do users transition to answering more questions as they gain experience?

My preliminary query doesn't show *big* transitions between `Asker` and `Answerer`, but does show that you'd have to look further into the `Undecided` category to know what's *really* going on.

Comment: I'm not sure how heavy the query is pushing the sede server but you could see if instead of reputation>101 remove the users that should have been deleted already as shown in the last query in my [answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296967/what-is-the-median-reputation-level-on-stack-overflow/296970#296970)

Comment: Thanks for this well thought-out answer Jeroen! This is a great starting point and it kind of confirms what I thought. Thanks for putting in the effort :)

Comment: Here's a very speculative interpretation of the data: first of all, whether you ask more or answer more depends not on your SO experience but on your knowledge and experience in general. This sounds fairly reasonable. Secondly, asking a lot of questions on SO isn't going to make you more knowledgeable. Why? Because underlying it is often an inability (or a lack of motivation) to figure things out for yourself. It would be interesting to correlate this data with age, maybe those who do cross the line from asker to answerer are going through the transition from teenagers to adults.

Comment: That is just way too nice a graphic for meta. It should be closer to [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ML9J5.png).

Comment: lol @Jeeped. Anyway, yea, I agree that it's fairly speculative... but I'm not so sure that asking more or answering more depends on knowledge and experience in general. I think people with more knowledge and experience are more likely to answer questions than those who are not, but at the same time, I think personality affects this as well. Some who are quite knowledgeable may not be inclined to answer questions they are well capable of answering, and those who aren't knowledgeable may try to answer whatever they can even if they aren't as qualified to.

Comment: @Jeeped Agreed. I've included your high-fidelity meta-proof version in the onclick of the image.

Comment: Now to post @Jeeped's diagram to CodeGolf "write a program that can analyze this image, create a representative Markov chain, and predict the probability of a given sequence of states."

Comment: If anyone else was curious the big bump on undecideds in the second half is people with no activity. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342817

Comment: @Sign Aye, it dawned only hours later on me that it might've been useful to split that group into "Undecided" and "Inactive".

Comment: @jeeped  that made my day. ok .. midday.

Comment: Very nice, Askers remain Askers, Answerers remain Answers, but those who start undecided can become Answerers, but not Askers. Makes sense.

Comment: I think "Undecided" is a bit misleading. If you ask 100 questions and answer 99, this division puts you in the "Asker" category. To me, that's the sign of someone who is pretty balanced between posting types. I'm not sure how to fix that or whether it would change your conclusion, however.

Comment: @JonEricson You're very right, had crossed my mind. What kind of Q/A ratio do you think is a reasonable boundry (for a *simple* analysis, that is)? Shall I re-run it with say `0.67 - 1.33` as "Undecided"? Re-running it is also a chance to filter out the "zero-zero" posters see if that matters...

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that I started as a Asker, transitioned to an Answerer as it was the only way I had to show up my coding skills, and then settled to be asker/answerer in small bits.
Stackoverflow really helped me to transition to a remote job. After i got my first remote job, experience became more important than Stackoverflow reputation.
And i really wanted to be in the top 100 for a month and unlock everything. Probably if there was something to unlock at 50.000 I would have gone up to 50.000 probably :D
I still try to mantain my answers up do date, expecially the accepted one.