# Premature closure

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed

It happens to me almost every day that some newbie will ask a perfectly legitimate question, maybe similar to an existing one or maybe not clearly worded, but nonetheless one I can answer quickly and easily. So I start, but the question gets closed as I'm typing.

Often I disagree with closure, but simply voting to reopen is totally useless, and there's no place to easily explain why I think the closure was wrong. I suppose in those cases where I think closure is clearly wrong (for example, it's closed as a duplicate but is clearly different), I could bring up the individual post here, but that seems drastic and really too much work.

I think a much better solution is simply to leave it closed, but take answers anyway. Let the original poster and commentors see them, but hide them from search if you must. But there's no reason to prevent someone from helping someone who wants help if he feels like it. And allow "reason to reopen" comments as well.

Comment: 'But there's no reason to prevent someone from helping someone who wants help if he feels like it' - well, there is the site policy.

Comment: What point is there in closing if this is implemented? The implication seems to be "please remove closing questions"

Comment: If you database searches to find the best stuff, then by all means exclude closed questions from search. But that's no reason not to help the person at hand if someone wants to.

Comment: This guy: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251897/off-topic-questions-have-to-be-cleared-out-of-the-way-but-not-via-closure?rq=1 has some good ideas, but he's a little more blue-sky. I'm thinking of something simpler, but maybe simple won't work here.

Comment: This very question is turning into a great example: I don't see a single legitimate reason for a downvote here. If you don't agree with what I suggest, great, make that your answer as my Greek friend below did. But the question is serious, detailed, brings to light a real problem for users, deserves discussion, and isn't off-topic or a duplicate. It just touches a nerve, apparently.

Comment: Voting is different on meta. Here it can (and probabl does) mean "I disagree with your premisse or with what you say", not only "your question lacks research or is unclear".

Comment: Really? OK, just seems odd.

Comment: That's how it is. It doesn't affect your rep anyway. I guess it's intended to show what the community thinks of feature request and discussions at a glance. I know theres an article about it somewhere, but I can't gather the strength to link it from my phone. ...

Comment: As for your actual discussion.... I have to say I agree with what other members are saying here. Even if they don't show in searches, letting users ask these questions with no negative consequence (I mean... they got their answer right?) Will lead to quality problems in the future. You see it everyday and they are aggressively closed. Imagine if they weren't.... stack would turn into yahoo answers

Comment: I'm getting that impression. SE has a reputation that It's insanely useful, but the folks there are kind of assholes. It might be that those are inevitably linked. :-)

Comment: "there's no place to easily explain why I think the closure was wrong" - why can't you leave a comment to explain your reopen vote? That may well persuade others to cast reopen votes too.

Comment: Maybe, just _maybe_, it's the people who refuse to follow the guidelines here that are the 'assholes', as you put it. It seems there are a lot more of us (those who want to use the site for its intended purpose) than there are people complaining about us. Just something for you to mull over...

Comment: Allowing people to answer closed questions would drive away the very people that make the site so valuable: the experts.  The whole point of closure is to prevent answers.  I can guarantee what will happen if you allow them to still be answered: the bad questions would inundate the ones that SE actually wants to keep, they'd get answered by people who's only goal is more rep, and the quality would spiral further and further down, as those rep hunters would start gaining privileges they shouldn't have, and the experts would leave, and now we're Yahoo Answers.

Answer (score 15):

Answering obviously off-topic (or help vampire) questions, **will actively hurt** the qualitiy of the SO site. You seriously should keep that in mind.

Answering (or even commenting) to help vampire or otherwise low quality/off-topic questions would leave the OP with the perception, that they will get an answer here, despite the question doesn't meet the actual policies enacted.

---

Being ***helpful*** here, is meant to have a long term view, involving the perception of future researchers, not for an individual asker that focusses on their current problems.

---

I have to admit, that it's sometimes hard to decide, if a question is just OT and down-/closevote it, or give a concise answer (especially for the easy ones, it's sometimes tempting).
Though before going to comment or answer, I have a collection of FAQ dupe questions at hand, and consider to use one of these.

Comment: I'm not sure how that differs from what I'm suggesting. I'm suggesting we mark the question as closed, note the reason "doesn't meet our criterion X", but allow some bit of help to reach the user anyway. I'm suggesting some method of "Gee, we don't really want that question on our site, but here's what you should have Googled, or your typo was on line 5", or something to that effect. I'm fine with closure. I'm just not fine with closure preventing helpfulness.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker You can always leave a comment on the question after it is closed.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - That would only encourage people to post off-topic questions.  I mean, why follow the site rules if you can ask anything and still get help?

Comment: The world is full of honest, well-meaning idiots. They'll go somewhere for help. There's not a lot of competition for SE at the moment, but there might be, and even if 90% of the questions here don't result in adding value to the database, they are still eyeballs for our ads that we don't want to drive away.