# How can one appeal the decisions of high-reputation users?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, moderation

High-rep users are humans like the rest of us. They can make mistakes, we all do. The way I see it, mods are doing a public service, and as such, they should be "customer oriented", welcoming, helpful and any kind of aggressiveness should be used only as the last resort.

Take the following example:
[What does the '{' symbol (curly-brace) indicate in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229317/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-java)

This question was deleted by Jarrod Roberson, Sotirios Delimanolis, and Louis. Later on, xenteros and Alexander O'Mara joined them, and I believe that one of them figured that it was a mistake to delete it, yet it was put on hold.

Before the question was deleted, the guy that wrote the top answer asked why is was being downvoted, and he was answered by Jarrod that this answer shouldn't have been there. Minor fact, the accepted answer was written by a member with over 200k rep!

IMO not only should this question not have been deleted, it shouldn't have been put on hold either.

As for the "dup" comment above: this is not a dup since the other question suggests that there is an answer that is valuable only to the OP and suggests to make the question and answers visible only to the OP and high rep users and make it invisible to "search". In this case I believe that the question is valuable and will help  other people in the future as well.

So my question is:

#### When a member of Stack Overflow believes that the actions of other members are made in error, who should this member "appeal" to and how?

Is the "reopen" link the only option?

Comment: well... in the case of closing/deleting questions, typically that's something that can be dealt with by anyone, not just diamond  mods. In that situation, non-elected moderators can undo those actions.

Comment: My personal feeling on this particular question is that it isn't useful, unless your teacher/instructor is asking said question. It would get a downvote from me, but I'd probably not bother with casting a close vote on it. I wouldn't bother casting a re-open vote either.

Comment: @KevinB I thought that only mods can delete question, it's only now after bluefeet's comment that I realized it can be done by high-rep users. Yet, the question still stands.

Comment: well... not useful questions do tend to get deleted, there's nothing wrong with that. it takes several users with more than a certain amount of rep to vote to delete them sooner. Now that the question has an upvoted answer, the only way it will be deleted is by people voting to delete it.

Comment: @KevinB note that it was not my question... personally, I don't care if the question was asked by the OP or by his teacher. The only thing I'm looking at is if I consider it valuable & helpful to other people in the future.

Comment: @KevinB I suspect that this question was deleted by a single user, but it might have been two - I'm not sure.

Comment: @alfasin it was deleted by: `Sotirios Delimanolis, Jarrod Roberson, Louis`. you can see this info by looking at the revision history

Comment: @KevinB is there a place I can read more about this (I searched but didn't find). Are you saying that it takes 3 high-rep users to delete a question ?

Comment: 10k rep users have that power: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: The person that answered the question opened saying that it's not a good question because it doesn't have a well defined answer.  Clearly *that* user is the one who knew they were doing something wrong when they answered the question; they know that they should have voted to close, but they didn't.  So, to answer your question of what we can do to deal with high rep users (in this case, the answerer) doing actions they know are wrong, we have several users that voted to close and then deleted this low quality question.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks! well I guess that 3 high-rep users would make the right decision in 99.99% of the time. I'll delete this post. Thanks again!

Comment: So, now that Meta effect is in full swing, let's not delete the discussion thread. It's been deleted twice, closed and reopened in one hour

Comment: @Servy the person who answered it opened by saying "the question your teacher posed is not so great". That's quite a different thing than saying "the question you're asking here is not a good question". They are not polar opposites by any means, but they are very different statements.

Comment: Should have just dupe closed it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241088/java-what-do-curly-braces-mean-by-themselves

Comment: that question is too narrow to cover what this question is asking.

Comment: @TylerH Considering that literally everything else in the question is pointless meta commentary that adds nothing to the question, I don't consider it a meaningful distinction.  How do you feel anything that the OP added to the question meaningfully impacts its appropriateness?

Comment: @Servy Actually, the rest of the question provides the subject of opportunity that the answerer used to respond.

Comment: @TylerH Nothing in the answer or any of the comments have addressed anything outside of the quoted question.

Comment: @Servy The quoted question only asks 'what does { do'. The OP follows the quote by demonstrating he is aware of its possible different uses depending on the programming context. It's that broader question that the answer addresses; the use in detail in each context and the overall question of 'what does it mean'.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not saying it should necessarily be edited out of the question, because yes, it does give at least a bit of context to what the OP understands, but fundamentally the answer is still really only ever answering the quoted question (and even re-iterates what the OP said they already knew) so clearly all of the problems with the question are still there; none of those problems are negated by anything the OP added to their teacher's question.

Comment: To me it sounds almost as if the user is asking what the teacher wants to hear, rather than asking what { means. He/she already seemed to know what it meant,

Comment: Note that the rep (or lack thereof) of any answering user is **not** relevant to whether or not it's a good question.

Comment: @KevinB I respectfully disagree with your last comment. I understand that this is your interpretation and now I also see the reasoning to reject it, my interpretation was different, it was something like: "that's what my teacher asked, this is all I know and even though I did my research - I want to make sure I didn't miss anything". Please give the OP the benefit of the doubt ;)

Comment: The op should edit the question to clarify. Until then, it should be closed/on hold.

Comment: @KevinB thanks to Martijn Pieters now the question is finally locked :) This demonstrates how the communication over the web lacks something basic. I believe that if both sides of the discussion would sit together (physically) and discuss it face to face (preferably holding a beer..) - it would have been resolved much quicker and with no hard feelings on either side. Oh well.. I'm glad I opened it for a discussion here in meta and even collected 20 downvotes which breaks all my past records :))) Happy holidays to all of you!

Comment: well, it's locked so that we can discuss the final outcome here.

Comment: @KevinB I'm glad that it's locked cause it also means that it's protected and unlike some of the people here - I *do* consider this question as valuable.

Comment: @alfasin it's unlikely that the question will stay locked forever.

Comment: @vaultah what kind of event, do you think, would change it ?

Comment: @alfasin Content dispute locks are, by there very nature, temporary.  When the lock was applied it was almost certainly a timed lock; it will automatically go away after a day or two, if a mod doesn't remove it earlier.

Comment: @alfasin ideally, the lock should give us enough time here to figure out what should happen on that question and then apply it.

Comment: @Servy thanks - good to know!

Comment: @Patrice something that I still fail to understand: some people here said that the OP should edit the question to make it clearer. I'm not sure how is it possible... Do they expect the OP to write something: "I don't expect you to be a mind-reader and figure out what my teacher meant, I just want to make sure I covered all the meanings of the the `{` symbol in Java language" ? because adding something like that to the question will make it worse IMO...

Comment: If the question was moved away from 'My teacher asked X' and to 'What does { mean in Java?' it would be more clear that the user was asking what `{` could mean in java, but then it'd just be a duplicate (though dupe is better than not useful i guess)

Comment: @KevinB ohhh.... I can't *not* agree with that :) too bad that there is no link to the dup in the comments.

Comment: @alfasin That would make it not opinion based or unclear but still too broad, which was exactly the reason it was closed for.

Comment: @Servy I think that the accepted answer proves that it's not too broad. That said, if it's a dup - it should be closed as such!

Comment: @alfasin The answer (that is not accepted) proves that it *is* too broad, given that it starts out by stating exactly why the question isn't answerable.  Posting an answer to a question doesn't mean it's too broad, it just means it hasn't actually gotten an answer that answers the question.

Comment: @Servy I don't see anywhere anything that states that "the question isn't answerable". It would be a bit of an oxymoron to do that, wouldn't it ? :)

Comment: I'm not saying this question is good or on-topic, but just think it should not be deleted immediately, at least it is a programming question, and we can give 5 days for op to edit the question, or let other users leave comments to point out how this question can be improved

Comment: It sounds like editing the question and making it more general and less "about the teacher" would be a good idea, but it's locked. So, what do we do now?

Comment: In 12 hours, it'll be unlocked, alfasin. Enjoy the respite.

Comment: here we go again, they decided to delete the question after I edited it... I'm giving up... Thanks for the help @Shog9 !

Comment: @alfasin you might be interested in joining the discussion Shog started: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340229/can-the-meaning-of-the-curly-brace-in-java-be-expressed-in-a-few-paragraphs

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Patrice !

Comment: You realize that now it looks like you're trying to pick a fight, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Premature closure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286040/premature-closure)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I've never argued over editing: if you want to discuss something let's do it either in the comments or in a chat room. I didn't know that someone else deleted your comment, your edit is accepted and I'm sorry for that (it wasn't clear from the comment on your first edit - which is why I reverted it). Second, that question is not similar since that other one you pointed to is intending to help the OP alone (by suggesting that the question will be visible only to the OP and not to "search"). In this case I believe that the question as well as the different answers are valuable.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*I re-wrote your question slightly; I think you made a reasonable attempt to be even-handed here, but terms like "attack" have the ironic property of making **you** appear more aggressive than you probably intended to. So with that said...*

> When a member of Stack Overflow believes that the actions of other members are made in error, who should this member "appeal" to and how?

I'll quote from [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions):

> Stack Exchange is collaboratively built, maintained, and moderated by the community. If you see a question and you disagree with the stated reason of its closure, you should **first try to edit the question** to improve it as much as possible. Read the close notice and any comments carefully to address concerns raised there.

### Editing should *always* be where you start your "appeal".

Time and time again, I've heard folks argue that they shouldn't *need* to edit because "they could understand the question perfectly well" without changes... But of course, that's irrelevant; you're not editing to improve *your own* interpretation of the question (although that might very well happen), you're editing to improve *everyone else's* ability to understand what's being asked - and in particular, you're editing to show the folks who are currently reacting badly to the question that it isn't as bad as they think it is.

...For brevity, I want to move on here, but... I really cannot overstate how important editing is. If you really care about success here, don't stop editing until you'd be proud to have the question appear under your own name; heck, don't stop until it's a question you'd happily show to a future employer as an example of how great you are at communicating with other developers. Fix *everything*, even the trivial stuff; heck, *especially* the trivial stuff: for whatever reason, most of us tend to get more annoyed by punctuation mistakes than by a question that completely misunderstands the terminology - right or wrong, it's just too easy to interpret little mistakes like that as *laziness*. If you've been around a while, you've probably met someone who'd toss out job applications if there was even a single spelling mistake - well, imagine there are a few thousand clones of that person gritting their collective teeth and moderating Stack Overflow. **So fix *everything*.**

Ok, done editing? Re-read those comments and edit again. You probably missed something, especially if the question *seemed* simple to you - maybe the author introduced a twist in the comments that caused everyone else to throw up their hands. **Don't be afraid to work in additional information** - too late to worry about stepping on toes now, you've invested too much time already; as they say, go big or go home. Take the author's pleading comments and spin them into an enthralling back-story, with a cliff-hanger ending that segues into the detailed form of the question. Re-read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure every last bit of information is there. Flesh out the tags, or remove irrelevant ones. Make sure the title is unique and descriptive and *mentions the actual subject of the question*.

Ok, now you're *sure* you're done editing, your keyboard a smoking pile of rubble on the desk in front of you, a crowd of onlookers gathering to witness the beat-down... Maybe someone is selling hot sausages onna bun.

Good. Now you just have the hard part left...

### Tell folks about your victory over mediocrity

Yeah, I know, I know... The question was "good enough" before you started. Stop fixating on that. "Good enough" is only a useful argument to have when you're 15 minutes away from a deadline and you're debating with your manager over whether the remaining bugs constitute legally-actionable negligence; you're not gonna get anywhere with that here. Your mission now is to be... Well, a missionary. Extolling to the benighted critics the hidden virtues of the question that you've so skillfully brought into the light.

- Post a comment explaining to the author *and anyone else reading* why your edits were necessary and how you sincerely believe they've totally addressed all outstanding complaints while reflecting the asker's true needs.
- If someone has been a particularly vehement critic of the question in the comments, address them directly and ask that they review your changes. Note that this is a particularly bad time to observe that only a blind marmoset could've ever failed to see the inherent goodness of the question in the first place; unless your goal is to be one of those missionaries who ends up drenched in the blood of their intended flock, you're gonna have far more luck appealing to the desire of your adversary to *stop* having <s>razor blades</s> poor grammar and spelling mistakes shoved in their eyeballs, noting the extreme effort and personal sacrifice you've dedicated to the question in order to salvage what would surely have been inevitable and righteous doom otherwise.
- You should probably also vote to reopen now.

Then, wait a bit. Most questions that are going to be reopened *will* be reopened in fairly short order; no sense putting any more work into it if not needed. Give it a half-hour; maybe go enjoy a nice cup of tea and a sausage onna bun.

Still closed / getting deleted / being attacked by marmosets? Ok; time to pull out the big guns:

### Appeal to Meta

(that's this site)

Again, perhaps avoid leading with an essay on the fallibility of all mankind and the bestial aggressiveness of certain users; instead, talk about the good folk on the 'Net who now - thanks in no small part to your efforts - will never again need to ask this particular question, *if only it could remain open and visible to all*. Complement the folks who've attempted to answer on their service to humanity, and also compliment the folks who motivated your improvements on so skillfully motivating such an exceptional editor.

Be obnoxiously polite and persistent: don't let folks drag you into a personal flame-war, or draw the conversation into some digression about those *other* questions or answers that are hurting the site; you're here for one purpose only, and that's to salvage this question; if others want to learn a lesson from it, that's on them.

And then, finally... Be willing to respect the decision of the community, even if it doesn't go your way. Some battles cannot be won. Don't let it get you down; grab another cup of tea and move on to the next one.

Comment: Wanna play Sherlock Holmes? [Help solve the mystery of the REAL source of the curley brace question!](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131087/discussion-on-answer-by-shog9-how-can-one-appeal-the-decisions-of-high-reputatio) Was it a teacher, an interviewer... Or the butler? But please don't discuss it here unless you've already covered the matter in great detail within your own answer; spoilers, y'know.

Comment: *'Editing should always be where you start your "appeal".'* - I thoroughly disagree. Usually, when I disagree strongly enough with a question closure to want to fight it (which doesn't happen often), the edits I would need to make to placate the close voters would not merely be *unnecessary*, but *destructive*. For instance, there's no way I'm going to try to placate the "what have you tried" crowd by deliberately adding some broken code into a question in order to show an "attempt" to solve it.

Answer (score 10):

This answer was meant for a previous interaction with the question, I agree with everything [Shog wrote elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339894/792066). A possible fix is for OP to show us an example that we could identify. What I meant with this answer is to critique the claim that using the moderating powers *to moderate* is seen as aggressive. Considering the attention span of the internet, no action is done early enough, and so I write the following answer:

> any kind of aggressiveness should be used only as the last resort.

Let me query about this statement... what in the world is "aggressive" in deleting a Crappy™ question? They have all the right that the system confers them to delete a Crappy™ question, which is meant to be used on these cases. The delete button is the *only* option in this specific case:

1. The answer, without knowing what the professor meant with it is impossible to give.
2. Even if we did educated guesses about it, [we could all be wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/389642/792066)
3. It is a waste of time.

Basically, what the asker wanted to know can only be reasonably answered by the one that crafted the question, and considering the context, it was probably meant as a mind teaser to see what its students were capable of, rather than looking for an specific answer, which FYI goes against the core principle of SE: specific answers to specific questions.

By all means, the question should be deleted ASAP to prevent innocent by-standers from wasting time upon it. The system is working as it's meant to, YAY!

Comment: well, it was anyway, until the question was undeleted a second time by the same users. :p (related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283555/why-are-we-able-to-vote-to-delete-or-undelete-over-and-over-again)

Comment: @KevinB I'm sidestepping that issue, by addressing the perceived "aggressiveness" on the actions of those users, I intend to show that they did the Right™ thing and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I believe that the question doesn't fall under any one of the 3 categories you provided, does it mean that it's actually not such a "crappy" question after all ?

Comment: @alfasin well, no, that simply means we disagree.

Comment: @KevinB out of plain curiosity: which one of the 3 do you think it falls under?

Comment: @alfasin all three. Given the rest of the course we may have had the context to understand what the professor was asking for, but we aren't the students. (that covers both 1 and 2) and 3, I don't see how the question, as asked, could be useful to anyone who isn't in the same class.

Comment: @alfasin Moderation on SO is based mostly on a consensus between a group of users with enough rep to have the privilage that allows them to moderate. Sometimes, such as here, we disagree. Now we have a meta post where we can freely discuss the outcome of this question. Not all cases are true/false, infact most cases have some gray area that is open to interpretation.

Comment: @KevinB I totally agree with your last comment. And as I wrote in one of the comments up there, now that I realized that it takes 3 high-rep in order to delete a question - I'm satisfied with it. Nothing is 100% error-proof, and we'll always have exceptions, and like any distributed system - if we can achieve four-five 9's of SLA - it's considered to be good/available, the same applies here (I hope that the geeky metaphor is clear).

Comment: While this question could indeed be improved, I don't see how it's intrinsically off-topic for Stack Overflow? Just because it's a "my teacher asked a question I don't understand"-question?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker err... the question isn't "off topic", it's a programming question that one would need a developer to answer, so it's withing the scope. The question itself, can't be answered as we would need more context to answer it, therefore: unclear or too broad can be used.

Comment: Yes, with "off-topic" I meant that in the broad sense to also intended to include Unclear & Too Broad. At any rate, it seems clear and specific enough to provide a good answer? The fact that someone actually did that seems proof of that?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker what? The OP itself ruled out all the possible answers.

Comment: @Braiam he didn't "rule out", he provided all the usages he found or in other words, he did his research and tried to answer his own question...

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I follow? Your answer (and comments) seem to focus that the OP asked the question in the wrong form (["NO SOUP FOR YOU!"](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php)). This might be true, but a very simple edit fixes this without changing anything about the underlying question/confusion that the OP has (I'd make this edit if the post wasn't locked). I don't see how there's anything intrinsically about the question that's off-topic/unclear/too broad/etc.?

Comment: @alfasin he did rule it out "As it could be the start of a method, or if statement, for loop, etc.", all of those, are potential meanings of { in Java. If he says that he knows all the possible answers, how isn't that ruling out all possibles answers?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker is not the "wrong form"; is that no matter what form, that question is fundamentally flawed: if a teacher asked me that same question, I would ask for more context, otherwise I expose myself to give the wrong answer.

Comment: But it's not *about* the teacher. Forget about that teacher; this is exactly the part I would edit out. It's *about* confusion on how the `{` character works in Java.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker you forget about the teacher, it was more of a visualization of the current state of affairs. My main point is: we can't tell you what you don't know, if you don't know what you don't know. The OP told us that he knows everything we already know, that without further clarifications from the OP (or OP's teacher), we don't know what the answer *is*.

Answer (score 1):

You appeal the decision by either performing the opposite action (reopening or undeleting) or by bringing the question to meta to allow others to perform said opposite action if they see fit.

Generally, moderation on SO is handled by users who have an appropriate amount of rep.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

15 rep: upvote, flag
125 rep: downvote
3000 rep: close/reopen vote
10000 rep: delete/undelete vote
20000 rep: earlier delete vote

An elected moderator's role in this kind of situation is generally more on the side of mediator; they lock the post, forcing us to instead discuss the post rather than keep on closing/reopening. When a consensus is reached the lock can be removed and the post actioned.

Comment: you forgot to list [most powerful privilege](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268115/839601) - meta participation which "...allows one to even overrule decisions of diamond moderators and change the way how Stack Overflow operates - what can be more powerful than *that*?"