# How can I appeal unfairly closed questions?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions, reopen-closed

How can I appeal unfairly closed questions?

I noticed that difficult and annoying* questions often get closed, not because they are unclear or lack details, but because **the voter finds it difficult to answer that question**.

This happened to me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74636553/match-comments-unless-the-initiating-char-is-surrounded-by-unescaped-quotes) and to my colleagues.

In my case, the question received a correct answer from a reputable user (>15K), so it was clear enough for him to understand it.  ... but was close-voted anyway.

The question also contained examples of a proper input and output in a color tagged diagram and test vectors for easy copy&pasting (because the text in the diagram would require retyping).  Finally, it included my best effort code to solve the problem (which worked on 92% of the test cases) and a link to a simulation.

My colleague with a high reputation to view the close votes has said that he experienced the same for clear but difficult questions from vindictive members.

How can I appeal such unfairness ... or at least find out what was the exact claim of "unclearness" being made?

* to some, but not others

Comment: *"I noticed that difficult questions often gets closed not because they are unclear or lack details but because the voter finds it difficult to answer that question"* -- did one of the close voters tell you straight out that this is why they voted to close your question? If not, how can you assume that this is the reason? Myself, I'm pretty poor at mind-reading, but perhaps your skills are better.

Comment: Because I know who he is and because of my correspondence with him

Comment: So, "he" did in fact tell you outright that he voted to close your question because it was too difficult? And it wasn't a "he" who closed your question but rather 3 site members, and I see no comments in the moved-to-chat from any one of your 3 close voters

Comment: Who is this "he"?

Comment: No but it is obvious and my question was not unclear or lacked details as you can see for yourself and it was not unclear to the member who had provided a correct answer, either..  Also my colleagues experienced the same unjustifiable closings on questions that were just difficult - not unclear.

Comment: You've edited your question [17 times](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74636553/revisions) before it got closed. In the 14th revision you added the part about escaping quotes, this seems to be an indicator that your question at least before the 14th revision wasn't clear enough. We don't have timestamps for the initial close voters (except maybe a moderator would be able to see those)

Comment: @Abdul:  No the part about escaping quotes was there from the beginning it was just in the color diagram.  Also, me editing it so many times shows the evolution of the test vectors for corner cases - not uncleariness.  I made a good effort to improve this question with all these edits.

Comment: It's certainly a tricky (and annoying) regex task, but I don't think the question is unclear. You've explained it quite well, IMHO.

Comment: @PM 2Ring:  Exactly, it is a tricky and annoying (to some) question.  But annoying is not the same as "unclear".  I think there should be requirement to justify an "unclear" claim during close-voting. e.g.: "it is unclear how to treat unbalanced quotes".  Finally, note that I am rising this issue despite already having received a correct answer, because I don't want this question AND ANSWER to disappear from Stackoveflow so other people can benefit from it in the future.

Comment: BTW, it's reasonable to claim that a question was closed unfairly or erroneously. However, it's *not* a good idea to make accusations about people's motives: that generally is not well-received here on meta. And despite what the close notice says, that doesn't mean that all 3 close voters chose that reason.

Comment: While the question isn't a duplicate, the answers here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268240/3648282 may assist you. The banner on your closed question is clear about reopening, if it's the reviewers that you want to complain about remember that it takes more than just one to close for that reason.

Comment: "the evolution of the test vectors for corner cases" That's nearly the *definition* of "unclear" for a question asking for a regular expression. Writing a regular expression is *largely* about what the corner cases are and how to handle them. Not having them explicitly defined nearly always makes such questions unclear.

Comment: @Makyen: Initially there were 10 test vectors and BEFORE the question was closed I added 3 more.  Due to the laws of combinatorics, an exhaustive list of all test vectors would be huge - one can only pick and choose the best ones for brevity.. All in all, closing and eventually deleting this question only deprives the people in the future from benefiting by the helluva good work that the author of the accepted answer had done.  Note, that closing this question has happened AFTER I already had added the 3 additional test vectors and AFTER I had received the correct answer.

Comment: You also started asking more follow up questions in the comments to the answer which is generally frowned upon: ```How would you wrap the found comment in constant HTML tags upon replace? $1<TAG>$2</TAG> would not work . Also, I have another comment coming up... Unfortunately, I need to hit the road now :( –```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can appeal it by editing the question and marking it ready for reopening, or casting a reopen vote. The reopen review queue will reevaluate the question and reopen it, if the question is suitable for the site.

If you think that a user voted to close your question out of spite due to your past interactions, you can flag the question for moderator attention with enough evidence to suggest that it's truly some kind of sick revenge.

Comment: Also note that mods generally don't get involved in normal reopening. Unless there's clear evidence to indicate some type of abuse, flags asking for questions to be reopened generally get declined. Use reopen votes instead

Comment: @Zoe:  Where do I find the "reopen votes" option ?

Comment: @Pavel You will be able to cast reopen votes on your own questions when you have 250 rep points. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Comment: Do we really not have a duplicate on Meta for this information?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Maybe this? [How can one appeal the decisions of high-reputation users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339881/1839439)