# Do we close questions that are only useful for the asker?

Tags: support

There are many questions from novice developers that are asking obvious things. Often they are also asking them badly. The questions like this quickly gather a lot of downvotes and end up in the close queue.

Now when I'm going through the close queue I often can guess what the question is about, especially if I see the question after a few rounds of comments / clarifications. I certainly can improve the question and provide a meaningful answer. In some cases that would be enough for the asker and in some cases that would be the XY and a follow-up question will follow ("Yes, but in my case I also doing A and it's then causing B").

In the end it is unlikely that this question will help future visitors, because it's about too local, too specific a problem that results from lack of understanding, knowledge and experience. (I don't mean it in a bad way; we all have to start somewhere).

Now, what is more important, to help an individual overcome his programming problem or to keep the site clean of content that is not useful to anyone but this single person? There are a lot of questions like this in the Close Queue, and I'm not voting to close them because I believe that the people can still get help (even if not from me). Am I right or wrong to do this. Should I vote close them instead?

Comment: Case by case basis. Such questions might fall under the close reason "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".

Comment: I don't think it's valid to close them on that reason alone. There use to be a "too localized" close reason, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons

Comment: @CRABOLO, lol, I know, I specifically has not mention it so that people don't tell me "it was removed for a reason!", I know that already =)

Comment: I believe there used to be a "too localized" Close Reason for this. In practice today, it's up to you to make the determination; if you feel it's worth your time to help someone else, then edit the post/answer it. If you think it's not worth *anyone's* time, cast a close vote. If you think it might be worth someone's time, just not yours, then just leave the question alone.

Comment: I personally hate that "useful/not useful" is one of the reasons to down/up vote a question as thats opinionated (which is a close reason and a bit hypocritical). Whether or not a question should be closed shouldn't matter as to how localised it is but whether or not it meets the guidelines. Whilst it may be local at the time the op is writing, they sometimes expand into useful material

Comment: @rene I didn't feel my response was fleshed out enough to be an answer. The real comment was the "too localized" memory; the rest was just thought diarrhea.

Comment: Ask yourself: who am I to judge that a question won't help someone else. I've had plenty of times that a Google search brought me to a question and answer that helped me fix a problem, even though the question itself was pretty bad and localized.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, you should see some questions. When you look at them there is no reasonable doubt.

Comment: When you guess what the author wanted to ask, edit his question for him, and then answer it - this would be very nice of you, but on the other hand you should also notice that this takes away from the author the possibility to learn how to use StackOverflow better. To put it as a question: What is generally more important - to get an answer for a problem at hand, or to learn how to use SO to get the answer to many questions? - Don't forget that closing/downvoting a question should be educational for the author, as well as good for the overall quality of the SO content.

Comment: @zespri Those questions usually already have another reason to close, like unclear, too broad, or "needs more information"

Comment: What annoys me more is that these questions tend to get more upvotes than decent questions.  Maybe I don't see the close-requested ones.

Comment: @Sayse opinion is the point of votes.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I personally think that attempting to guess, up-front, whether a question may or may not help other people beyond the OP is like attempting to divine the future from tea leaves.

Even said "typographical errors" can sometimes lead to inscrutable error messages, and future developers could benefit from a question that links the error message to the answer explaining what's going on (I mean, have you tried leaving off the `;` after a `struct` definition in C or C++?).

As a result, I wonder if rather than guesstimate up-front, we should not simply let such questions be and only retro-actively clean them up if they appear not to gather enough attention (upvotes/views).

Post-curation instead of pre-curation!

*Note: the idea actually came about when discussing how SO can feel grating for newcomers, why not answer if we have the capability (and clean-up after a while) rather than just close? Wouldn't it feel more welcoming?*

Comment: I did not down vote you, but I would expect that such a major for SO idea as providing useful searchable content for others should be reflected in an answer with positive connotations.

Comment: "(I mean, have you tried leaving off the ; after a struct definition in C or C++?)" Nope, and I dare not - but I've seen people put a space between a function name and the opening parenthesis only to find out [it doesn't work in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877198/why-is-rgb-224-226-213-an-invalid-property-value).

Comment: [Does anyone have a `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/592322/1015495)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Every time I learn about another PHP shenanigan I cry a little inside.

Comment: @matt [lolphp](https://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/)

Comment: I think the typo is more like "You used FullName when the variable was *actually* "Fullname". Those kinds of problems, unless *very* well worded, deserve the "not useful to future readers" close reason.

Comment: I don't remember seeing a "not useful to future readers" close reason.

Comment: @Warren Dew: It usually goes by the description "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" - because it's that portion that's highlighted in bold in the notice of closure.

Comment: *"I mean, have you tried leaving off the `;` after a `struct` definition in C or C++?"* [Yes.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b37fac4642ecb9a3) :P But I agree, as long as there is enough of the error message for the question to be searchable and not a huge blob of code, sure, why not answer it or close as dupe. I do however not agree with answering poor questions because it is welcoming, we rather should educate new users how to ask good questions, not encourage "help vampires".

Answer (score 7):

You did a very bad thing here, by asking two separate, and even severely contradicting questions:

1. Should we close badly worded or obvious questions?
2. Should we close questions that are only useful for asker?

This kind of "questions" always spawn a discussion, because people seldom read the text as a whole, but instead start answering regarding only one side.

Yet, when taken separately, these two questions have obvious answers:

1. No, we have to improve and answer them (or close as a duplicate)
2. Yes, we have to close them as too localized (which, in case you didn't notice, is disguised as "Offtopic->Questions seeking debugging help" now).

Regarding the question in the last paragraph, it has been asked a zillion times already. And solutions were proposed as well. But nobody has the guts to make the change.

*De jure* we have to keep the site clean and make it source for knowledge.
*De facto* we have a service for quick-and-dirty on-site answers, which makes it paradise for hordes of noobs, who don't want to learn, as well for the rep-whores, who feed on bad questions. As these two parties outnumber any other party on Stack Overflow, there is no way to change anything.

Yes, occasionally it works as expected, producing great content. But there are two major problems with it: the community.

1. People here are extremely intolerant to any opinion that doesn't comply with their views.
2. *Modus operandi* of the community is to **constantly retell old tales again and again**. Unfortunately, with very little intelligence added.

Surely, your hands are already itching, to downvote and to delete-delete-delete such a vile slander. But wait a second. I have a proof.

To proof the first statement, I won't take my humble person, but instead a *very* vivid case, when your community tried to close a [question with extremely useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393441/obfuscated-c-code-contest-2006-please-explain-sykes2-c), totally unique content **[three times](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15393441/revisions)** in a row. Three times, Carl! And it would have closed it, no doubt, and eventually *deleted(!)* this great contribution, if no mods intervened.

For the second statement no proof really needed I believe. Anyone who have a fancy of tracing constant flow of questions here, already made a picture for himself. Instead of closing as a duplicate, people are really taking delight in retelling old answers again and again. It wouldn't be that bad, if sometimes their tales weren't a plain lie.

Tale #1. "Escape everything you put in the query".
As a result, we have an [illiterate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236505/mysqli-bind-param-not-setting-string-to-null/24236542#24236542) that says to escape data that is going to be used in a prepared statement.

Tale #2. "Use placeholder for the everything you put in the query".
This is a king, a guaranteed reputation gain. Alas, [when used without real knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329733/php-pdo-selecting-columns-with-single-quotes-in-their-name/12329745#12329745), it's but a blunder.

Tale #3. "Gag any error message you may get".
As a result we have an answer, that is not only contradicting with basic programming principles, but [even doesn't work the way the author *thinks* it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32127137/285587). Because he never tried this code actually himself. He just picked it up somewhere around here, and since then retelling in mindlessly, having no idea if it's right or wrong.

What did your community do to these illiterate answers?

## Nothing

but upvoting and appreciating them.

Now on the bright side.

Yes, this site *occasionally* works as expected, producing some unique content. But signal to noise ratio is unacceptable low. Especially when compared to the *real* source of knowledge - Wikipedia. The very similar, community-driven non-commercial site. But outcome is dramatically different. Try to think, what is the difference.

Comment: There is no "too localized" close reason any more.

Comment: May I suggest removing the fluff from this answer, talking about how the question is _"bad"_, and those last 2 paragraphs?... They really don't add anything to the answer.

Comment: @RowlandShaw [seeking debugging help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685/839601) has got a place in close dialog for about a year now. That said, [Off topic questions have to be cleared out of the way, but NOT via closure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251897/839601)

Comment: *De facto* we actually have both, with an incredibly high signal-to-noise ratio compared to the remainder of the InterTubules. I find the apparent attitude towards beginners and those who enjoy helping them, as I do, rather annoying. A good reputation addict writes excellent answers to basic questions to give newcomers a foundation.

Comment: I do wonder whether the constant worry from some users about the signal to noise ratio is misguided, and based on having been an active user for so long. It's really noticeable that there's a lot of garbage if you're reviewing, editing, etc. - but if you're *looking for an answer* then the site works pretty well, and improving that experience is probably more about improving search and related question algorithms than it is about removing the garbage. As long as people don't *see* too much of the garbage, does the existence of it really matter? So I don't see the harm in basic questions.

Comment: As a caveat to that, I'm not suggesting genuinely *bad* questions are OK, or having loads of duplicates is OK. It's important that really poor or off-topic questions are amended or closed, and it's important that duplicates get pointed to the existing question. The latter helps with the answer-finding process. But basic/simple but decently written questions? I'm not seeing a huge problem, and you never know when they might help someone else. If they're getting voted up, they probably *are* helping people.

Answer (score 7):

It depends why you believe a particular question is only useful for the asker. If they've illustrated the problem with external links to their site, or are asking readers to download their project to debug it, then yes - it should be closed. This is because it would also contravene the rule that questions should be (at least mostly) self-contained.

If the question is too localised and is very short or lazy, then again it can be closed, but not because it is too localised.

Very occasionally I will use the custom reason to "bring back" the old "too localised" close reason. Sometimes I will do this if the question contains several distinct sub-questions that would have been better on their own. Of course, if the question does not yet have any answers, it may sometimes be better to edit out the secondary questions, and leave a good primary question open. (As long as you explain what you're doing, the OP usually will not mind this, as they've avoided being put on hold!)

A short answer to your question, then: yes, you can close for "too localised", but close for another reason if you can, and if you are in doubt, leave it open.

Answer (score -15):

No ! If search is correctly prioritizing much answered much cited questions then "useless" questions are doing no harm to anybody. Mostly, as the asker of some useful questions and some useless ones, it has been useful, to me, to watch some of my questions swinging in the breeze unanswered, and much nicer than feeling the victim of an over-zealous administrator.

Comment: This is the problem though: the view that useless questions are doing no harm is strongly contested on Stack Overflow. My opinion is that lazy/unclear/broad questions need to be closed to discourage help vampirism, but also because allowing that sort of question to persist increases the administrative burden on community members for no worthwhile benefit. Of course, if a question can be improved, that is ideal, but there are many questions on the site that are not improvable.

Answer (score -15):

I believe it is more important to help the fellow programmer get off his learning tracks and then keeping the site clean on that aspect.

For this, what I would propose, would be for, in the answers to their question, motivate them to post more general information about their problems, so as to leave tips for future programmers with similar questions who might somehow get something from that programmers question, even if it is pretty local/specific. There is always something someone might take from it.

Also, your point on improving the question. That would be an ideal solution, on my opinion.
Some might think it's not worth the effort, but I believe it would also help the asker achieve a further understanding of the solution and of the situation, which in some cases they don't. They simply copy the answer, because they don't get to fully understand the answer, even if they try "it happens".

And, by improving their questions, or adding some extra "general" information at the end if it, it might end up helping future programmers with the same or similar questions, even if some specific details might differ. Which would stop them from opening a question, which they might just find the answer from reading the first post.

Comment: I disagree, There are [examples](http://answers.unity3d.com/) of what happens when a Q&A starts catering for every "beginner" question. And what happens in the end is that all the experienced users leave for greener pastures (SO). Making sure questions follow guidelines make sure these experienced users stay around.

Comment: True. And you make a really good point. 
But, that also might frustrate some new users a little bit, as they might feel that their questions are being shouldered from the more experienced ones.
It is true that they have to try and search around for the answer and try to solve it themselves, as one musn't come to help at every bump on the road. But, sometimes, they really require help, and might end up feeling they are being thrown aside due to their inexperience

Comment: This is also caused, with experieced users answering new users questions kind of rudelly, and not guiding them to places where they might learn how to ask the questions the right way. As i have seen sometimes.
But i understand your point, and i partly agree with it. I just worry about the new users a bit too ahaha (not saying you don't)

Comment: I've been there, my first (now deleted and hopefully irretrievable) question was a question my manager was asking whilst sat next to me while I typed and it got *heavily* downvoted. But it really doesn't take long to scan over [ask] or look at a couple upvoted questions to see what makes a good question.

Comment: @Sayse I know, and i fully agree. People should search and try to think a little. But there's always people who simply don't know how to do so, and need a little extra help xD "Not counting for those who don't try, but for those who simply don't know"